# How to insert Greek with "ascii keyboard" and XeTeX, Polyglossia

Tags: xetex, polyglossia

How can I write greek without entering the greek characters directly? With babel, I can do this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[polutonikogreek]{babel}
\begin{document}
\selectlanguage{polutonikogreek}
d`e >en'arqontai m`en o>uk >ol'iqoi
\end{document}
```

But what should I do when using polyglossia and XeTeX?

Comment: Why don’t you change your keyboard layout temporarily? In Mac OS X I can do this with a short cut.

Comment: That is one option I'll investigate. But I need the ascii input as a fallback (not all authors can switch easily).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I get satisfying results by converting this `asciitogreek.map` file

```
; TECkit mapping for ASCII Greek <-> Unicode characters

LHSName "TeX-text"
RHSName "UNICODE"

pass(Unicode)

; Class "letter" consists of letters and characters denoting accents
; in order to cope with "sigma finalis", i.e., A-Z a-z ` ' > < ~
; we don't need the double quote because it goes only after a vowel
UniClass[letter] = ( U+0041..U+005A U+0061..U+007A U+0060 U+0027 U+003E U+003C U+007E )


; ligatures from Knuth's original CMR fonts
U+002D U+002D <> U+2013 ; -- -> en dash
U+002D U+002D U+002D <> U+2014 ; --- -> em dash

; Greek (according to C. Beccari conventions)

; (-1)
U+0022 <> U+2019 ; APOSTROPHE
U+0060 U+0060 <> U+201C ; `` -> LEFT DOUBLE QUOTATION MARK
U+0027 U+0027 <> U+201D ; '' -> RIGHT DOUBLE QUOTATION MARK
U+003C U+003C <> U+00AB ; << -> LEFT-POINTING DOUBLE ANGLE QUOTATION MARK
U+003E U+003E <> U+00BB ; >> -> RIGHT-POINTING DOUBLE ANGLE QUOTATION MARK
U+0028 U+0028 <> U+00AB ; (( -> LEFT-POINTING DOUBLE ANGLE QUOTATION MARK
U+0029 U+0029 <> U+00BB ; )) -> RIGHT-POINTING DOUBLE ANGLE QUOTATION MARK

; (0) basic letters
; uppercase
U+0041 <> U+0391 
U+0042 <> U+0392 
U+0044 <> U+0394 
U+0045 <> U+0395 
U+0046 <> U+03A6 
U+0047 <> U+0393 
U+0048 <> U+0397 
U+0049 <> U+0399 
U+004A <> U+0398 
U+004B <> U+039A 
U+004C <> U+039B 
U+004D <> U+039C 
U+004E <> U+039D 
U+004F <> U+039F 
U+0050 <> U+03A0 
U+0051 <> U+03A7 
U+0052 <> U+03A1 
U+0053 <> U+03A3 
U+0054 <> U+03A4 
U+0055 <> U+03A5 
U+0057 <> U+03A9 
U+0058 <> U+039E 
U+0059 <> U+03A8 
U+005A <> U+0396 
; lowercase
U+0061 <> U+03B1 
U+0062 <> U+03B2 
U+0063 <> U+03C2 
U+0064 <> U+03B4 
U+0065 <> U+03B5 
U+0066 <> U+03C6 
U+0067 <> U+03B3 
U+0068 <> U+03B7 
U+0069 <> U+03B9 
U+006A <> U+03B8 
U+006B <> U+03BA 
U+006C <> U+03BB 
U+006D <> U+03BC 
U+006E <> U+03BD 
U+006F <> U+03BF 
U+0070 <> U+03C0 
U+0071 <> U+03C7 
U+0072 <> U+03C1 
U+0073 <> U+03C3 
U+0073 / _ ^[letter] <> U+03C2 
U+0074 <> U+03C4 
U+0075 <> U+03C5 
U+0077 <> U+03C9 
U+0078 <> U+03BE 
U+0079 <> U+03C8 
U+007A <> U+03B6 

; (1) ` + letter -> varia
U+0060 U+0041 <> U+1FBA 
U+0060 U+0061 <> U+1F70 
U+0060 U+0045 <> U+1FC8 
U+0060 U+0065 <> U+1F72 
U+0060 U+0048 <> U+1FCA 
U+0060 U+0068 <> U+1F74 
U+0060 U+0049 <> U+1FDA 
U+0060 U+0069 <> U+1F76 
U+0060 U+004F <> U+1FF8 
U+0060 U+006F <> U+1F78 
U+0060 U+0055 <> U+1FEA 
U+0060 U+0075 <> U+1F7A 
U+0060 U+0057 <> U+1FFA 
U+0060 U+0077 <> U+1F7C 

; (2) ' + letter -> oxia
U+0027 U+0041 <> U+1FBB 
U+0027 U+0061 <> U+1F71 
U+0027 U+0045 <> U+1FC9 
U+0027 U+0065 <> U+1F73 
U+0027 U+0048 <> U+1FCB 
U+0027 U+0068 <> U+1F75 
U+0027 U+0049 <> U+1FDB 
U+0027 U+0069 <> U+1F77 
U+0027 U+004F <> U+1FF9 
U+0027 U+006F <> U+1F79 
U+0027 U+0055 <> U+1FEB 
U+0027 U+0075 <> U+1F7B 
U+0027 U+0057 <> U+1FFB 
U+0027 U+0077 <> U+1F7D 

; (3) > + letter -> psili
U+003E U+0041 <> U+1F08 
U+003E U+0061 <> U+1F00 
U+003E U+0045 <> U+1F18 
U+003E U+0065 <> U+1F10 
U+003E U+0048 <> U+1F28 
U+003E U+0068 <> U+1F20 
U+003E U+0049 <> U+1F38 
U+003E U+0069 <> U+1F30 
U+003E U+004F <> U+1F48 
U+003E U+006F <> U+1F40 
U+003E U+0055 <> U+1FBF U+03A5 
U+003E U+0075 <> U+1F50 
U+003E U+0057 <> U+1F68 
U+003E U+0077 <> U+1F60 

; (4) < + letter -> dasia
U+003C U+0041 <> U+1F09 
U+003C U+0061 <> U+1F01 
U+003C U+0045 <> U+1F19 
U+003C U+0065 <> U+1F11 
U+003C U+0048 <> U+1F29 
U+003C U+0068 <> U+1F21 
U+003C U+0049 <> U+1F39 
U+003C U+0069 <> U+1F31 
U+003C U+004F <> U+1F49 
U+003C U+006F <> U+1F41 
U+003C U+0055 <> U+1F59 
U+003C U+0075 <> U+1F51 
U+003C U+0057 <> U+1F69 
U+003C U+0077 <> U+1F61 

; (5) >` + letter -> psili and varia
U+003E U+0060 U+0041 <> U+1F0A 
U+003E U+0060 U+0061 <> U+1F02 
U+003E U+0060 U+0045 <> U+1F1A 
U+003E U+0060 U+0065 <> U+1F12 
U+003E U+0060 U+0048 <> U+1F2A 
U+003E U+0060 U+0068 <> U+1F22 
U+003E U+0060 U+0049 <> U+1F3A 
U+003E U+0060 U+0069 <> U+1F32 
U+003E U+0060 U+004F <> U+1F4A 
U+003E U+0060 U+006F <> U+1F42 
U+003E U+0060 U+0055 <> U+1FCD U+03A5 
U+003E U+0060 U+0075 <> U+1F52 
U+003E U+0060 U+0057 <> U+1F6A 
U+003E U+0060 U+0077 <> U+1F62 

; (6) `> + letter -> psili and varia
U+0060 U+003E U+0041 <> U+1F0A 
U+0060 U+003E U+0061 <> U+1F02 
U+0060 U+003E U+0045 <> U+1F1A 
U+0060 U+003E U+0065 <> U+1F12 
U+0060 U+003E U+0048 <> U+1F2A 
U+0060 U+003E U+0068 <> U+1F22 
U+0060 U+003E U+0049 <> U+1F3A 
U+0060 U+003E U+0069 <> U+1F32 
U+0060 U+003E U+004F <> U+1F4A 
U+0060 U+003E U+006F <> U+1F42 
U+0060 U+003E U+0055 <> U+1FCD U+03A5 
U+0060 U+003E U+0075 <> U+1F52 
U+0060 U+003E U+0057 <> U+1F6A 
U+0060 U+003E U+0077 <> U+1F62 

; (7) >' + letter -> psili and oxia
U+003E U+0027 U+0041 <> U+1F0C 
U+003E U+0027 U+0061 <> U+1F04 
U+003E U+0027 U+0045 <> U+1F1C 
U+003E U+0027 U+0065 <> U+1F14 
U+003E U+0027 U+0048 <> U+1F2C 
U+003E U+0027 U+0068 <> U+1F24 
U+003E U+0027 U+0049 <> U+1F3C 
U+003E U+0027 U+0069 <> U+1F34 
U+003E U+0027 U+004F <> U+1F4C 
U+003E U+0027 U+006F <> U+1F44 
U+003E U+0027 U+0055 <> U+1FCE U+03A5 
U+003E U+0027 U+0075 <> U+1F54 
U+003E U+0027 U+0057 <> U+1F6C 
U+003E U+0027 U+0077 <> U+1F64 

; (8) '> + letter -> psili and oxia
U+0027 U+003E U+0041 <> U+1F0C 
U+0027 U+003E U+0061 <> U+1F04 
U+0027 U+003E U+0045 <> U+1F1C 
U+0027 U+003E U+0065 <> U+1F14 
U+0027 U+003E U+0048 <> U+1F2C 
U+0027 U+003E U+0068 <> U+1F24 
U+0027 U+003E U+0049 <> U+1F3C 
U+0027 U+003E U+0069 <> U+1F34 
U+0027 U+003E U+004F <> U+1F4C 
U+0027 U+003E U+006F <> U+1F44 
U+0027 U+003E U+0055 <> U+1FCE U+03A5 
U+0027 U+003E U+0075 <> U+1F54 
U+0027 U+003E U+0057 <> U+1F6C 
U+0027 U+003E U+0077 <> U+1F64 

; (9) <` + letter -> dasia and varia
U+003C U+0060 U+0041 <> U+1F0B 
U+003C U+0060 U+0061 <> U+1F03 
U+003C U+0060 U+0045 <> U+1F1B 
U+003C U+0060 U+0065 <> U+1F13 
U+003C U+0060 U+0048 <> U+1F2B 
U+003C U+0060 U+0068 <> U+1F23 
U+003C U+0060 U+0049 <> U+1F3B 
U+003C U+0060 U+0069 <> U+1F33 
U+003C U+0060 U+004F <> U+1F4B 
U+003C U+0060 U+006F <> U+1F43 
U+003C U+0060 U+0055 <> U+1F5B 
U+003C U+0060 U+0075 <> U+1F53 
U+003C U+0060 U+0057 <> U+1F6B 
U+003C U+0060 U+0077 <> U+1F63 

; (10) `< + letter -> dasia and varia
U+0060 U+003C U+0041 <> U+1F0B 
U+0060 U+003C U+0061 <> U+1F03 
U+0060 U+003C U+0045 <> U+1F1B 
U+0060 U+003C U+0065 <> U+1F13 
U+0060 U+003C U+0048 <> U+1F2B 
U+0060 U+003C U+0068 <> U+1F23 
U+0060 U+003C U+0049 <> U+1F3B 
U+0060 U+003C U+0069 <> U+1F33 
U+0060 U+003C U+004F <> U+1F4B 
U+0060 U+003C U+006F <> U+1F43 
U+0060 U+003C U+0055 <> U+1F5B 
U+0060 U+003C U+0075 <> U+1F53 
U+0060 U+003C U+0057 <> U+1F6B 
U+0060 U+003C U+0077 <> U+1F63 

; (11) ~ + letter -> perispomeni
U+007E U+0041 <> U+0391 U+0342 
U+007E U+0061 <> U+1FB6 
U+007E U+0048 <> U+0397 U+0342 
U+007E U+0068 <> U+1FC6 
U+007E U+0049 <> U+0399 U+0342 
U+007E U+0069 <> U+1FD6 
U+007E U+0055 <> U+03A5 U+0342 
U+007E U+0075 <> U+1FE6 
U+007E U+0057 <> U+03A9 U+0342 
U+007E U+0077 <> U+1FF6 

; (12) >~ + letter -> psili and perispomeni
U+003E U+007E U+0041 <> U+1F0E 
U+003E U+007E U+0061 <> U+1F06 
U+003E U+007E U+0048 <> U+1F2E 
U+003E U+007E U+0068 <> U+1F26 
U+003E U+007E U+0049 <> U+1F3E 
U+003E U+007E U+0069 <> U+1F36 
U+003E U+007E U+0055 <> U+1FCF U+03A5 
U+003E U+007E U+0075 <> U+1F56 
U+003E U+007E U+0057 <> U+1F6E 
U+003E U+007E U+0077 <> U+1F66 

; (13) ~> + letter -> psili and perispomeni
U+007E U+003E U+0041 <> U+1F0E 
U+007E U+003E U+0061 <> U+1F06 
U+007E U+003E U+0048 <> U+1F2E 
U+007E U+003E U+0068 <> U+1F26 
U+007E U+003E U+0049 <> U+1F3E 
U+007E U+003E U+0069 <> U+1F36 
U+007E U+003E U+0055 <> U+1FCF U+03A5 
U+007E U+003E U+0075 <> U+1F56 
U+007E U+003E U+0057 <> U+1F6E 
U+007E U+003E U+0077 <> U+1F66 

; (14) <~ + letter -> dasia and perispomeni
U+003C U+007E U+0041 <> U+1F0F 
U+003C U+007E U+0061 <> U+1F07 
U+003C U+007E U+0048 <> U+1F2F 
U+003C U+007E U+0068 <> U+1F27 
U+003C U+007E U+0049 <> U+1F3F 
U+003C U+007E U+0069 <> U+1F37 
U+003C U+007E U+0055 <> U+1F5F 
U+003C U+007E U+0075 <> U+1F57 
U+003C U+007E U+0057 <> U+1F6F 
U+003C U+007E U+0077 <> U+1F67 

; (15) ~< + letter -> dasia and perispomeni
U+007E U+003C U+0041 <> U+1F0F 
U+007E U+003C U+0061 <> U+1F07 
U+007E U+003C U+0048 <> U+1F2F 
U+007E U+003C U+0068 <> U+1F27 
U+007E U+003C U+0049 <> U+1F3F 
U+007E U+003C U+0069 <> U+1F37 
U+007E U+003C U+0055 <> U+1F5F 
U+007E U+003C U+0075 <> U+1F57 
U+007E U+003C U+0057 <> U+1F6F 
U+007E U+003C U+0077 <> U+1F67 

; (16) letter + | -> ypogegrammeni
U+0041 U+007C <> U+1FBC 
U+0061 U+007C <> U+1FB3 
U+0048 U+007C <> U+1FCC 
U+0068 U+007C <> U+1FC3 
U+0057 U+007C <> U+1FFC 
U+0077 U+007C <> U+1FF3 

; (17) ` + letter + | -> varia and ypogegrammeni
U+0060 U+0061 U+007C <> U+1FB2 
U+0060 U+0068 U+007C <> U+1FC2 
U+0060 U+0077 U+007C <> U+1FF2 

; (18) ' + letter + | -> oxia and ypogegrammeni
U+0027 U+0061 U+007C <> U+1FB2 
U+0027 U+0068 U+007C <> U+1FC2 
U+0027 U+0077 U+007C <> U+1FF2 

; (19) ~ + letter + | -> perispomeni and ypogegrammeni
U+007E U+0061 U+007C <> U+1FB7 
U+007E U+0068 U+007C <> U+1FC7 
U+007E U+0077 U+007C <> U+1FF7 

; (20) > + letter + | -> psili and ypogegrammeni
U+003E U+0041 U+007C <> U+1F88 
U+003E U+0061 U+007C <> U+1F80 
U+003E U+0048 U+007C <> U+1F98 
U+003E U+0068 U+007C <> U+1F90 
U+003E U+0057 U+007C <> U+1FA8 
U+003E U+0077 U+007C <> U+1FA0 

; (21) >` + letter + | -> psili and varia and ypogegrammeni
U+003E U+0060 U+0041 U+007C <> U+1F8A 
U+003E U+0060 U+0061 U+007C <> U+1F82 
U+003E U+0060 U+0048 U+007C <> U+1F9A 
U+003E U+0060 U+0068 U+007C <> U+1F92 
U+003E U+0060 U+0057 U+007C <> U+1FAA 
U+003E U+0060 U+0077 U+007C <> U+1FA2 

; (22) `> + letter + | -> psili and varia and ypogegrammeni
U+0060 U+003E U+0041 U+007C <> U+1F8A 
U+0060 U+003E U+0061 U+007C <> U+1F82 
U+0060 U+003E U+0048 U+007C <> U+1F9A 
U+0060 U+003E U+0068 U+007C <> U+1F92 
U+0060 U+003E U+0057 U+007C <> U+1FAA 
U+0060 U+003E U+0077 U+007C <> U+1FA2 

; (23) >' + letter + | -> psili and oxia and ypogegrammeni
U+003E U+0027 U+0041 U+007C <> U+1F8C 
U+003E U+0027 U+0061 U+007C <> U+1F84 
U+003E U+0027 U+0048 U+007C <> U+1F9C 
U+003E U+0027 U+0068 U+007C <> U+1F94 
U+003E U+0027 U+0057 U+007C <> U+1FAC 
U+003E U+0027 U+0077 U+007C <> U+1FA4 

; (24) '> + letter + | -> psili and oxia and ypogegrammeni
U+0027 U+003E U+0041 U+007C <> U+1F8C 
U+0027 U+003E U+0061 U+007C <> U+1F84 
U+0027 U+003E U+0048 U+007C <> U+1F9C 
U+0027 U+003E U+0068 U+007C <> U+1F94 
U+0027 U+003E U+0057 U+007C <> U+1FAC 
U+0027 U+003E U+0077 U+007C <> U+1FA4 

; (25) < + letter + | -> dasia and ypogegrammeni
U+003C U+0041 U+007C <> U+1F89 
U+003C U+0061 U+007C <> U+1F81 
U+003C U+0048 U+007C <> U+1F99 
U+003C U+0068 U+007C <> U+1F91 
U+003C U+0057 U+007C <> U+1FA9 
U+003C U+0077 U+007C <> U+1FA1 

; (26) <` + letter + | -> dasia and varia and ypogegrammeni
U+003C U+0060 U+0041 U+007C <> U+1F8B 
U+003C U+0060 U+0061 U+007C <> U+1F83 
U+003C U+0060 U+0048 U+007C <> U+1F9B 
U+003C U+0060 U+0068 U+007C <> U+1F93 
U+003C U+0060 U+0057 U+007C <> U+1FAB 
U+003C U+0060 U+0077 U+007C <> U+1FA3 

; (27) `< + letter + | -> dasia and varia and ypogegrammeni
U+0060 U+003C U+0041 U+007C <> U+1F8B 
U+0060 U+003C U+0061 U+007C <> U+1F83 
U+0060 U+003C U+0048 U+007C <> U+1F9B 
U+0060 U+003C U+0068 U+007C <> U+1F93 
U+0060 U+003C U+0057 U+007C <> U+1FAB 
U+0060 U+003C U+0077 U+007C <> U+1FA3 

; (28) <' + letter + | -> dasia and oxia and ypogegrammeni
U+003C U+0027 U+0041 U+007C <> U+1F8D 
U+003C U+0027 U+0061 U+007C <> U+1F85 
U+003C U+0027 U+0048 U+007C <> U+1F9D 
U+003C U+0027 U+0068 U+007C <> U+1F95 
U+003C U+0027 U+0057 U+007C <> U+1FAD 
U+003C U+0027 U+0077 U+007C <> U+1FA5 

; (29) '< + letter + | -> dasia and oxia and ypogegrammeni
U+0027 U+003C U+0041 U+007C <> U+1F8D 
U+0027 U+003C U+0061 U+007C <> U+1F85 
U+0027 U+003C U+0048 U+007C <> U+1F9D 
U+0027 U+003C U+0068 U+007C <> U+1F95 
U+0027 U+003C U+0057 U+007C <> U+1FAD 
U+0027 U+003C U+0077 U+007C <> U+1FA5 

; (30) " + letter -> dialytika
U+0022 U+0049 <> U+03AA 
U+0022 U+0069 <> U+03CA 
U+0022 U+0055 <> U+03AB 
U+0022 U+0075 <> U+03CB 

; (31) "' + letter -> dialytika and oxia
U+0022 U+0027 U+0069 <> U+1FD3 
U+0022 U+0027 U+0075 <> U+1FE3 

; (32) '" + letter -> dialytika and oxia
U+0027 U+0022 U+0069 <> U+1FD3 
U+0027 U+0022 U+0075 <> U+1FE3 

; (33) "` + letter -> dialytika and varia
U+0022 U+0060 U+0069 <> U+1FD2 
U+0022 U+0060 U+0075 <> U+1FE2 

; (34) `" + letter -> dialytika and varia
U+0060 U+0022 U+0069 <> U+1FD2 
U+0060 U+0022 U+0075 <> U+1FE2 

; (35) "~ + letter -> dialytika and perispomeni
U+0022 U+007E U+0069 <> U+1FD7 
U+0022 U+007E U+0075 <> U+1FE7 

; (36) ~" + letter -> dialytika and perispomeni
U+007E U+0022 U+0069 <> U+1FD7 
U+007E U+0022 U+0075 <> U+1FE7 

; (37) rho, medial sigma and punctuation
; >r
U+003E U+0072 <> U+1FE4 
; <R
U+003C U+0052 <> U+1FEC 
; <r
U+003C U+0072 <> U+1FE5 
; medial sigma (sv)
U+0073 U+0076 <> U+03C3 
; question mark
U+003F <> U+037E 
; semicolon
U+003B <> U+0387
```

with the command

```
teckit_compile asciitogreek.map
```

Then the following document

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Tempora LGC Unicode}
% \newfontfamily\greekfont{GFS Neohellenic}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setmainlanguage[variant=polytonic]{greek}

\XeTeXinputnormalization=1

\newenvironment{transgreek}
  {\catcode`\~=12 \begin{otherlanguage}{greek}%
   \addfontfeature{Mapping=asciitogreek}}
  {\end{otherlanguage}}
\newenvironment{transgreek*}
  {\catcode`\~=12 \begin{otherlanguage*}{greek}%
   \addfontfeature{Mapping=asciitogreek}}
  {\end{otherlanguage*}}

\newcommand{\texttransgreek}{\begingroup
  \catcode`\~=12 \innertexttransgreek}
\newcommand*{\innertexttransgreek}[1]{%
  \begin{transgreek*}#1\end{transgreek*}\endgroup}

\begin{document}

\begin{transgreek}
Th| p'anta dido'ush| ka`i
>apolambano'ush| f'usei <o
pepaideum'enos ka`i a>id'hmwn
l'egei; ((d`os, <`o j'eleis,
>ap'olabe, <`o j'eleic)).
L'egei d`e to~uto o>u
katajrasun'omenos, >all`a
peijarq~wn m'onon ka`i
e>uno~wn a>ut~h|.
\end{transgreek}

\texttransgreek{Th| p'anta dido'ush| ka`i
>apolambano'ush| f'usei <o
pepaideum'enos ka`i a>id'hmwn
l'egei; ((d`os, <`o j'eleis,
>ap'olabe, <`o j'eleic)).
L'egei d`e to~uto o>u
katajrasun'omenos, >all`a
peijarq~wn m'onon ka`i
e>uno~wn a>ut~h|.}

\begin{transgreek}
Œì<<tonos>>

``soma''


0 

abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz

ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ

abgdezhjiklmnxoprsctupqyw

ABGDEZHJIKLMNXOPRSTUFQYW

1 (bare~ia) `a `e `h `i `o `u `w `A `E `H `I `O `U `W

2 (>oxe~ia) 'a 'e 'h 'i 'o 'u 'w 'A 'E 'H 'I 'O 'U 'W

3 (das`u pne~uma) >a >e >h >i >o >u >w >A >E >H >I >O >U >W

4 (yil'on pne~uma) <a <e <h <i <o <u <w <A <E <H <I <O <U <W

5 >`a >`e >`h >`i >`o >`u >`w >`A >`E >`H >`I >`O >`U >`W

6 `>a `>e `>h `>i `>o `>u `>w `>A `>E `>H `>I `>O `>U `>W

7 >'a >'e >'h >'i >'o >'u >'w >'A >'E >'H >'I >'O >'U >'W

8 '>a '>e '>h '>i '>o '>u '>w '>A '>E '>H '>I '>O '>U '>W

9 >`a >`e >`h >`i >`o >`u >`w >`A >`E >`H >`I >`O >`U >`W

10 `>a `>e `>h `>i `>o `>u `>w `>A `>E `>H `>I `>O `>U `>W

11 (perispwm'enh) ~a ~h ~i ~u ~w ~A ~H ~I ~U ~W

12 >~a >~h >~i >~u >~w >~A >~H >~I >~U >~W

13 ~>a ~>h ~>i ~>u ~>w ~>A ~>H ~>I ~>U ~>W

14 <~a <~h <~i <~u <~w <~A <~H <~I <~U <~W

15 ~<a ~<h ~<i ~<u ~<w ~<A ~<H ~<I ~<U ~<W

16 a| h| w| A| H| W|

17 `a| `h| `w|

18 'a| 'h| 'w|

19 ~a| ~h| ~w|

20 >a| >h| >w| >A| >H| >W| 

21 >`a| >`h| >`w| >`A| >`H| >`W| 

22 `>a| `>h| `>w| `>A| `>H| `>W|

23 >'a| >'h| >'w| >'A| >'H| >'W| 

24 '>a| '>h| '>w| '>A| '>H| '>W|

25 <a| <h| <w| <A| <H| <W| 

26 <`a| <`h| <`w| <`A| <`H| <`W| 

27 `<a| `<h| `<w| `<A| `<H| `<W|

28 <'a| <'h| <'w| <'A| <'H| <'W| 

29 '<a| '<h| '<w| '<A| '<H| '<W|

30 "i "u "I "U

31 "'i "'u

32 '"i '"u

33 "`i "`u

34 `"i `"u

35 "~i "~u

36 ~"i ~"u

37 >r <R <r sv s" ? ;
\end{transgreek}
\end{document}
```

will show that the transliterization works according with the **babel** conventions.

[image]

Comment: Looks fine to me! I had an issue with the asciitogreek.map. `teckit_compile` complained about `:` - is it safe to replace the `:` by `;`?

Comment: @Patrick Sorry: I had to modify the file (the full version has comments for identifying the code points) and in the process the semicolons became colons. The new version should be correct.

Answer (score 5):

If you have only a few greek chars you want to enter you can also use the `^^^^+unicode` notation. E.g. for an alpha:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Arial}
\begin{document}
^^^^03b1

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

If you’re using GNU/Linux, the Hellenic Polytonic HOWTO ([tlgu.carmen.gr/Hellenic_polytonic_HOWTO.html](http://tlgu.carmen.gr/Hellenic_polytonic_HOWTO.html)) will be invaluable to you.  Note, however, that some of the instructions need updating: at least on Debian systems, one now edits /etc/default/keyboard rather than XF86Config.

Answer (score 3):

I improved the `asciitogreek.map` developed by `egreg` because it did not account for some combinations of accents. The missing accent combinations were:

- Combination of dasia (rough breathing mark) and oxia, such as in ἵνα
- Combination of breathing mark (dasia, psili), perispomeni (long accent) and ypogegrammeni, such as in ᾖς

This is my content of `asciitogreek.map`:

```
; TECkit mapping for ASCII Greek <-> Unicode characters

LHSName "TeX-text"
RHSName "UNICODE"

pass(Unicode)

; Class "letter" consists of letters and characters denoting accents
; in order to cope with "sigma finalis", i.e., A-Z a-z ` ' > < ~
; we don't need the double quote because it goes only after a vowel
UniClass[letter] = ( U+0041..U+005A U+0061..U+007A U+0060 U+0027 U+003E U+003C U+007E )


; ligatures from Knuth's original CMR fonts
U+002D U+002D <> U+2013 ; -- -> en dash
U+002D U+002D U+002D <> U+2014 ; --- -> em dash

; Greek (according to C. Beccari conventions)

; (-1)
U+0022 <> U+2019 ; APOSTROPHE
U+0060 U+0060 <> U+201C ; `` -> LEFT DOUBLE QUOTATION MARK
U+0027 U+0027 <> U+201D ; '' -> RIGHT DOUBLE QUOTATION MARK
U+003C U+003C <> U+00AB ; << -> LEFT-POINTING DOUBLE ANGLE QUOTATION MARK
U+003E U+003E <> U+00BB ; >> -> RIGHT-POINTING DOUBLE ANGLE QUOTATION MARK
U+0028 U+0028 <> U+00AB ; (( -> LEFT-POINTING DOUBLE ANGLE QUOTATION MARK
U+0029 U+0029 <> U+00BB ; )) -> RIGHT-POINTING DOUBLE ANGLE QUOTATION MARK

; (0) basic letters
; uppercase
U+0041 <> U+0391 
U+0042 <> U+0392 
U+0044 <> U+0394 
U+0045 <> U+0395 
U+0046 <> U+03A6 
U+0047 <> U+0393 
U+0048 <> U+0397 
U+0049 <> U+0399 
U+004A <> U+0398 
U+004B <> U+039A 
U+004C <> U+039B 
U+004D <> U+039C 
U+004E <> U+039D 
U+004F <> U+039F 
U+0050 <> U+03A0 
U+0051 <> U+03A7 
U+0052 <> U+03A1 
U+0053 <> U+03A3 
U+0054 <> U+03A4 
U+0055 <> U+03A5 
U+0057 <> U+03A9 
U+0058 <> U+039E 
U+0059 <> U+03A8 
U+005A <> U+0396 
; lowercase
U+0061 <> U+03B1 
U+0062 <> U+03B2 
U+0063 <> U+03C2 
U+0064 <> U+03B4 
U+0065 <> U+03B5 
U+0066 <> U+03C6 
U+0067 <> U+03B3 
U+0068 <> U+03B7 
U+0069 <> U+03B9 
U+006A <> U+03B8 
U+006B <> U+03BA 
U+006C <> U+03BB 
U+006D <> U+03BC 
U+006E <> U+03BD 
U+006F <> U+03BF 
U+0070 <> U+03C0 
U+0071 <> U+03C7 
U+0072 <> U+03C1 
U+0073 <> U+03C3 
U+0073 / _ ^[letter] <> U+03C2 
U+0074 <> U+03C4 
U+0075 <> U+03C5 
U+0077 <> U+03C9 
U+0078 <> U+03BE 
U+0079 <> U+03C8 
U+007A <> U+03B6 

; (1) ` + letter -> varia
U+0060 U+0041 <> U+1FBA 
U+0060 U+0061 <> U+1F70 
U+0060 U+0045 <> U+1FC8 
U+0060 U+0065 <> U+1F72 
U+0060 U+0048 <> U+1FCA 
U+0060 U+0068 <> U+1F74 
U+0060 U+0049 <> U+1FDA 
U+0060 U+0069 <> U+1F76 
U+0060 U+004F <> U+1FF8 
U+0060 U+006F <> U+1F78 
U+0060 U+0055 <> U+1FEA 
U+0060 U+0075 <> U+1F7A 
U+0060 U+0057 <> U+1FFA 
U+0060 U+0077 <> U+1F7C 

; (2) ' + letter -> oxia
U+0027 U+0041 <> U+1FBB 
U+0027 U+0061 <> U+1F71 
U+0027 U+0045 <> U+1FC9 
U+0027 U+0065 <> U+1F73 
U+0027 U+0048 <> U+1FCB 
U+0027 U+0068 <> U+1F75 
U+0027 U+0049 <> U+1FDB 
U+0027 U+0069 <> U+1F77 
U+0027 U+004F <> U+1FF9 
U+0027 U+006F <> U+1F79 
U+0027 U+0055 <> U+1FEB 
U+0027 U+0075 <> U+1F7B 
U+0027 U+0057 <> U+1FFB 
U+0027 U+0077 <> U+1F7D 

; (3) > + letter -> psili
U+003E U+0041 <> U+1F08 
U+003E U+0061 <> U+1F00 
U+003E U+0045 <> U+1F18 
U+003E U+0065 <> U+1F10 
U+003E U+0048 <> U+1F28 
U+003E U+0068 <> U+1F20 
U+003E U+0049 <> U+1F38 
U+003E U+0069 <> U+1F30 
U+003E U+004F <> U+1F48 
U+003E U+006F <> U+1F40 
U+003E U+0055 <> U+1FBF U+03A5 
U+003E U+0075 <> U+1F50 
U+003E U+0057 <> U+1F68 
U+003E U+0077 <> U+1F60 

; (4) < + letter -> dasia
U+003C U+0041 <> U+1F09 
U+003C U+0061 <> U+1F01 
U+003C U+0045 <> U+1F19 
U+003C U+0065 <> U+1F11 
U+003C U+0048 <> U+1F29 
U+003C U+0068 <> U+1F21 
U+003C U+0049 <> U+1F39 
U+003C U+0069 <> U+1F31 
U+003C U+004F <> U+1F49 
U+003C U+006F <> U+1F41 
U+003C U+0055 <> U+1F59 
U+003C U+0075 <> U+1F51 
U+003C U+0057 <> U+1F69 
U+003C U+0077 <> U+1F61 

; (5) >` + letter -> psili and varia
U+003E U+0060 U+0041 <> U+1F0A 
U+003E U+0060 U+0061 <> U+1F02 
U+003E U+0060 U+0045 <> U+1F1A 
U+003E U+0060 U+0065 <> U+1F12 
U+003E U+0060 U+0048 <> U+1F2A 
U+003E U+0060 U+0068 <> U+1F22 
U+003E U+0060 U+0049 <> U+1F3A 
U+003E U+0060 U+0069 <> U+1F32 
U+003E U+0060 U+004F <> U+1F4A 
U+003E U+0060 U+006F <> U+1F42 
U+003E U+0060 U+0055 <> U+1FCD U+03A5 
U+003E U+0060 U+0075 <> U+1F52 
U+003E U+0060 U+0057 <> U+1F6A 
U+003E U+0060 U+0077 <> U+1F62 

; (6) `> + letter -> psili and varia
U+0060 U+003E U+0041 <> U+1F0A 
U+0060 U+003E U+0061 <> U+1F02 
U+0060 U+003E U+0045 <> U+1F1A 
U+0060 U+003E U+0065 <> U+1F12 
U+0060 U+003E U+0048 <> U+1F2A 
U+0060 U+003E U+0068 <> U+1F22 
U+0060 U+003E U+0049 <> U+1F3A 
U+0060 U+003E U+0069 <> U+1F32 
U+0060 U+003E U+004F <> U+1F4A 
U+0060 U+003E U+006F <> U+1F42 
U+0060 U+003E U+0055 <> U+1FCD U+03A5 
U+0060 U+003E U+0075 <> U+1F52 
U+0060 U+003E U+0057 <> U+1F6A 
U+0060 U+003E U+0077 <> U+1F62 

; (7) >' + letter -> psili and oxia
U+003E U+0027 U+0041 <> U+1F0C 
U+003E U+0027 U+0061 <> U+1F04 
U+003E U+0027 U+0045 <> U+1F1C 
U+003E U+0027 U+0065 <> U+1F14 
U+003E U+0027 U+0048 <> U+1F2C 
U+003E U+0027 U+0068 <> U+1F24 
U+003E U+0027 U+0049 <> U+1F3C 
U+003E U+0027 U+0069 <> U+1F34 
U+003E U+0027 U+004F <> U+1F4C 
U+003E U+0027 U+006F <> U+1F44 
U+003E U+0027 U+0055 <> U+1FCE U+03A5 
U+003E U+0027 U+0075 <> U+1F54 
U+003E U+0027 U+0057 <> U+1F6C 
U+003E U+0027 U+0077 <> U+1F64 

; (8) '> + letter -> psili and oxia
U+0027 U+003E U+0041 <> U+1F0C 
U+0027 U+003E U+0061 <> U+1F04 
U+0027 U+003E U+0045 <> U+1F1C 
U+0027 U+003E U+0065 <> U+1F14 
U+0027 U+003E U+0048 <> U+1F2C 
U+0027 U+003E U+0068 <> U+1F24 
U+0027 U+003E U+0049 <> U+1F3C 
U+0027 U+003E U+0069 <> U+1F34 
U+0027 U+003E U+004F <> U+1F4C 
U+0027 U+003E U+006F <> U+1F44 
U+0027 U+003E U+0055 <> U+1FCE U+03A5 
U+0027 U+003E U+0075 <> U+1F54 
U+0027 U+003E U+0057 <> U+1F6C 
U+0027 U+003E U+0077 <> U+1F64 

; (9) <` + letter -> dasia and varia
U+003C U+0060 U+0041 <> U+1F0B 
U+003C U+0060 U+0061 <> U+1F03 
U+003C U+0060 U+0045 <> U+1F1B 
U+003C U+0060 U+0065 <> U+1F13 
U+003C U+0060 U+0048 <> U+1F2B 
U+003C U+0060 U+0068 <> U+1F23 
U+003C U+0060 U+0049 <> U+1F3B 
U+003C U+0060 U+0069 <> U+1F33 
U+003C U+0060 U+004F <> U+1F4B 
U+003C U+0060 U+006F <> U+1F43 
U+003C U+0060 U+0055 <> U+1F5B 
U+003C U+0060 U+0075 <> U+1F53 
U+003C U+0060 U+0057 <> U+1F6B 
U+003C U+0060 U+0077 <> U+1F63 

; (10) `< + letter -> dasia and varia
U+0060 U+003C U+0041 <> U+1F0B 
U+0060 U+003C U+0061 <> U+1F03 
U+0060 U+003C U+0045 <> U+1F1B 
U+0060 U+003C U+0065 <> U+1F13 
U+0060 U+003C U+0048 <> U+1F2B 
U+0060 U+003C U+0068 <> U+1F23 
U+0060 U+003C U+0049 <> U+1F3B 
U+0060 U+003C U+0069 <> U+1F33 
U+0060 U+003C U+004F <> U+1F4B 
U+0060 U+003C U+006F <> U+1F43 
U+0060 U+003C U+0055 <> U+1F5B 
U+0060 U+003C U+0075 <> U+1F53 
U+0060 U+003C U+0057 <> U+1F6B 
U+0060 U+003C U+0077 <> U+1F63 

; (11) <' + letter -> dasia and oxia
U+003C U+0027 U+0041 <> U+1F0D 
U+003C U+0027 U+0061 <> U+1F05 
U+003C U+0027 U+0045 <> U+1F1D 
U+003C U+0027 U+0065 <> U+1F15 
U+003C U+0027 U+0048 <> U+1F2D 
U+003C U+0027 U+0068 <> U+1F25 
U+003C U+0027 U+0049 <> U+1F3D 
U+003C U+0027 U+0069 <> U+1F35 
U+003C U+0027 U+004F <> U+1F4D 
U+003C U+0027 U+006F <> U+1F45 
U+003C U+0027 U+0055 <> U+1F5D 
U+003C U+0027 U+0075 <> U+1F55 
U+003C U+0027 U+0057 <> U+1F6D 
U+003C U+0027 U+0077 <> U+1F65 

; (12) '< + letter -> dasia and oxia
U+0027 U+003C U+0041 <> U+1F0D 
U+0027 U+003C U+0061 <> U+1F05 
U+0027 U+003C U+0045 <> U+1F1D 
U+0027 U+003C U+0065 <> U+1F15 
U+0027 U+003C U+0048 <> U+1F2D 
U+0027 U+003C U+0068 <> U+1F25 
U+0027 U+003C U+0049 <> U+1F3D 
U+0027 U+003C U+0069 <> U+1F35 
U+0027 U+003C U+004F <> U+1F4D 
U+0027 U+003C U+006F <> U+1F45 
U+0027 U+003C U+0055 <> U+1F5D 
U+0027 U+003C U+0075 <> U+1F55 
U+0027 U+003C U+0057 <> U+1F6D 
U+0027 U+003C U+0077 <> U+1F65 

; (13) ~ + letter -> perispomeni
U+007E U+0041 <> U+0391 U+0342 
U+007E U+0061 <> U+1FB6 
U+007E U+0048 <> U+0397 U+0342 
U+007E U+0068 <> U+1FC6 
U+007E U+0049 <> U+0399 U+0342 
U+007E U+0069 <> U+1FD6 
U+007E U+0055 <> U+03A5 U+0342 
U+007E U+0075 <> U+1FE6 
U+007E U+0057 <> U+03A9 U+0342 
U+007E U+0077 <> U+1FF6 

; (14) >~ + letter -> psili and perispomeni
U+003E U+007E U+0041 <> U+1F0E 
U+003E U+007E U+0061 <> U+1F06 
U+003E U+007E U+0048 <> U+1F2E 
U+003E U+007E U+0068 <> U+1F26 
U+003E U+007E U+0049 <> U+1F3E 
U+003E U+007E U+0069 <> U+1F36 
U+003E U+007E U+0055 <> U+1FCF U+03A5 
U+003E U+007E U+0075 <> U+1F56 
U+003E U+007E U+0057 <> U+1F6E 
U+003E U+007E U+0077 <> U+1F66 

; (15) >~ + letter + | -> psili and perispomeni and ypogegrammeni
U+003E U+007E U+0041 U+007C <> U+1F0E U+0345  
U+003E U+007E U+0061 U+007C <> U+1F06 U+0345  
U+003E U+007E U+0048 U+007C <> U+1F2E U+0345  
U+003E U+007E U+0068 U+007C <> U+1F26 U+0345  
U+003E U+007E U+0057 U+007C <> U+1F6E U+0345  
U+003E U+007E U+0077 U+007C <> U+1F66 U+0345  

; (16) ~> + letter -> psili and perispomeni
U+007E U+003E U+0041 <> U+1F0E 
U+007E U+003E U+0061 <> U+1F06 
U+007E U+003E U+0048 <> U+1F2E 
U+007E U+003E U+0068 <> U+1F26 
U+007E U+003E U+0049 <> U+1F3E 
U+007E U+003E U+0069 <> U+1F36 
U+007E U+003E U+0055 <> U+1FCF U+03A5 
U+007E U+003E U+0075 <> U+1F56 
U+007E U+003E U+0057 <> U+1F6E 
U+007E U+003E U+0077 <> U+1F66 

; (17) ~> + letter + | -> psili and perispomeni and ypogegrammeni
U+007E U+003E U+0041 U+007C <> U+1F0E U+0345  
U+007E U+003E U+0061 U+007C <> U+1F06 U+0345  
U+007E U+003E U+0048 U+007C <> U+1F2E U+0345  
U+007E U+003E U+0068 U+007C <> U+1F26 U+0345  
U+007E U+003E U+0057 U+007C <> U+1F6E U+0345  
U+007E U+003E U+0077 U+007C <> U+1F66 U+0345  

; (18) <~ + letter -> dasia and perispomeni
U+003C U+007E U+0041 <> U+1F0F 
U+003C U+007E U+0061 <> U+1F07 
U+003C U+007E U+0048 <> U+1F2F 
U+003C U+007E U+0068 <> U+1F27 
U+003C U+007E U+0049 <> U+1F3F 
U+003C U+007E U+0069 <> U+1F37 
U+003C U+007E U+0055 <> U+1F5F 
U+003C U+007E U+0075 <> U+1F57 
U+003C U+007E U+0057 <> U+1F6F 
U+003C U+007E U+0077 <> U+1F67 

; (19) <~ + letter + | -> dasia and perispomeni and ypogegrammeni
U+003C U+007E U+0041 U+007C <> U+1F0F U+0345  
U+003C U+007E U+0061 U+007C <> U+1F07 U+0345  
U+003C U+007E U+0048 U+007C <> U+1F2F U+0345  
U+003C U+007E U+0068 U+007C <> U+1F27 U+0345  
U+003C U+007E U+0057 U+007C <> U+1F6F U+0345  
U+003C U+007E U+0077 U+007C <> U+1F67 U+0345  

; (20) ~< + letter -> dasia and perispomeni
U+007E U+003C U+0041 <> U+1F0F 
U+007E U+003C U+0061 <> U+1F07 
U+007E U+003C U+0048 <> U+1F2F 
U+007E U+003C U+0068 <> U+1F27 
U+007E U+003C U+0049 <> U+1F3F 
U+007E U+003C U+0069 <> U+1F37 
U+007E U+003C U+0055 <> U+1F5F 
U+007E U+003C U+0075 <> U+1F57 
U+007E U+003C U+0057 <> U+1F6F 
U+007E U+003C U+0077 <> U+1F67 

; (21) ~< + letter + | -> dasia and perispomeni and ypogegrammeni
U+007E U+003C U+0041 U+007C <> U+1F0F U+0345  
U+007E U+003C U+0061 U+007C <> U+1F07 U+0345  
U+007E U+003C U+0048 U+007C <> U+1F2F U+0345  
U+007E U+003C U+0068 U+007C <> U+1F27 U+0345  
U+007E U+003C U+0057 U+007C <> U+1F6F U+0345  
U+007E U+003C U+0077 U+007C <> U+1F67 U+0345  

; (22) letter + | -> ypogegrammeni
U+0041 U+007C <> U+1FBC 
U+0061 U+007C <> U+1FB3 
U+0048 U+007C <> U+1FCC 
U+0068 U+007C <> U+1FC3 
U+0057 U+007C <> U+1FFC 
U+0077 U+007C <> U+1FF3 

; (23) ` + letter + | -> varia and ypogegrammeni
U+0060 U+0061 U+007C <> U+1FB2 
U+0060 U+0068 U+007C <> U+1FC2 
U+0060 U+0077 U+007C <> U+1FF2 

; (24) ' + letter + | -> oxia and ypogegrammeni
U+0027 U+0061 U+007C <> U+1FB2 
U+0027 U+0068 U+007C <> U+1FC2 
U+0027 U+0077 U+007C <> U+1FF2 

; (25) ~ + letter + | -> perispomeni and ypogegrammeni
U+007E U+0061 U+007C <> U+1FB7 
U+007E U+0068 U+007C <> U+1FC7 
U+007E U+0077 U+007C <> U+1FF7 

; (26) > + letter + | -> psili and ypogegrammeni
U+003E U+0041 U+007C <> U+1F88 
U+003E U+0061 U+007C <> U+1F80 
U+003E U+0048 U+007C <> U+1F98 
U+003E U+0068 U+007C <> U+1F90 
U+003E U+0057 U+007C <> U+1FA8 
U+003E U+0077 U+007C <> U+1FA0 

; (27) >` + letter + | -> psili and varia and ypogegrammeni
U+003E U+0060 U+0041 U+007C <> U+1F8A 
U+003E U+0060 U+0061 U+007C <> U+1F82 
U+003E U+0060 U+0048 U+007C <> U+1F9A 
U+003E U+0060 U+0068 U+007C <> U+1F92 
U+003E U+0060 U+0057 U+007C <> U+1FAA 
U+003E U+0060 U+0077 U+007C <> U+1FA2 

; (28) `> + letter + | -> psili and varia and ypogegrammeni
U+0060 U+003E U+0041 U+007C <> U+1F8A 
U+0060 U+003E U+0061 U+007C <> U+1F82 
U+0060 U+003E U+0048 U+007C <> U+1F9A 
U+0060 U+003E U+0068 U+007C <> U+1F92 
U+0060 U+003E U+0057 U+007C <> U+1FAA 
U+0060 U+003E U+0077 U+007C <> U+1FA2 

; (29) >' + letter + | -> psili and oxia and ypogegrammeni
U+003E U+0027 U+0041 U+007C <> U+1F8C 
U+003E U+0027 U+0061 U+007C <> U+1F84 
U+003E U+0027 U+0048 U+007C <> U+1F9C 
U+003E U+0027 U+0068 U+007C <> U+1F94 
U+003E U+0027 U+0057 U+007C <> U+1FAC 
U+003E U+0027 U+0077 U+007C <> U+1FA4 

; (30) '> + letter + | -> psili and oxia and ypogegrammeni
U+0027 U+003E U+0041 U+007C <> U+1F8C 
U+0027 U+003E U+0061 U+007C <> U+1F84 
U+0027 U+003E U+0048 U+007C <> U+1F9C 
U+0027 U+003E U+0068 U+007C <> U+1F94 
U+0027 U+003E U+0057 U+007C <> U+1FAC 
U+0027 U+003E U+0077 U+007C <> U+1FA4 

; (31) < + letter + | -> dasia and ypogegrammeni
U+003C U+0041 U+007C <> U+1F89 
U+003C U+0061 U+007C <> U+1F81 
U+003C U+0048 U+007C <> U+1F99 
U+003C U+0068 U+007C <> U+1F91 
U+003C U+0057 U+007C <> U+1FA9 
U+003C U+0077 U+007C <> U+1FA1 

; (32) <` + letter + | -> dasia and varia and ypogegrammeni
U+003C U+0060 U+0041 U+007C <> U+1F8B 
U+003C U+0060 U+0061 U+007C <> U+1F83 
U+003C U+0060 U+0048 U+007C <> U+1F9B 
U+003C U+0060 U+0068 U+007C <> U+1F93 
U+003C U+0060 U+0057 U+007C <> U+1FAB 
U+003C U+0060 U+0077 U+007C <> U+1FA3 

; (33) `< + letter + | -> dasia and varia and ypogegrammeni
U+0060 U+003C U+0041 U+007C <> U+1F8B 
U+0060 U+003C U+0061 U+007C <> U+1F83 
U+0060 U+003C U+0048 U+007C <> U+1F9B 
U+0060 U+003C U+0068 U+007C <> U+1F93 
U+0060 U+003C U+0057 U+007C <> U+1FAB 
U+0060 U+003C U+0077 U+007C <> U+1FA3 

; (34) <' + letter + | -> dasia and oxia and ypogegrammeni
U+003C U+0027 U+0041 U+007C <> U+1F8D 
U+003C U+0027 U+0061 U+007C <> U+1F85 
U+003C U+0027 U+0048 U+007C <> U+1F9D 
U+003C U+0027 U+0068 U+007C <> U+1F95 
U+003C U+0027 U+0057 U+007C <> U+1FAD 
U+003C U+0027 U+0077 U+007C <> U+1FA5 

; (35) '< + letter + | -> dasia and oxia and ypogegrammeni
U+0027 U+003C U+0041 U+007C <> U+1F8D 
U+0027 U+003C U+0061 U+007C <> U+1F85 
U+0027 U+003C U+0048 U+007C <> U+1F9D 
U+0027 U+003C U+0068 U+007C <> U+1F95 
U+0027 U+003C U+0057 U+007C <> U+1FAD 
U+0027 U+003C U+0077 U+007C <> U+1FA5 

; (36) " + letter -> dialytika
U+0022 U+0049 <> U+03AA 
U+0022 U+0069 <> U+03CA 
U+0022 U+0055 <> U+03AB 
U+0022 U+0075 <> U+03CB 

; (37) "' + letter -> dialytika and oxia
U+0022 U+0027 U+0069 <> U+1FD3 
U+0022 U+0027 U+0075 <> U+1FE3 

; (38) '" + letter -> dialytika and oxia
U+0027 U+0022 U+0069 <> U+1FD3 
U+0027 U+0022 U+0075 <> U+1FE3 

; (39) "` + letter -> dialytika and varia
U+0022 U+0060 U+0069 <> U+1FD2 
U+0022 U+0060 U+0075 <> U+1FE2 

; (40) `" + letter -> dialytika and varia
U+0060 U+0022 U+0069 <> U+1FD2 
U+0060 U+0022 U+0075 <> U+1FE2 

; (41) "~ + letter -> dialytika and perispomeni
U+0022 U+007E U+0069 <> U+1FD7 
U+0022 U+007E U+0075 <> U+1FE7 

; (42) ~" + letter -> dialytika and perispomeni
U+007E U+0022 U+0069 <> U+1FD7 
U+007E U+0022 U+0075 <> U+1FE7 

; (43) rho, medial sigma and punctuation
; >r
U+003E U+0072 <> U+1FE4 
; <R
U+003C U+0052 <> U+1FEC 
; <r
U+003C U+0072 <> U+1FE5 
; medial sigma (sv)
U+0073 U+0076 <> U+03C3 
; question mark
U+003F <> U+037E 
; semicolon
U+003B <> U+0387
```

This solves the problem:

`\texttransgreek{<'ina >~h|s}`

leads to:

`ἵνα ᾖς`