# How to use a different font for a specific language with XeTeX?

Tags: fonts, xetex, languages

I am trying to set a specific font for polutonikogreek. To make it easy to switch to that language, I defined the following command:

```
\newfontfamily{\Vusillus}[]{Vusillus Old Face}
\newcommand{\greek}[1]{{%
\Vusillus\selectlanguage{polutonikogreek}#1%
}}
```

But when I try something like this:

```
\greek{>erot'aw}
```

the font Vusillus Old Face isn't used, while this:

```
\Vusillus Something without a meaning
```

works well. Am I missing something?

Here an working example:

```
\documentclass[10pt,twoside]{memoir}
\usepackage[english,greek,polutonikogreek,ngerman,german]{babel}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} 
\usepackage{scrpage2}

% rubber: set program xelatex

\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{xltxtra}
\setmainfont[Numbers={OldStyle},Ligatures={Common, Historic}]{Adobe Garamond Pro}

\newfontfamily{\Vusillus}[]{Vusillus Old Face}
\newcommand{\greek}[1]{{%
\Vusillus\selectlanguage{polutonikogreek}#1%
}}

\begin{document}
Das ist nur ein Flie{\ss}text, sonst nichts: {\greek{>erot'aw}} und {\greek{>'erowc}}.
As you may have noticed the greek words are not in Vusillus, but \Vusillus this text actually is.
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can't do that way. With `babel`, the `\greek` command switches to an internal font encoding that's not understood by OpenType fonts (see later for more information).

With Polyglossia you can define a `\greekfont` that will do as you want, provided you input the Greek text using the actual characters.

```
\documentclass[10pt,twoside]{memoir}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setmainlanguage[spelling=new]{german}
\setotherlanguage[variant=polytonic]{greek}
\setotherlanguage{english}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont[Ligatures=TeX]{Hoefler Text}

\newfontfamily{\greekfont}[Ligatures=TeX]{Old Standard}

\begin{document}

Das ist nur ein Flie{\ss}text, sonst nichts: 
\textgreek{ἐροτάω} und \textgreek{ἔροως}.

\begin{otherlanguage*}{english}
As you may have noticed the greek words \emph{are} in Old Standard,
like \greekfont this text actually is.
\end{otherlanguage*}

\end{document}
```

Note that `inputenc` must not be used with XeLaTeX. I simplified the language calls and used fonts I have on my system.

[image]

What about entering Greek text with the old transliteration scheme? See [How to insert Greek with "ascii keyboard" and XeTeX, Polyglossia](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/30829/how-to-insert-greek-with-ascii-keyboard-and-xetex-polyglossia)

After building the `asciitogreek.tec` file following the instructions, the input can become

```
\documentclass[10pt,twoside]{memoir}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setmainlanguage[spelling=new]{german}
\setotherlanguage[variant=polytonic]{greek}
\setotherlanguage{english}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont[Ligatures=TeX]{Hoefler Text}

\newfontfamily{\greekfont}[Mapping=asciitogreek]{Old Standard}

\begin{document}

Das ist nur ein Flie{\ss}text, sonst nichts: 
\textgreek{>erot'aw} und \textgreek{>'erowc}.

\begin{otherlanguage*}{english}
As you may have noticed the greek words \emph{are} in Old Standard,
like \greekfont this text actually is.
\end{otherlanguage*}

\end{document}
```

Of course also text after `\greekfont` will be transliterated (I left it just by way of example). You can also use direct input of Greek characters.

[image]

Actually there is a problem with `~`, see the linked answer for a workaround.

Comment: Ereg, you are my hero! I used the first variant, and it work's perfect!