# Why doesn't \vDash work?

Tags: mathtools

I am trying to set some logical expressions, but unfortunately I cant get the command `\vDash` working. What am I missing?

```
\documentclass[10pt,twoside]{memoir}
\usepackage[english,german]{babel}
\usepackage{polyglossia} % Vgl. http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/135185
\setmainlanguage[spelling=old,babelshorthands=true,script=latin]{english}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont[Numbers={OldStyle},Ligatures={Common, Historic}]{Adobe Garamond Pro}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\begin{document}

\begin{english}

$ A,\neg A \vDash B $

\end{english}
\end{document}
```

Comment: There seem to be a lot of `\vDash` and similar commands, especially in package `\mathabx`. If that is not included automatically by `mathtools`, you have to do it manually.

Comment: `\usepackage{amssymb}` is necessary. However, `mathtools` should be loaded before `fontspec` and loading both `babel` and `polyglossia` doesn't make sense.

Comment: If you are typesetting symbolic logic, you should look at `turnstile`. To get everything looking right, you also need to adjust the spacing of some things because symbols are sometimes used differently (e.g. the spacing of a unary operator should not be the same as that of a binary one). But this is less of a problem if you use `\neg` rather than the tilde for negation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Surely, apart from anything else, you need to be loading the principal AMS packages before adding the supplementary math tools. Try, for a start, adding `\usepackage{amssymb}`