# Problem with Polyglossia setting \textgreek after update to TeX Live 2018

Tags: xetex, polyglossia, greek

I used to set an specific font for greek text using [polyglossia](https://ctan.org/pkg/polyglossia) with `\newfontfamily{\textgreek}[Ligatures=TeX]{Vusillus Old Face}`.

After I updated to TeX Live 2018 all my documents wouldn't compile anymore throwing the error:

> LaTeX error: "xparse/command-already-defined" Command '\textgreek' already defined! For immediate help type H .

This is truly unfortunate, because that means the update breaks compatibility to a couple of hundred of my documents. However, my questions are:

1. What happened in polyglossia, that I cant use the above mentioned
   command anymore, to set the font for a specific language?
2. How am I supposed to do this now?
3. How could I make my old documents compile again the easiest way?

By the way, I am using polyglossia due to its compatibility with XeLaTeX. Here is a minimal not working example:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt,twoside]{memoir}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setmainlanguage[spelling=old,babelshorthands=true,script=latin]{german}
\setotherlanguage[variant=polytonic]{greek}
\newfontfamily{\textgreek}[Ligatures=TeX]{Vusillus Old Face}

\begin{document}
textgreek{πάντα ῥεῖ} – Alles fließt.
\end{document}
```

Comment: the `\text<language>` commands are defined by polyglossia to define language switches, so you shouldn't define them to be font commands,

Comment: `fontspec` changed the behaviour of `\newfontfamily{\cmd}` recently, earlier the command would not check if `\cmd` was already defined, it would simply overwrite the command. Now `\newfontfamily{\cmd}` checks if `\cmd` is defined and errors if that is the case. Since `polyglossia` defines `\textgreek` you get an error now.

Comment: Use `\newfontfamily{\greekfont}` to specify a font for Greek text.

Comment: `\textgreek` is (and has always been) a bad name for a font family selection command, because generally `\text...` commands require an argument, whereas the syntax for choosing a font family defined with `\newfontfamily{\foo}{Font}` is `{\foo text}`, not `\foo{text}`.

Comment: Also probably a good idea to set `Scale=` on font families loaded with `fontspec`, or as a default feature.

Comment: And yes, that definition of `\textgreek` probably caused the new font to bleed over?

Comment: @Davislor I guess that I originally had it done correctly with `\newfontfamily{\greekfont}` as @egreg suggest here: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/135185. But than at some point the bad name `\textgreek` sneaked into my style. I never had any problems though. Everything looked quite good. So I didn't notice I did something wrong.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`fontspec` recently changed the behaviour of `\newfontfamily`. `\newfontfamily<cmd>` now throws an error if `<cmd>` is defined. Earlier `\newfontfamily` would behave like `\setfontfamily` behaves now. It would simply overwrite the old definition of the command. (See p. 9 of the [`fontspec` documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/fontspec/fontspec.pdf)).

As David Carlisle explains in the comments `\textgreek` is a command defined by `polyglossia` to typeset Greek. (`polyglossia` defines `\text<language>` for all loaded languages. See also p. 5 of the [`polyglossia` documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/polyglossia/polyglossia.pdf).)

So when you get to

```
\newfontfamily{\textgreek}[Ligatures=TeX]{Vusillus Old Face}
```

new versions of `fontspec` throw an error, because `\textgreek` is already defined. Older version of `fontspec` will have overwritten `polyglossia`'s definition of `\textgreek`, which probably meant that you did not actually get proper language switching.

The correct way to specify the font for Greek is by redefining `\greekfont`. See also pp. 6-7 of the [`polyglossia` documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/polyglossia/polyglossia.pdf).

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt,twoside]{memoir}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setmainlanguage[spelling=old,babelshorthands=true,script=latin]{german}
\setotherlanguage[variant=polytonic]{greek}
\newfontfamily{\greekfont}[Ligatures=TeX]{Linux Libertine O}

\begin{document}
\textgreek{πάντα ῥεῖ} – Alles fließt.
\end{document}
```

You could also use `babel` instead of `polyglossia`. `babel` supports LuaLaTeX and XeLaTeX and is actively being developed. (`polyglossia` development seems to have stalled recently.) For western languages with Latin scripts `polyglossia` is barely better than `babel`. For Greek  `babel` also gives very good results. Even for RTL languages recent `babel` development looks very promising.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt,twoside]{memoir}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage[polutonikogreek,german]{babel}
\babelfont{rm}{Latin Modern Roman}
\babelfont[polutonikogreek]{rm}{Linux Libertine O}

\begin{document}
\foreignlanguage{polutonikogreek}{πάντα ῥεῖ} – Alles fließt.
\end{document}
```

The output of both examples is the same

[image: πάντα ῥεῖ – Alles fließt.]

Comment: @egreg makes an important point in the comments under the question. With `\setfontfamily\textgreek` the font will leak out and change everything in the current group since font families are defined as switches and not macros. Which means that `\textgreek{πάντα ῥεῖ} – Alles fließt.` with older `fontspec` or `\setfontfamily` would also change the font of 'Alles fließt', while in the MWE of the answer the font is not changed and stays Latin Modern.