# Installing Hieroglyph Package

Tags: fonts

I am a new Latex user with little programming knowledge. I have downloaded the hieroglyph package and unzipped the two files. The installation instructions list a path where to place MF and AUXMF folders. My problem is that I cannot find either folder in the unzipped files. What don't I understand about this instruction and how do I proceed from this point?

Thank you for responding. Any help is greatly appreciated. I  downloaded HieroTex-3.5.tgz, HieroType1-3.1.4.tgz, LIEZMOI, and README from CTAN Tex-archive fonts hieroglyph. I am using MiKTeX 2.9 with TeXstudio 2.12.4.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Please elaborate on what you did. Which files did you download from which source?

Comment: Thank you for responding. Any help is greatly appreciated. I downloaded HieroTex-3.5.tgz, HieroType1-3.1.4.tgz, LIEZMOI, and README from CTAN Tex-archive fonts hieroglyph. I am using MiKTeX 2.9 with TeXstudio 2.12.4 @TeXnician

Answer (score 4):

The steps are:

1. Put sesh.exe somewhere visible to your operating system (I made a new folder and put the folder name into the `path` environmental variable (on Windows machine))
2. Put everything in the two `texmf` folders into your local texmf tree (I made a texmf folder, and copied the folders in; then, because this was the first time using a local texmf tree, in MiKTeX Console, under `Settings`, `Directories`, added in the texmf folder)
3. Refresh the file name data base, and refresh font map files (in MiKTeX Console, under `Tasks`)
4. Try the test file, call it `foo.htx`:

   ```
   \documentclass[12pt]{article}
   \usepackage{egypto}
   \usepackage[psfonts]{hiero}
   \begin{document}
   \begin{hieroglyph}
   A1 \end{hieroglyph}
   \end{document}
   ```

It turns out that Sesh.exe is a pre-processor that converts Gardiner Numbers (like `A1`) into hierotex code (`\leavevmode \loneSign{\Aca GA/32/`), which includes layout, positioning, direction and scaling.

Sesh uses stdin and stdout, so command-line compilation looks like this, including the input and output arrows:

```
sesh < foo.htx > foo.tex
latex foo.tex
```

I wasn't able to install the PS and Type1 fonts properly (old-style, non-Unicode font installation is a bugbear!) - and got as far as on the latex run as `maketfm` failing because there's a Hier.cfg file that it couldn't find.

**Alternative**

Easier for me at the moment to use a Unicode font (like `Noto Sans Egyptian Hieroglyphs`) and raw Tikz, with manual positioning and scaling, like so:

[image: Example hieroglyph placement using TikZ]

MWE

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning, arrows, fit}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{graphicx}
%\setmainfont{Minion Pro}
%\setmainfont{Times New Roman}
%\setmainfont{CMU Serif}
\setmainfont{Old Standard}
\newfontface\egyfe{Noto Sans Egyptian Hieroglyphs}
\newfontface\egym[Mapping=gardnernum-to-hieroglyph]{Noto Sans Egyptian Hieroglyphs}%Code2003}

\newfontface\egyn[Mapping=gardnernum-to-hieroglyph2,Color=blue]{Noto Sans Egyptian Hieroglyphs}



\DeclareTextFontCommand{\texthg}{\egym}
\DeclareTextFontCommand{\texthi}{\huge\egyn}


\expandafter\newcommand\csname A001\endcsname{\symbol{"13000}}


\newenvironment{thiero}
  {\egym\huge\ignorespaces}
  {\ignorespacesafterend}
  
%uniliteral  
\newcommand\eha{{\egym G001}}
\newcommand\ehaa{{\egym D036}}\newcommand\ehb{{\egym D058}}
\newcommand\ehd{{\egym D046}}
%\newcommand\ehf{{\egym I009}}
\newcommand\ehg{{\egym W011}}
%\newcommand\ehh{{\egym N028}}
\newcommand\ehh{{\egym O004}}
\newcommand\ehH{{\egym V028}}\newcommand\ehi{{\egym M017}}
\newcommand\ehii{{\egym N018}}
\newcommand\ehj{{\egym I010}}
\newcommand\ehk{{\egym V031}}
\newcommand\ehl{{\egym E023}}
\newcommand\ehm{{\egym G017}}
\newcommand\ehmm{{\egym G018}}
\newcommand\ehn{{\egym N035}}
\newcommand\eho{{\egym V004}}
\newcommand\ehnn{{\egym S003}}
\newcommand\ehp{{\egym Q003}}
\newcommand\ehq{{\egym O040}}
\newcommand\ehqq{{\egym N029}}
%\newcommand\ehr{{\egym N005}}
\newcommand\ehr{{\egym D021}}
\newcommand\ehs{{\egym S029}}%voiceless
\newcommand\ehsh{{\egym N039}}
\newcommand\eht{{\egym X001}}
\newcommand\ehch{{\egym V013}}\newcommand\ehw{{\egym G043}}
\newcommand\ehX{{\egym AA001}}
\newcommand\ehy{{\egym M017A}}
\newcommand\ehz{{\egym O034}}

\newcommand\ehlaw{{\egym U038}}



\usetikzlibrary{backgrounds, shapes, arrows}


\newcommand\ehrtllion{\color{blue}{\scalebox{-2.8}[2.8]{\ehl}}}

\newcommand\ehbo{below of}
\newcommand\ehnnx{x27}
\newcommand\ehys{yshift}
\newcommand\ehoneex{1.0ex}



\begin{document}
Tikz test

\begin{tikzpicture}
%  \node at (10pt, 50pt) {Й};
  
  \node at (0pt, 0pt) {0};
  
 \node at (1em, 1em) {1};
 \node at (1em, 2em) {2};
 \node at (2em, 1em) {3};
 \node at (2em, 2em) {4};
 
 \node at (-1em, -1em) {\scalebox{-1}[2]{5}};
 \node at (-1em, -2em) {6};
 \node at (-2em, -1em) {7};
 \node at (-2em, -2em) {8};

 \node at (-1em, 1em) {\color{red}\textbf{a}};
 \node at (-1em, 2em) {b};
 \node at (-2em, 1em) {c};
 \node at (-2em, 2em) {d};
 
 
 \node (e) at (1em, -1em) {e};
 \node (f) at (1em, -2em) {f};
 \node at (2em, -1em) {g};
 \node at (2em, -2em) {\rotatebox{60}{h}};

 \node (z)[
        left of=f,
            node distance=1ex,  
            inner sep=0,
            ]
            {\color{blue}{\egym{A001}}};

   \end{tikzpicture}
   
   Using Tikz to position hieroglyphs
   
  \begin{tikzpicture}
  \node (x1)  at (0em, 0em) {\color{blue}{\scalebox{3}[3]{\egym{A001}}}}; 
  \node (x2)[
    right of=x1,
    yshift=1.2ex,
%   above =of x1.east,
%   node distance=2ex,
        ]{\color{blue}{\scalebox{1.8}[1.8]{\egym{E001}}}}; 
  \node (x3)[
    below of=x2,
    node distance=3.0ex,
    ]{\color{blue}{\scalebox{2.0}[2.0]{\egym{V002}}}};

\node (x4)  [
        right of=x3,
        yshift=2ex,
        ] {\color{blue}{\scalebox{3}[3]{\egym{A010}}}}; 
\node (x5)  [
        right of=x4,
%       yshift=2ex,
        ] {\color{blue}{\scalebox{3}[3]{\egym{T003}}}}; 
\node (x6)  [
        right of=x5,
        xshift=-2ex,
        inner sep=0,
        ] {\color{blue}{\scalebox{3}[3]{\egym{S001}}}}; 

%
%
%
%

    
        
\node (x7)  [
        right of=x6,
        yshift=1.6ex,
        xshift=1.4ex,
        ] {\color{blue}{\scalebox{2}[2]{\ehq}}}; 
\node (x8)  [
        below of=x7,
%       xshift=-2ex,
        yshift=1.4ex,
        ] {\color{blue}{\scalebox{2.4}[2.4]{\ehl}}}; 
\node (x9)  [
        right of=x8,
%       xshift=-2ex,
        yshift=2.0ex,
        ] {\color{blue}{\scalebox{3}[3]{\ehi}}}; 
\node (x10)  [
        right of=x9,
        xshift=-1ex,
%       yshift=2.2ex,
        ] {\color{blue}{\scalebox{2.8}[2.8]{\eho}}}; 
%\ehp
\node (x11)  [
        right of=x10,
        xshift=-0.4ex,
        yshift=-0.4ex,
        ] {\color{blue}{\scalebox{3}[3]{\ehp}}}; 
%\eha
\node (x12)  [
        right of=x11,
        xshift=-1ex,
        yshift=0.4ex,
        ] {\color{blue}{\scalebox{3}[3]{\eha}}}; 
%\ehd
\node (x13)  [
        right of=x12,
        xshift=0.8ex,
        yshift=1.8ex,
        ] {\color{blue}{\scalebox{2}[2]{\ehd}}}; 
%\ehr
\node (x14)  [
        below of=x13,
%%      xshift=-2ex,
        yshift=2.4ex,
        ] {\color{blue}{\scalebox{2}[2]{\ehr}}}; 
%\eha
\node (x15)  [
        right of=x14,
        xshift=1ex,
        yshift=1.1ex,
        ] {\color{blue}{\scalebox{3}[3]{\eha}}}; 
%\eht
\node (x16)  [
        right of=x15,
%%      xshift=-2ex,
        yshift=-1.8ex,
        ] {\color{blue}{\scalebox{3}[3]{\eht}}}; 
 
 \node [
        red,
        thick,
        draw, 
        rectangle, 
        rounded corners=3ex,
        inner sep=0,
        fit={(x7)(x8)(x15)(x16)},
        ] (c1) {}; 
 
\node (x17)  [
        below of=x16,
        yshift=-1.4ex,
        xshift=0.4ex,
        ] {\color{blue}{\scalebox{2}[2]{\ehq}}}; 
\node (x18)  [
        below of=x17,
%       xshift=-2ex,
        yshift=1.0ex,
        ] {\color{blue}{\scalebox{2.8}[2.8]{\ehl}}}; 
\node (x19)  [
        below of=x18,
        xshift=-2ex,
%       yshift=2.0ex,
        ] {\color{blue}{\scalebox{2}[2]{\ehi}}}; 
\node (x20)  [
        right of=x19,
        xshift=-2ex,
%       yshift=2.2ex,
        ] {\color{blue}{\scalebox{2}[2]{\eho}}}; 
%\ehp
\node (x21)  [
        below of=x20,
        xshift=-2.4ex,
        yshift=-0.4ex,
        ] {\color{blue}{\scalebox{3}[3]{\ehp}}}; 
%\eha
\node (x22)  [
        right of=x21,
        xshift=-1.8ex,
        yshift=0.4ex,
        ] {\color{blue}{\scalebox{2}[2]{\eha}}}; 
%\ehd
\node (x23)  [
        below of=x22,
        xshift=-1.2ex,
        yshift=1.0ex,
        ] {\color{blue}{\scalebox{2}[2]{\ehd}}}; 
%\ehr
\node (x24)  [
        below of=x23,
%%      xshift=-2ex,
        yshift=2.4ex,
        ] {\color{blue}{\scalebox{2}[2]{\ehr}}}; 
%\eha
\node (x25)  [
        below of=x24,
        xshift=-1ex,
        yshift=1.1ex,
        ] {\color{blue}{\scalebox{2}[2]{\eha}}}; 
%\eht
\node (x26)  [
        right of=x25,
        xshift=-2.5ex,
        yshift=0.8ex,
        ] {\color{blue}{\scalebox{2}[2]{\eht}}}; 
 
 
 
 \node [
        red,
        thick,
        draw, 
        rectangle, 
        rounded corners=3ex,
        inner sep=0,
        fit={(x17)(x18)(x25)(x26)},
        ] (c2) {}; 
 
 
 
\node (x27)  [
        below of=x1,
        yshift=-2.8ex,
        xshift=0.4ex,
        ] {\color{blue}{\scalebox{-2}[2]{\ehq}}}; 
\node (x28)  [
%%      below of=x27,
        \ehbo = \ehnnx ,
%       xshift=-2ex,
%%      yshift=1.0ex,
        \ehys = \ehoneex ,
%       ] {\color{blue}{\scalebox{-2.8}[2.8]{\ehl}}}; 
]{\ehrtllion};

\node (x29)  [
        below of=x28,
        xshift=2ex,
%       yshift=2.0ex,
        ] {\color{blue}{\scalebox{-2}[2]{\ehi}}}; 
\node (x30)  [
        left of=x29,
        xshift=2ex,
%       yshift=2.2ex,
        ] {\color{blue}{\scalebox{-2}[2]{\eho}}}; 
%\ehp
\node (x31)  [
        below of=x30,
        xshift=3.8ex,
        yshift=-0.4ex,
        ] {\color{blue}{\scalebox{-3}[3]{\ehp}}}; 
%\eha
\node (x32)  [
        left of=x31,
        xshift=1.8ex,
        yshift=0.4ex,
        ] {\color{blue}{\scalebox{-2}[2]{\eha}}}; 
%\ehd
\node (x33)  [
        below of=x32,
        xshift=1.2ex,
        yshift=1.0ex,
        ] {\color{blue}{\scalebox{-2}[2]{\ehd}}}; 
%\ehr
\node (x34)  [
        below of=x33,
%%      xshift=-2ex,
        yshift=2.4ex,
        ] {\color{blue}{\scalebox{-2}[2]{\ehr}}}; 
%\eha
\node (x35)  [
        below of=x34,
        xshift=1ex,
        yshift=1.1ex,
        ] {\color{blue}{\scalebox{-2}[2]{\eha}}}; 
%\eht
\node (x36)  [
        left of=x35,
        xshift=2.5ex,
        yshift=0.8ex,
        ] {\color{blue}{\scalebox{-2}[2]{\eht}}}; 
 
 
 
 \node [
        red,
        thick,
        draw, 
        rectangle, 
        rounded corners=3ex,
        inner sep=0,
        fit={(x27)(x28)(x35)(x36)},
        ] (c3) {}; 
 
% \draw (0,0) circle {2cm};
% 
%\node (x99a)  [
%       below of=x8,
%       scale=-3,
%       rotate=90,
%       color=red,
%%      xshift=2.5ex,
%%      yshift=-6.8ex,
%%      ] {\color{red}{\scalebox{5}[5]{\ehlaw}}}; 
%       ] {\ehl};
% 
%%\node (x99b)  [
%%      below of=x8,
%%      scale=3,
%%      rotate=90,
%%      color=blue,
%%      xshift=-3.5ex,
%%%     yshift=-6.8ex,
%%      ] {\ehl};       
%
%
%%\node (x99c)  [
%%      below of=x8,
%%      scale=-3,
%%      rotate=270,
%%      color=blue,
%%      xshift=-3.5ex,
%%      yshift=-1.5ex,
%%      ] {\ehl};   
%
%%\draw[thick, black] (x99a) -- (x99c);
%
%\node (x99d)  [
%       below of=x8,
%       scale=-3,
%       rotate=180,
%       color=red,
%       xshift=-2.5ex,
%       yshift=-1.5ex,
%       ] {\ehl};
%
%
%\node (x99e)  [
%       below of=x8,
%       scale=-3,
%       rotate=0,
%       color=red,
%       xshift=-2.5ex,
%       yshift=1.6ex,
%       ] {\ehl};
%
\node (x99f)  [
        below of=x8,
        scale=3,
        rotate=90,
        color=red,
        xshift=-3.5ex,
        yshift=0ex,
        ] { };  

%%===============
%
%
%\node (x99fa)  [
%       below of=x99f,
%       scale=-3,
%       rotate=0,
%       color=blue,
%%      xshift=1.5ex,
%%      yshift=2.5ex,
%%      ] {\color{red}{\scalebox{5}[5]{\ehlaw}}}; 
%       ] {\ehl};
% 
%\node (x99fb)  [
%       below left of=x99fa,
%       scale=3,
%       rotate=180,
%       color=blue,
%%      xshift=-2.5ex,
%%      yshift=-1.5ex,
%       ] {\ehl};
%
%
\node (x99fc)  [
        below of=x99f,
        xscale=-3,
        yscale=-3,
        rotate=0,
        color=blue,
        xshift=-2.5ex,
        yshift=1.6ex,
        ] {\ehl};

\node (x99fca)  [
        below of=x99f,
        xscale=-3,
        yscale=3,
        rotate=0,
        color=blue,
        xshift=-2.5ex,
        yshift=1.6ex,
        ] {\ehl};


\node (x99fcy)  [
        below of=x99f,
        xscale=3,
        yscale=-3,
        rotate=0,
        color=blue,
        xshift=-2.5ex,
        yshift=1.6ex,
        ] {\ehl};

\node (x99fcay)  [
        below of=x99f,
        xscale=3,
        yscale=3,
        rotate=0,
        color=blue,
        xshift=-2.5ex,
        yshift=1.6ex,
        ] {\ehl};


%===================================
\node (x99fcu)  [
        below of=x99f,
        xscale=-3,
        yscale=-3,
        rotate=90,
        color=blue,
        xshift=-2.5ex,
        yshift=1.6ex,
        ] {\ehl};

\node (x99fcau)  [
        below of=x99f,
        xscale=-3,
        yscale=3,
        rotate=90,
        color=blue,
        xshift=-2.5ex,
        yshift=1.6ex,
        ] {\ehl};


\node (x99fcyu)  [
        below of=x99f,
        xscale=3,
        yscale=-3,
        rotate=90,
        color=blue,
        xshift=-2.5ex,
        yshift=1.6ex,
        ] {\ehl};

\node (x99fcayu)  [
        below of=x99f,
        xscale=3,
        yscale=3,
        rotate=90,
        color=blue,
        xshift=-2.5ex,
        yshift=1.6ex,
        ] {\ehl};

\node (n1)  [right of=x99fc] {1}; % $(-1,-1)$
\node (n2)  [right of=x99fca] {2};
\node (n3)  [left of=x99fcy] {3};
\node (n4)  [left of=x99fcay] {4};

\node (n5)  [
        above of=x99fcu,
%       xscale=3,
%       yscale=3,
%       rotate=90,
%       color=blue,
%       xshift=-2.5ex,
%       yshift=1.6ex,
        ] {5};


\node (n6)  [
        below of=x99fcau,
%       xscale=3,
%       yscale=3,
%       rotate=90,
%       color=blue,
%       xshift=-2.5ex,
%       yshift=1.6ex,
        ] {6};



\node (n7)  [
        above of=x99fcyu,
%       xscale=3,
%       yscale=3,
%       rotate=90,
%       color=blue,
%       xshift=-2.5ex,
%       yshift=1.6ex,
        ] {7};



\node (n8)  [
        below of=x99fcayu,
%       xscale=3,
%       yscale=3,
%       rotate=90,
%       color=blue,
%       xshift=-2.5ex,
%       yshift=1.6ex,
        ] {8};

%
%\node (x99fd)  [
%       below of=x99f,
%       scale=-3,
%       rotate=90,
%       color=blue,
%       xshift=-3.5ex,
%       yshift=0ex,
%       ] {\ehl};       


 \node [
    below of=x26,
    xshift=-1.8ex,
    yshift=-5.2ex,
    ](zx1)  {\color{blue}{\scalebox{-3}[3]{\egym{A001}}}}; 
  \node (zx2)[
    left of=zx1,
    yshift=1.2ex,
%   above =of x1.east,
%   node distance=2ex,
        ]{\color{blue}{\scalebox{-1.8}[1.8]{\egym{E001}}}}; 
  \node (zx3)[
    below of=zx2,
    node distance=3.0ex,
    ]{\color{blue}{\scalebox{-2.0}[2.0]{\egym{V002}}}};

\node (zx4)  [
        left of=zx3,
    xshift=-1.2ex,
        yshift=2ex,
        ] {\color{blue}{\scalebox{-3}[3]{\egym{A010}}}}; 
\node (zx5)  [
        left of=zx4,
%       yshift=2ex,
        ] {\color{blue}{\scalebox{-3}[3]{\egym{T003}}}}; 
\node (zx6)  [
        left of=zx5,
        xshift=1.5ex,
%       inner sep=0,
        ] {\color{blue}{\scalebox{-3}[3]{\egym{S001}}}}; 

%
%
%
%

    
        
\node (zx7)  [
        left of=zx6,
        yshift=1.6ex,
        xshift=-2.4ex,
        ] {\color{blue}{\scalebox{-2}[2]{\ehq}}}; 
\node (zx8)  [
        below of=zx7,
%       xshift=-2ex,
        yshift=1.4ex,
        ] {\color{blue}{\scalebox{-2.4}[2.4]{\ehl}}}; 
\node (zx9)  [
        left of=zx8,
%       xshift=-2ex,
        yshift=2.0ex,
        ] {\color{blue}{\scalebox{-3}[3]{\ehi}}}; 
\node (zx10)  [
        left of=zx9,
        xshift=1ex,
%       yshift=2.2ex,
        ] {\color{blue}{\scalebox{-2.8}[2.8]{\eho}}}; 
%\ehp
\node (zx11)  [
        left of=zx10,
        xshift=0.4ex,
        yshift=-0.4ex,
        ] {\color{blue}{\scalebox{-3}[3]{\ehp}}}; 
%\eha
\node (zx12)  [
        left of=zx11,
        xshift=1ex,
        yshift=0.4ex,
        ] {\color{blue}{\scalebox{-3}[3]{\eha}}}; 
%\ehd
\node (zx13)  [
        left of=zx12,
        xshift=-0.8ex,
        yshift=1.8ex,
        ] {\color{blue}{\scalebox{-2}[2]{\ehd}}}; 
%\ehr
\node (zx14)  [
        below of=zx13,
%%      xshift=-2ex,
        yshift=2.4ex,
        ] {\color{blue}{\scalebox{-2}[2]{\ehr}}}; 
%\eha
\node (zx15)  [
        left of=zx14,
        xshift=-1.2ex,
        yshift=1.1ex,
        ] {\color{blue}{\scalebox{-3}[3]{\eha}}}; 
%\eht
\node (zx16)  [
        left of=zx15,
%%      xshift=-2ex,
        yshift=-1.8ex,
        ] {\color{blue}{\scalebox{-3}[3]{\eht}}}; 
 
 \node [
        red,
        thick,
        draw, 
        rectangle, 
        rounded corners=3ex,
        inner sep=0,
        fit={(zx7)(zx8)(zx15)(zx16)},
        ] (zc1) {}; 
 






 \end{tikzpicture}
  
  
\section{Writing Hieroglyphs}
To write hieroglyphs, you will need:
\begin{itemize}
\item a font that contains hieroglyphs
    \begin{itemize}
    \item e.g. Noto Sans Egyptian Hieroglyphs
    \end{itemize}
\item an editor that can handle utf-8 or other unicode-format files
    \begin{itemize}
    \item e.g. TeXworks
    \end{itemize}
\item an input method to enter the hieroglyphs into the file
    \begin{itemize}
    \item keyboard (1000+ keys = impractical)
       \item an IME (none written yet?)
       \item font-mapping (TECkit fontmaps work only in xelatex. not in lualatex)
    \end{itemize}
\item a TeX flavour to process the file
    \begin{itemize}
    \item e.g. xelatex
    \end{itemize}
\item and for advanced typesetting:
    \begin{itemize}
    \item a way of positioning the hieroglyphs in sequence, horizontally and vertically
        \begin{itemize}
        \item e.g. the tabular environment
        \item e.g. Tikz
        \end{itemize}
    \item a way of scaling the hieroglyphs appropriately within any stacked or side-by-side arrangement, including flipping them horizontally when writing in the opposite direction (flipping is applying a scaling factor of $ -1$)
        \begin{itemize}
        \item e.g. the scalebox command
        \item e.g. the xscale= and yscale= node options in Tikz
        \end{itemize}
    \end{itemize}
\end{itemize}

\section{Mapping}

Birth name: Tuthmosis ("Born of the God Thoth")
Throne name: Menkheperre ("Lasting is the Manifestation of Re")

\begin{tikzpicture}
\node (p1)  
        at (0,0) 
%   [
%   left of=zx15,
%%      xshift=-2ex,
%       yshift=-1.8ex,
%       ]
         {\color{blue}{\scalebox{3}[3]{\egym M023}}}; 


\node (p2)  
%       at (0,0) 
    [
    below of=p1,
%%      xshift=-2ex,
        yshift=-2.4ex,
        ]
         {\color{blue}{\scalebox{3}[3]{\egym L002}}}; 
 

\node (m1)  
%       at (0,0) 
    [
    below of=p2,
%%      xshift=-2ex,
        yshift=-2.4ex,
        ]
         {\color{blue}{\scalebox{3}[3]{\egym N005}}}; 
 
 \node (m2)  
    [
    below of=m1,
%%      xshift=-2ex,
%       yshift=-1.8ex,
        ]
         {\color{blue}{\scalebox{3}[3]{\egym Y005}}}; 
 
 \node (m3)  
    [
    below of=m2,
%%      xshift=-2ex,
%       yshift=-1.8ex,
        ]
         {\color{blue}{\scalebox{3}[3]{\egym L001}}}; 
 
 \node [
        red,
        thick,
        draw, 
        rectangle, 
        rounded corners=3ex,
        inner sep=0,
        fit={(m1) (m2) (m3)},
        ] (zc1) {}; 

\node (b1)  
%       at (0,0) 
    [
    right of=p1,
        xshift=5ex,
%       yshift=-2.4ex,
        ]
         {\color{blue}{\scalebox{3}[3]{\egym G039}}}; 

 \node (b2)  
    [
    below of=b1,
%%      xshift=-2ex,
        yshift=-2.8ex,
        ]
         {\color{blue}{\scalebox{3}[3]{\egym N005}}}; 


 \node (n1)  
    [
    below of=b2,
%%      xshift=-2ex,
        yshift=-2.8ex,
        ]
         {\color{blue}{\scalebox{3.2}[3.2]{\egym G026}}}; 

 \node (n2)  
    [
    below of=n1,
        xshift=-1.8ex,
        yshift=-1.4ex,
        ]
         {\color{blue}{\scalebox{2}[2]{\egym F031}}}; 

 \node (n3)  
    [
    right of=n2,
        xshift=-1.8ex,
%       yshift=-1.4ex,
        ]
         {\color{blue}{\scalebox{2}[2]{\egym F035}}}; 

 \node (n4)  
    [
    below of=n3,
        xshift=-1.8ex,
        yshift=-1.4ex,
        ]
         {\color{blue}{\scalebox{2}[2]{\egym L001}}}; 

 \node (n5)  
    [
    below of=n4,
%       xshift=-1.8ex,
        yshift=0.4ex,
        ]
         {\color{blue}{\scalebox{2}[2]{\egym Z002}}}; 


 
 \node [
        red,
        thick,
        draw, 
        rectangle, 
        rounded corners=3ex,
        inner sep=0,
        fit={(n1)(n2)(n3)(n4)(n5)},
        ] (zd1) {}; 
 \end{tikzpicture}

\section{Inputting}

\verb|\symbol{"13000}| =  {\egyfe\huge \symbol{"13000}}


Macro command \textbackslash A001 = {\egyfe\huge \csname A001\endcsname}



Mapped Gardiner number A001 = { \huge \texthg{A001}}

(Second mapping) Mapped Gardiner number A1 = {\huge\texthi{A1}}

A001: In an environment: 
\begin{thiero}
A001
\end{thiero}

\section{Gardner numbers}
A1~=~{\texthi{A1}}
A2~=~{\texthi{A2}}
A3~=~{\texthi{A3}}
A4~=~{\texthi{A4}}
A5~=~{\texthi{A5}}
A5A~=~{\texthi{A5A}}
A6~=~{\texthi{A6}}
A6A~=~{\texthi{A6A}}
A6B~=~{\texthi{A6B}}
A7~=~{\texthi{A7}}
A8~=~{\texthi{A8}}
A9~=~{\texthi{A9}}
A10~=~{\texthi{A10}}
A11~=~{\texthi{A11}}
A12~=~{\texthi{A12}}
A13~=~{\texthi{A13}}
A14~=~{\texthi{A14}}
A14A~=~{\texthi{A14A}}
A15~=~{\texthi{A15}}
A16~=~{\texthi{A16}}
A17~=~{\texthi{A17}}
A17A~=~{\texthi{A17A}}
A18~=~{\texthi{A18}}
A19~=~{\texthi{A19}}
A20~=~{\texthi{A20}}
A21~=~{\texthi{A21}}
A22~=~{\texthi{A22}}
A23~=~{\texthi{A23}}
A24~=~{\texthi{A24}}
A25~=~{\texthi{A25}}
A26~=~{\texthi{A26}}
A27~=~{\texthi{A27}}
A28~=~{\texthi{A28}}
A29~=~{\texthi{A29}}
A30~=~{\texthi{A30}}
A31~=~{\texthi{A31}}
A32~=~{\texthi{A32}}
A32A~=~{\texthi{A32A}}
A33~=~{\texthi{A33}}
A34~=~{\texthi{A34}}
A35~=~{\texthi{A35}}
A36~=~{\texthi{A36}}
A37~=~{\texthi{A37}}
A38~=~{\texthi{A38}}
A39~=~{\texthi{A39}}
A40~=~{\texthi{A40}}
A40A~=~{\texthi{A40A}}
A41~=~{\texthi{A41}}
A42~=~{\texthi{A42}}
A42A~=~{\texthi{A42A}}
A43~=~{\texthi{A43}}
A43A~=~{\texthi{A43A}}
A44~=~{\texthi{A44}}
A45~=~{\texthi{A45}}
A45A~=~{\texthi{A45A}}
A46~=~{\texthi{A46}}
A47~=~{\texthi{A47}}
A48~=~{\texthi{A48}}
A49~=~{\texthi{A49}}
A50~=~{\texthi{A50}}
A51~=~{\texthi{A51}}
A52~=~{\texthi{A52}}
A53~=~{\texthi{A53}}
A54~=~{\texthi{A54}}
A55~=~{\texthi{A55}}
A56~=~{\texthi{A56}}
A57~=~{\texthi{A57}}
A58~=~{\texthi{A58}}
A59~=~{\texthi{A59}}
A60~=~{\texthi{A60}}
A61~=~{\texthi{A61}}
A62~=~{\texthi{A62}}
A63~=~{\texthi{A63}}
A64~=~{\texthi{A64}}
A65~=~{\texthi{A65}}
A66~=~{\texthi{A66}}
A67~=~{\texthi{A67}}
A68~=~{\texthi{A68}}
A69~=~{\texthi{A69}}
A70~=~{\texthi{A70}}
etc

  \end{document}
```

*Alternative 2*

Another alternative, more portable, is to use regular expressions, under expl3, for example:

[image: regex]

MWE

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Noto Serif}
\newfontfamily\fegy{Noto Sans Egyptian Hieroglyphs}
\ExplSyntaxOn

\newcommand\doegyhiero{%
\regex_replace_all:nnN { a001 } { ^^^^^13000 } \l_my_tl
\regex_replace_all:nnN { g010 } { ^^^^^1314b } \l_my_tl
\regex_replace_all:nnN { m017a } { ^^^^^131cc } \l_my_tl
\regex_replace_all:nnN { n001 } { ^^^^^131ef } \l_my_tl
}

\NewDocumentCommand { \textegyhiero } { m } {%
\tl_set:Nn \l_my_tl { #1 }
\doegyhiero
\tl_use:N \l_my_tl
}

\NewDocumentEnvironment{egyhiero}{ +b } 
{
\tl_set:Nn \l_my_tl { #1 }
\doegyhiero
\tl_use:N \l_my_tl
}
{ }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

This is inline {\fegy\Large\textegyhiero{a001 g010 n001}}.

And the following is inside an environment:
\begin{egyhiero}\fegy\Large

a001 g010 n001

a001 g010 n001 m017a

\end{egyhiero}
End of environment.

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

**Disclaimer: This is just an interpretation of the very bad readme combined with some TeX knowledge. I did not test it.**

You will find two types of folders in those archives: `texmf` and something else.

The `texmf` folder should be put anywhere on your laptop and will be indexed by MikTeX as soon as you add it. Put the contents of both `texmf` folders (from both archives) into one folder, f.i. `texmf-local`, so that you would have the following structure:

```
- texmf-local
-- doc
-- dvips
-- fonts
-- pdftex
-- tex
```

Then add this to the MikTeX search path (tab roots in the settings manager, afaik). Rebuild your filename database (tab general in the settings manager, afaik).

The last step would be to put the sesh executables from HieroTeX into a folder which is in the PATH of your OS. There are tons of how-tos out there showing how to do that. Test if it worked by running `sesh` on the command-line.

Now you should be ready to go.

Comment: Have followed your instructions to the best of my ability.  When I run sesh, I get a dos screen with a blinking cursor.  When I run the package in Texstudio, I receive a hiero.sty not found error.

Comment: @MiltRiggs A `.sty` not found means that you do not have added that folder to the MikTeX search path or forgot to refresh the FNDB afterwards. Unfortunately I can't say what sesh is supposed to do, but a blinking cursor may mean that it's waiting for input, hence it's not the main problem here.

Answer (score 0):

The author of this package is the associated professor Rosmorduc. The unpackged files contain a folder named texmf which is already in the structer of TDS. Use your "Miktex option" you can register those files in right directory for Miktex. But the last step for your installation(run sesh.exe) is outdate, because your new version of Miktex is designed for 64bit system instead the one(32bit system) Pro. Rosmorduc programmed sesh.exe. The corresponding file to run Sesh.exe in Miktex 2.9 which you are using is in the directory root\MikTex\miktex\bin\x64. Indeed, if you still wish to run the package of Rosmorduc, you should update the whole engine of this package in this sense.

Comment: Not really clear, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

Part 2: the mapping file
(compile with `TECkit_compile foo` to produce the `.tec` file

MAP

```
; TECkit mapping for TeX input conventions <-> Unicode characters

LHSName "Gardiner-to-Hieroglyph2"
RHSName "UNICODE"

pass(Unicode)

; ligatures from Knuth's original CMR fonts
U+002D U+002D           <>  U+2013  ; -- -> en dash
U+002D U+002D U+002D    <>  U+2014  ; --- -> em dash

U+0027          <>  U+2019  ; ' -> right single quote
U+0027 U+0027   <>  U+201D  ; '' -> right double quote
U+0022           >  U+201D  ; " -> right double quote

U+0060          <>  U+2018  ; ` -> left single quote
U+0060 U+0060   <>  U+201C  ; `` -> left double quote

U+0021 U+0060   <>  U+00A1  ; !` -> inverted exclam
U+003F U+0060   <>  U+00BF  ; ?` -> inverted question

; additions supported in T1 encoding
U+002C U+002C   <>  U+201E  ; ,, -> DOUBLE LOW-9 QUOTATION MARK
U+003C U+003C   <>  U+00AB  ; << -> LEFT POINTING GUILLEMET
U+003E U+003E   <>  U+00BB  ; >> -> RIGHT POINTING GUILLEMET



; Egyptian hieroglyphs
 U+0041 U+0031 <>  U+13000
 U+0041 U+0032 <>  U+13001
 U+0041 U+0033 <>  U+13002
 U+0041 U+0034 <>  U+13003
 U+0041 U+0035 <>  U+13004
 U+0041 U+0035 U+0041 <>  U+13005
 U+0041 U+0036 <>  U+13006
 U+0041 U+0036 U+0041 <>  U+13007
 U+0041 U+0036 U+0042 <>  U+13008
 U+0041 U+0037 <>  U+13009
 U+0041 U+0038 <>  U+1300A
 U+0041 U+0039 <>  U+1300B
 U+0041 U+0031 U+0030 <>  U+1300C
 U+0041 U+0031 U+0031 <>  U+1300D
 U+0041 U+0031 U+0032 <>  U+1300E
 U+0041 U+0031 U+0033 <>  U+1300F
 U+0041 U+0031 U+0034 <>  U+13010
 U+0041 U+0031 U+0034 U+0041 <>  U+13011
 U+0041 U+0031 U+0035 <>  U+13012
 U+0041 U+0031 U+0036 <>  U+13013
 U+0041 U+0031 U+0037 <>  U+13014
 U+0041 U+0031 U+0037 U+0041 <>  U+13015
 U+0041 U+0031 U+0038 <>  U+13016
 U+0041 U+0031 U+0039 <>  U+13017
 U+0041 U+0032 U+0030 <>  U+13018
 U+0041 U+0032 U+0031 <>  U+13019
 U+0041 U+0032 U+0032 <>  U+1301A
 U+0041 U+0032 U+0033 <>  U+1301B
 U+0041 U+0032 U+0034 <>  U+1301C
 U+0041 U+0032 U+0035 <>  U+1301D
 U+0041 U+0032 U+0036 <>  U+1301E
 U+0041 U+0032 U+0037 <>  U+1301F
 U+0041 U+0032 U+0038 <>  U+13020
 U+0041 U+0032 U+0039 <>  U+13021
 U+0041 U+0033 U+0030 <>  U+13022
 U+0041 U+0033 U+0031 <>  U+13023
 U+0041 U+0033 U+0032 <>  U+13024
 U+0041 U+0033 U+0032 U+0041 <>  U+13025
 U+0041 U+0033 U+0033 <>  U+13026
 U+0041 U+0033 U+0034 <>  U+13027
 U+0041 U+0033 U+0035 <>  U+13028
 U+0041 U+0033 U+0036 <>  U+13029
 U+0041 U+0033 U+0037 <>  U+1302A
 U+0041 U+0033 U+0038 <>  U+1302B
 U+0041 U+0033 U+0039 <>  U+1302C
 U+0041 U+0034 U+0030 <>  U+1302D
 U+0041 U+0034 U+0030 U+0041 <>  U+1302E
 U+0041 U+0034 U+0031 <>  U+1302F
 U+0041 U+0034 U+0032 <>  U+13030
 U+0041 U+0034 U+0032 U+0041 <>  U+13031
 U+0041 U+0034 U+0033 <>  U+13032
 U+0041 U+0034 U+0033 U+0041 <>  U+13033
 U+0041 U+0034 U+0034 <>  U+13034
 U+0041 U+0034 U+0035 <>  U+13035
 U+0041 U+0034 U+0035 U+0041 <>  U+13036
 U+0041 U+0034 U+0036 <>  U+13037
 U+0041 U+0034 U+0037 <>  U+13038
 U+0041 U+0034 U+0038 <>  U+13039
 U+0041 U+0034 U+0039 <>  U+1303A
 U+0041 U+0035 U+0030 <>  U+1303B
 U+0041 U+0035 U+0031 <>  U+1303C
 U+0041 U+0035 U+0032 <>  U+1303D
 U+0041 U+0035 U+0033 <>  U+1303E
 U+0041 U+0035 U+0034 <>  U+1303F
 U+0041 U+0035 U+0035 <>  U+13040
 U+0041 U+0035 U+0036 <>  U+13041
 U+0041 U+0035 U+0037 <>  U+13042
 U+0041 U+0035 U+0038 <>  U+13043
 U+0041 U+0035 U+0039 <>  U+13044
 U+0041 U+0036 U+0030 <>  U+13045
 U+0041 U+0036 U+0031 <>  U+13046
 U+0041 U+0036 U+0032 <>  U+13047
 U+0041 U+0036 U+0033 <>  U+13048
 U+0041 U+0036 U+0034 <>  U+13049
 U+0041 U+0036 U+0035 <>  U+1304A
 U+0041 U+0036 U+0036 <>  U+1304B
 U+0041 U+0036 U+0037 <>  U+1304C
 U+0041 U+0036 U+0038 <>  U+1304D
 U+0041 U+0036 U+0039 <>  U+1304E
 U+0041 U+0037 U+0030 <>  U+1304F
 U+0042 U+0031 <>  U+13050
 U+0042 U+0032 <>  U+13051
 U+0042 U+0033 <>  U+13052
 U+0042 U+0034 <>  U+13053
 U+0042 U+0035 <>  U+13054
 U+0042 U+0035 U+0041 <>  U+13055
 U+0042 U+0036 <>  U+13056
 U+0042 U+0037 <>  U+13057
 U+0042 U+0038 <>  U+13058
 U+0042 U+0039 <>  U+13059
 U+0043 U+0031 <>  U+1305A
 U+0043 U+0032 <>  U+1305B
 U+0043 U+0032 U+0041 <>  U+1305C
 U+0043 U+0032 U+0042 <>  U+1305D
 U+0043 U+0032 U+0043 <>  U+1305E
 U+0043 U+0033 <>  U+1305F
 U+0043 U+0034 <>  U+13060
 U+0043 U+0035 <>  U+13061
 U+0043 U+0036 <>  U+13062
 U+0043 U+0037 <>  U+13063
 U+0043 U+0038 <>  U+13064
 U+0043 U+0039 <>  U+13065
 U+0043 U+0031 U+0030 <>  U+13066
 U+0043 U+0031 U+0030 U+0041 <>  U+13067
 U+0043 U+0031 U+0031 <>  U+13068
 U+0043 U+0031 U+0032 <>  U+13069
 U+0043 U+0031 U+0033 <>  U+1306A
 U+0043 U+0031 U+0034 <>  U+1306B
 U+0043 U+0031 U+0035 <>  U+1306C
 U+0043 U+0031 U+0036 <>  U+1306D
 U+0043 U+0031 U+0037 <>  U+1306E
 U+0043 U+0031 U+0038 <>  U+1306F
 U+0043 U+0031 U+0039 <>  U+13070
 U+0043 U+0032 U+0030 <>  U+13071
 U+0043 U+0032 U+0031 <>  U+13072
 U+0043 U+0032 U+0032 <>  U+13073
 U+0043 U+0032 U+0033 <>  U+13074
 U+0043 U+0032 U+0034 <>  U+13075
 U+0044 U+0031 <>  U+13076
 U+0044 U+0032 <>  U+13077
 U+0044 U+0033 <>  U+13078
 U+0044 U+0034 <>  U+13079
 U+0044 U+0035 <>  U+1307A
 U+0044 U+0036 <>  U+1307B
 U+0044 U+0037 <>  U+1307C
 U+0044 U+0038 <>  U+1307D
 U+0044 U+0038 U+0041 <>  U+1307E
 U+0044 U+0039 <>  U+1307F
 U+0044 U+0031 U+0030 <>  U+13080
 U+0044 U+0031 U+0031 <>  U+13081
 U+0044 U+0031 U+0032 <>  U+13082
 U+0044 U+0031 U+0033 <>  U+13083
 U+0044 U+0031 U+0034 <>  U+13084
 U+0044 U+0031 U+0035 <>  U+13085
 U+0044 U+0031 U+0036 <>  U+13086
 U+0044 U+0031 U+0037 <>  U+13087
 U+0044 U+0031 U+0038 <>  U+13088
 U+0044 U+0031 U+0039 <>  U+13089
 U+0044 U+0032 U+0030 <>  U+1308A
 U+0044 U+0032 U+0031 <>  U+1308B
 U+0044 U+0032 U+0032 <>  U+1308C
 U+0044 U+0032 U+0033 <>  U+1308D
 U+0044 U+0032 U+0034 <>  U+1308E
 U+0044 U+0032 U+0035 <>  U+1308F
 U+0044 U+0032 U+0036 <>  U+13090
 U+0044 U+0032 U+0037 <>  U+13091
 U+0044 U+0032 U+0037 U+0041 <>  U+13092
 U+0044 U+0032 U+0038 <>  U+13093
 U+0044 U+0032 U+0039 <>  U+13094
 U+0044 U+0033 U+0030 <>  U+13095
 U+0044 U+0033 U+0031 <>  U+13096
 U+0044 U+0033 U+0031 U+0041 <>  U+13097
 U+0044 U+0033 U+0032 <>  U+13098
 U+0044 U+0033 U+0033 <>  U+13099
 U+0044 U+0033 U+0034 <>  U+1309A
 U+0044 U+0033 U+0034 U+0041 <>  U+1309B
 U+0044 U+0033 U+0035 <>  U+1309C
 U+0044 U+0033 U+0036 <>  U+1309D
 U+0044 U+0033 U+0037 <>  U+1309E
 U+0044 U+0033 U+0038 <>  U+1309F
 U+0044 U+0033 U+0039 <>  U+130A0
 U+0044 U+0034 U+0030 <>  U+130A1
 U+0044 U+0034 U+0031 <>  U+130A2
 U+0044 U+0034 U+0032 <>  U+130A3
 U+0044 U+0034 U+0033 <>  U+130A4
 U+0044 U+0034 U+0034 <>  U+130A5
 U+0044 U+0034 U+0035 <>  U+130A6
 U+0044 U+0034 U+0036 <>  U+130A7
 U+0044 U+0034 U+0036 U+0041 <>  U+130A8
 U+0044 U+0034 U+0037 <>  U+130A9
 U+0044 U+0034 U+0038 <>  U+130AA
 U+0044 U+0034 U+0038 U+0041 <>  U+130AB
 U+0044 U+0034 U+0039 <>  U+130AC
 U+0044 U+0035 U+0030 <>  U+130AD
 U+0044 U+0035 U+0030 U+0041 <>  U+130AE
 U+0044 U+0035 U+0030 U+0042 <>  U+130AF
 U+0044 U+0035 U+0030 U+0043 <>  U+130B0
 U+0044 U+0035 U+0030 U+0044 <>  U+130B1
 U+0044 U+0035 U+0030 U+0045 <>  U+130B2
 U+0044 U+0035 U+0030 U+0046 <>  U+130B3
 U+0044 U+0035 U+0030 U+0047 <>  U+130B4
 U+0044 U+0035 U+0030 U+0048 <>  U+130B5
 U+0044 U+0035 U+0030 U+0049 <>  U+130B6
 U+0044 U+0035 U+0031 <>  U+130B7
 U+0044 U+0035 U+0032 <>  U+130B8
 U+0044 U+0035 U+0032 U+0041 <>  U+130B9
 U+0044 U+0035 U+0033 <>  U+130BA
 U+0044 U+0035 U+0034 <>  U+130BB
 U+0044 U+0035 U+0034 U+0041 <>  U+130BC
 U+0044 U+0035 U+0035 <>  U+130BD
 U+0044 U+0035 U+0036 <>  U+130BE
 U+0044 U+0035 U+0037 <>  U+130BF
 U+0044 U+0035 U+0038 <>  U+130C0
 U+0044 U+0035 U+0039 <>  U+130C1
 U+0044 U+0036 U+0030 <>  U+130C2
 U+0044 U+0036 U+0031 <>  U+130C3
 U+0044 U+0036 U+0032 <>  U+130C4
 U+0044 U+0036 U+0033 <>  U+130C5
 U+0044 U+0036 U+0034 <>  U+130C6
 U+0044 U+0036 U+0035 <>  U+130C7
 U+0044 U+0036 U+0036 <>  U+130C8
 U+0044 U+0036 U+0037 <>  U+130C9
 U+0044 U+0036 U+0037 U+0041 <>  U+130CA
 U+0044 U+0036 U+0037 U+0042 <>  U+130CB
 U+0044 U+0036 U+0037 U+0043 <>  U+130CC
 U+0044 U+0036 U+0037 U+0044 <>  U+130CD
 U+0044 U+0036 U+0037 U+0045 <>  U+130CE
 U+0044 U+0036 U+0037 U+0046 <>  U+130CF
 U+0044 U+0036 U+0037 U+0047 <>  U+130D0
 U+0044 U+0036 U+0037 U+0048 <>  U+130D1
 U+0045 U+0031 <>  U+130D2
 U+0045 U+0032 <>  U+130D3
 U+0045 U+0033 <>  U+130D4
 U+0045 U+0034 <>  U+130D5
 U+0045 U+0035 <>  U+130D6
 U+0045 U+0036 <>  U+130D7
 U+0045 U+0037 <>  U+130D8
 U+0045 U+0038 <>  U+130D9
 U+0045 U+0038 U+0041 <>  U+130DA
 U+0045 U+0039 <>  U+130DB
 U+0045 U+0039 U+0041 <>  U+130DC
 U+0045 U+0031 U+0030 <>  U+130DD
 U+0045 U+0031 U+0031 <>  U+130DE
 U+0045 U+0031 U+0032 <>  U+130DF
 U+0045 U+0031 U+0033 <>  U+130E0
 U+0045 U+0031 U+0034 <>  U+130E1
 U+0045 U+0031 U+0035 <>  U+130E2
 U+0045 U+0031 U+0036 <>  U+130E3
 U+0045 U+0031 U+0036 U+0041 <>  U+130E4
 U+0045 U+0031 U+0037 <>  U+130E5
 U+0045 U+0031 U+0037 U+0041 <>  U+130E6
 U+0045 U+0031 U+0038 <>  U+130E7
 U+0045 U+0031 U+0039 <>  U+130E8
 U+0045 U+0032 U+0030 <>  U+130E9
 U+0045 U+0032 U+0030 U+0041 <>  U+130EA
 U+0045 U+0032 U+0031 <>  U+130EB
 U+0045 U+0032 U+0032 <>  U+130EC
 U+0045 U+0032 U+0033 <>  U+130ED
 U+0045 U+0032 U+0034 <>  U+130EE
 U+0045 U+0032 U+0035 <>  U+130EF
 U+0045 U+0032 U+0036 <>  U+130F0
 U+0045 U+0032 U+0037 <>  U+130F1
 U+0045 U+0032 U+0038 <>  U+130F2
 U+0045 U+0032 U+0038 U+0041 <>  U+130F3
 U+0045 U+0032 U+0039 <>  U+130F4
 U+0045 U+0033 U+0030 <>  U+130F5
 U+0045 U+0033 U+0031 <>  U+130F6
 U+0045 U+0033 U+0032 <>  U+130F7
 U+0045 U+0033 U+0033 <>  U+130F8
 U+0045 U+0033 U+0034 <>  U+130F9
 U+0045 U+0033 U+0034 U+0041 <>  U+130FA
 U+0045 U+0033 U+0036 <>  U+130FB
 U+0045 U+0033 U+0037 <>  U+130FC
 U+0045 U+0033 U+0038 <>  U+130FD
 U+0046 U+0031 <>  U+130FE
 U+0046 U+0031 U+0041 <>  U+130FF
 U+0046 U+0032 <>  U+13100
 U+0046 U+0033 <>  U+13101
 U+0046 U+0034 <>  U+13102
 U+0046 U+0035 <>  U+13103
 U+0046 U+0036 <>  U+13104
 U+0046 U+0037 <>  U+13105
 U+0046 U+0038 <>  U+13106
 U+0046 U+0039 <>  U+13107
 U+0046 U+0031 U+0030 <>  U+13108
 U+0046 U+0031 U+0031 <>  U+13109
 U+0046 U+0031 U+0032 <>  U+1310A
 U+0046 U+0031 U+0033 <>  U+1310B
 U+0046 U+0031 U+0033 U+0041 <>  U+1310C
 U+0046 U+0031 U+0034 <>  U+1310D
 U+0046 U+0031 U+0035 <>  U+1310E
 U+0046 U+0031 U+0036 <>  U+1310F
 U+0046 U+0031 U+0037 <>  U+13110
 U+0046 U+0031 U+0038 <>  U+13111
 U+0046 U+0031 U+0039 <>  U+13112
 U+0046 U+0032 U+0030 <>  U+13113
 U+0046 U+0032 U+0031 <>  U+13114
 U+0046 U+0032 U+0031 U+0041 <>  U+13115
 U+0046 U+0032 U+0032 <>  U+13116
 U+0046 U+0032 U+0033 <>  U+13117
 U+0046 U+0032 U+0034 <>  U+13118
 U+0046 U+0032 U+0035 <>  U+13119
 U+0046 U+0032 U+0036 <>  U+1311A
 U+0046 U+0032 U+0037 <>  U+1311B
 U+0046 U+0032 U+0038 <>  U+1311C
 U+0046 U+0032 U+0039 <>  U+1311D
 U+0046 U+0033 U+0030 <>  U+1311E
 U+0046 U+0033 U+0031 <>  U+1311F
 U+0046 U+0033 U+0031 U+0041 <>  U+13120
 U+0046 U+0033 U+0032 <>  U+13121
 U+0046 U+0033 U+0033 <>  U+13122
 U+0046 U+0033 U+0034 <>  U+13123
 U+0046 U+0033 U+0035 <>  U+13124
 U+0046 U+0033 U+0036 <>  U+13125
 U+0046 U+0033 U+0037 <>  U+13126
 U+0046 U+0033 U+0037 U+0041 <>  U+13127
 U+0046 U+0033 U+0038 <>  U+13128
 U+0046 U+0033 U+0038 U+0041 <>  U+13129
 U+0046 U+0033 U+0039 <>  U+1312A
 U+0046 U+0034 U+0030 <>  U+1312B
 U+0046 U+0034 U+0031 <>  U+1312C
 U+0046 U+0034 U+0032 <>  U+1312D
 U+0046 U+0034 U+0033 <>  U+1312E
 U+0046 U+0034 U+0034 <>  U+1312F
 U+0046 U+0034 U+0035 <>  U+13130
 U+0046 U+0034 U+0035 U+0041 <>  U+13131
 U+0046 U+0034 U+0036 <>  U+13132
 U+0046 U+0034 U+0036 U+0041 <>  U+13133
 U+0046 U+0034 U+0037 <>  U+13134
 U+0046 U+0034 U+0037 U+0041 <>  U+13135
 U+0046 U+0034 U+0038 <>  U+13136
 U+0046 U+0034 U+0039 <>  U+13137
 U+0046 U+0035 U+0030 <>  U+13138
 U+0046 U+0035 U+0031 <>  U+13139
 U+0046 U+0035 U+0031 U+0041 <>  U+1313A
 U+0046 U+0035 U+0031 U+0042 <>  U+1313B
 U+0046 U+0035 U+0031 U+0043 <>  U+1313C
 U+0046 U+0035 U+0032 <>  U+1313D
 U+0046 U+0035 U+0033 <>  U+1313E
 U+0047 U+0031 <>  U+1313F
 U+0047 U+0032 <>  U+13140
 U+0047 U+0033 <>  U+13141
 U+0047 U+0034 <>  U+13142
 U+0047 U+0035 <>  U+13143
 U+0047 U+0036 <>  U+13144
 U+0047 U+0036 U+0041 <>  U+13145
 U+0047 U+0037 <>  U+13146
 U+0047 U+0037 U+0041 <>  U+13147
 U+0047 U+0037 U+0042 <>  U+13148
 U+0047 U+0038 <>  U+13149
 U+0047 U+0039 <>  U+1314A
 U+0047 U+0031 U+0030 <>  U+1314B
 U+0047 U+0031 U+0031 <>  U+1314C
 U+0047 U+0031 U+0031 U+0041 <>  U+1314D
 U+0047 U+0031 U+0032 <>  U+1314E
 U+0047 U+0031 U+0033 <>  U+1314F
 U+0047 U+0031 U+0034 <>  U+13150
 U+0047 U+0031 U+0035 <>  U+13151
 U+0047 U+0031 U+0036 <>  U+13152
 U+0047 U+0031 U+0037 <>  U+13153
 U+0047 U+0031 U+0038 <>  U+13154
 U+0047 U+0031 U+0039 <>  U+13155
 U+0047 U+0032 U+0030 <>  U+13156
 U+0047 U+0032 U+0030 U+0041 <>  U+13157
 U+0047 U+0032 U+0031 <>  U+13158
 U+0047 U+0032 U+0032 <>  U+13159
 U+0047 U+0032 U+0033 <>  U+1315A
 U+0047 U+0032 U+0034 <>  U+1315B
 U+0047 U+0032 U+0035 <>  U+1315C
 U+0047 U+0032 U+0036 <>  U+1315D
 U+0047 U+0032 U+0036 U+0041 <>  U+1315E
 U+0047 U+0032 U+0037 <>  U+1315F
 U+0047 U+0032 U+0038 <>  U+13160
 U+0047 U+0032 U+0039 <>  U+13161
 U+0047 U+0033 U+0030 <>  U+13162
 U+0047 U+0033 U+0031 <>  U+13163
 U+0047 U+0033 U+0032 <>  U+13164
 U+0047 U+0033 U+0033 <>  U+13165
 U+0047 U+0033 U+0034 <>  U+13166
 U+0047 U+0033 U+0035 <>  U+13167
 U+0047 U+0033 U+0036 <>  U+13168
 U+0047 U+0033 U+0036 U+0041 <>  U+13169
 U+0047 U+0033 U+0037 <>  U+1316A
 U+0047 U+0033 U+0037 U+0041 <>  U+1316B
 U+0047 U+0033 U+0038 <>  U+1316C
 U+0047 U+0033 U+0039 <>  U+1316D
 U+0047 U+0034 U+0030 <>  U+1316E
 U+0047 U+0034 U+0031 <>  U+1316F
 U+0047 U+0034 U+0032 <>  U+13170
 U+0047 U+0034 U+0033 <>  U+13171
 U+0047 U+0034 U+0033 U+0041 <>  U+13172
 U+0047 U+0034 U+0034 <>  U+13173
 U+0047 U+0034 U+0035 <>  U+13174
 U+0047 U+0034 U+0035 U+0041 <>  U+13175
 U+0047 U+0034 U+0036 <>  U+13176
 U+0047 U+0034 U+0037 <>  U+13177
 U+0047 U+0034 U+0038 <>  U+13178
 U+0047 U+0034 U+0039 <>  U+13179
 U+0047 U+0035 U+0030 <>  U+1317A
 U+0047 U+0035 U+0031 <>  U+1317B
 U+0047 U+0035 U+0032 <>  U+1317C
 U+0047 U+0035 U+0033 <>  U+1317D
 U+0047 U+0035 U+0034 <>  U+1317E
 U+0048 U+0031 <>  U+1317F
 U+0048 U+0032 <>  U+13180
 U+0048 U+0033 <>  U+13181
 U+0048 U+0034 <>  U+13182
 U+0048 U+0035 <>  U+13183
 U+0048 U+0036 <>  U+13184
 U+0048 U+0036 U+0041 <>  U+13185
 U+0048 U+0037 <>  U+13186
 U+0048 U+0038 <>  U+13187
 U+0049 U+0031 <>  U+13188
 U+0049 U+0032 <>  U+13189
 U+0049 U+0033 <>  U+1318A
 U+0049 U+0034 <>  U+1318B
 U+0049 U+0035 <>  U+1318C
 U+0049 U+0035 U+0041 <>  U+1318D
 U+0049 U+0036 <>  U+1318E
 U+0049 U+0037 <>  U+1318F
 U+0049 U+0038 <>  U+13190
 U+0049 U+0039 <>  U+13191
 U+0049 U+0039 U+0041 <>  U+13192
 U+0049 U+0031 U+0030 <>  U+13193
 U+0049 U+0031 U+0030 U+0041 <>  U+13194
 U+0049 U+0031 U+0031 <>  U+13195
 U+0049 U+0031 U+0031 U+0041 <>  U+13196
 U+0049 U+0031 U+0032 <>  U+13197
 U+0049 U+0031 U+0033 <>  U+13198
 U+0049 U+0031 U+0034 <>  U+13199
 U+0049 U+0031 U+0035 <>  U+1319A
 U+004B U+0031 <>  U+1319B
 U+004B U+0032 <>  U+1319C
 U+004B U+0033 <>  U+1319D
 U+004B U+0034 <>  U+1319E
 U+004B U+0035 <>  U+1319F
 U+004B U+0036 <>  U+131A0
 U+004B U+0037 <>  U+131A1
 U+004B U+0038 <>  U+131A2
 U+004C U+0031 <>  U+131A3
 U+004C U+0032 <>  U+131A4
 U+004C U+0032 U+0041 <>  U+131A5
 U+004C U+0033 <>  U+131A6
 U+004C U+0034 <>  U+131A7
 U+004C U+0035 <>  U+131A8
 U+004C U+0036 <>  U+131A9
 U+004C U+0036 U+0041 <>  U+131AA
 U+004C U+0037 <>  U+131AB
 U+004C U+0038 <>  U+131AC
 U+004D U+0031 <>  U+131AD
 U+004D U+0031 U+0041 <>  U+131AE
 U+004D U+0031 U+0042 <>  U+131AF
 U+004D U+0032 <>  U+131B0
 U+004D U+0033 <>  U+131B1
 U+004D U+0033 U+0041 <>  U+131B2
 U+004D U+0034 <>  U+131B3
 U+004D U+0035 <>  U+131B4
 U+004D U+0036 <>  U+131B5
 U+004D U+0037 <>  U+131B6
 U+004D U+0038 <>  U+131B7
 U+004D U+0039 <>  U+131B8
 U+004D U+0031 U+0030 <>  U+131B9
 U+004D U+0031 U+0030 U+0041 <>  U+131BA
 U+004D U+0031 U+0031 <>  U+131BB
 U+004D U+0031 U+0032 <>  U+131BC
 U+004D U+0031 U+0032 U+0041 <>  U+131BD
 U+004D U+0031 U+0032 U+0042 <>  U+131BE
 U+004D U+0031 U+0032 U+0043 <>  U+131BF
 U+004D U+0031 U+0032 U+0044 <>  U+131C0
 U+004D U+0031 U+0032 U+0045 <>  U+131C1
 U+004D U+0031 U+0032 U+0046 <>  U+131C2
 U+004D U+0031 U+0032 U+0047 <>  U+131C3
 U+004D U+0031 U+0032 U+0048 <>  U+131C4
 U+004D U+0031 U+0033 <>  U+131C5
 U+004D U+0031 U+0034 <>  U+131C6
 U+004D U+0031 U+0035 <>  U+131C7
 U+004D U+0031 U+0035 U+0041 <>  U+131C8
 U+004D U+0031 U+0036 <>  U+131C9
 U+004D U+0031 U+0036 U+0041 <>  U+131CA
 U+004D U+0031 U+0037 <>  U+131CB
 U+004D U+0031 U+0037 U+0041 <>  U+131CC
 U+004D U+0031 U+0038 <>  U+131CD
 U+004D U+0031 U+0039 <>  U+131CE
 U+004D U+0032 U+0030 <>  U+131CF
 U+004D U+0032 U+0031 <>  U+131D0
 U+004D U+0032 U+0032 <>  U+131D1
 U+004D U+0032 U+0032 U+0041 <>  U+131D2
 U+004D U+0032 U+0033 <>  U+131D3
 U+004D U+0032 U+0034 <>  U+131D4
 U+004D U+0032 U+0034 U+0041 <>  U+131D5
 U+004D U+0032 U+0035 <>  U+131D6
 U+004D U+0032 U+0036 <>  U+131D7
 U+004D U+0032 U+0037 <>  U+131D8
 U+004D U+0032 U+0038 <>  U+131D9
 U+004D U+0032 U+0038 U+0041 <>  U+131DA
 U+004D U+0032 U+0039 <>  U+131DB
 U+004D U+0033 U+0030 <>  U+131DC
 U+004D U+0033 U+0031 <>  U+131DD
 U+004D U+0033 U+0031 U+0041 <>  U+131DE
 U+004D U+0033 U+0032 <>  U+131DF
 U+004D U+0033 U+0033 <>  U+131E0
 U+004D U+0033 U+0033 U+0041 <>  U+131E1
 U+004D U+0033 U+0033 U+0042 <>  U+131E2
 U+004D U+0033 U+0034 <>  U+131E3
 U+004D U+0033 U+0035 <>  U+131E4
 U+004D U+0033 U+0036 <>  U+131E5
 U+004D U+0033 U+0037 <>  U+131E6
 U+004D U+0033 U+0038 <>  U+131E7
 U+004D U+0033 U+0039 <>  U+131E8
 U+004D U+0034 U+0030 <>  U+131E9
 U+004D U+0034 U+0030 U+0041 <>  U+131EA
 U+004D U+0034 U+0031 <>  U+131EB
 U+004D U+0034 U+0032 <>  U+131EC
 U+004D U+0034 U+0033 <>  U+131ED
 U+004D U+0034 U+0034 <>  U+131EE
 U+004E U+0031 <>  U+131EF
 U+004E U+0032 <>  U+131F0
 U+004E U+0033 <>  U+131F1
 U+004E U+0034 <>  U+131F2
 U+004E U+0035 <>  U+131F3
 U+004E U+0036 <>  U+131F4
 U+004E U+0037 <>  U+131F5
 U+004E U+0038 <>  U+131F6
 U+004E U+0039 <>  U+131F7
 U+004E U+0031 U+0030 <>  U+131F8
 U+004E U+0031 U+0031 <>  U+131F9
 U+004E U+0031 U+0032 <>  U+131FA
 U+004E U+0031 U+0033 <>  U+131FB
 U+004E U+0031 U+0034 <>  U+131FC
 U+004E U+0031 U+0035 <>  U+131FD
 U+004E U+0031 U+0036 <>  U+131FE
 U+004E U+0031 U+0037 <>  U+131FF
```

Comment: The mapping file has been truncated (30k char limit on answers). https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/346630/what-is-mapping-and-how-can-i-use-it-to-my-advantage/507452#507452 has the full file (manually compressed with character replacement to fit under 30k), and information on how to restore it.

Answer (score 0):

MAP file (part 2 of 2)

```
U+004E U+0031 U+0038 <>  U+13200
 U+004E U+0031 U+0038 U+0041 <>  U+13201
 U+004E U+0031 U+0038 U+0042 <>  U+13202
 U+004E U+0031 U+0039 <>  U+13203
 U+004E U+0032 U+0030 <>  U+13204
 U+004E U+0032 U+0031 <>  U+13205
 U+004E U+0032 U+0032 <>  U+13206
 U+004E U+0032 U+0033 <>  U+13207
 U+004E U+0032 U+0034 <>  U+13208
 U+004E U+0032 U+0035 <>  U+13209
 U+004E U+0032 U+0035 U+0041 <>  U+1320A
 U+004E U+0032 U+0036 <>  U+1320B
 U+004E U+0032 U+0037 <>  U+1320C
 U+004E U+0032 U+0038 <>  U+1320D
 U+004E U+0032 U+0039 <>  U+1320E
 U+004E U+0033 U+0030 <>  U+1320F
 U+004E U+0033 U+0031 <>  U+13210
 U+004E U+0033 U+0032 <>  U+13211
 U+004E U+0033 U+0033 <>  U+13212
 U+004E U+0033 U+0033 U+0041 <>  U+13213
 U+004E U+0033 U+0034 <>  U+13214
 U+004E U+0033 U+0034 U+0041 <>  U+13215
 U+004E U+0033 U+0035 <>  U+13216
 U+004E U+0033 U+0035 U+0041 <>  U+13217
 U+004E U+0033 U+0036 <>  U+13218
 U+004E U+0033 U+0037 <>  U+13219
 U+004E U+0033 U+0037 U+0041 <>  U+1321A
 U+004E U+0033 U+0038 <>  U+1321B
 U+004E U+0033 U+0039 <>  U+1321C
 U+004E U+0034 U+0030 <>  U+1321D
 U+004E U+0034 U+0031 <>  U+1321E
 U+004E U+0034 U+0032 <>  U+1321F
 U+004E U+004C U+0031 <>  U+13220
 U+004E U+004C U+0032 <>  U+13221
 U+004E U+004C U+0033 <>  U+13222
 U+004E U+004C U+0034 <>  U+13223
 U+004E U+004C U+0035 <>  U+13224
 U+004E U+004C U+0035 U+0041 <>  U+13225
 U+004E U+004C U+0036 <>  U+13226
 U+004E U+004C U+0037 <>  U+13227
 U+004E U+004C U+0038 <>  U+13228
 U+004E U+004C U+0039 <>  U+13229
 U+004E U+004C U+0031 U+0030 <>  U+1322A
 U+004E U+004C U+0031 U+0031 <>  U+1322B
 U+004E U+004C U+0031 U+0032 <>  U+1322C
 U+004E U+004C U+0031 U+0033 <>  U+1322D
 U+004E U+004C U+0031 U+0034 <>  U+1322E
 U+004E U+004C U+0031 U+0035 <>  U+1322F
 U+004E U+004C U+0031 U+0036 <>  U+13230
 U+004E U+004C U+0031 U+0037 <>  U+13231
 U+004E U+004C U+0031 U+0037 U+0041 <>  U+13232
 U+004E U+004C U+0031 U+0038 <>  U+13233
 U+004E U+004C U+0031 U+0039 <>  U+13234
 U+004E U+004C U+0032 U+0030 <>  U+13235
 U+004E U+0055 U+0031 <>  U+13236
 U+004E U+0055 U+0032 <>  U+13237
 U+004E U+0055 U+0033 <>  U+13238
 U+004E U+0055 U+0034 <>  U+13239
 U+004E U+0055 U+0035 <>  U+1323A
 U+004E U+0055 U+0036 <>  U+1323B
 U+004E U+0055 U+0037 <>  U+1323C
 U+004E U+0055 U+0038 <>  U+1323D
 U+004E U+0055 U+0039 <>  U+1323E
 U+004E U+0055 U+0031 U+0030 <>  U+1323F
 U+004E U+0055 U+0031 U+0030 U+0041 <>  U+13240
 U+004E U+0055 U+0031 U+0031 <>  U+13241
 U+004E U+0055 U+0031 U+0031 U+0041 <>  U+13242
 U+004E U+0055 U+0031 U+0032 <>  U+13243
 U+004E U+0055 U+0031 U+0033 <>  U+13244
 U+004E U+0055 U+0031 U+0034 <>  U+13245
 U+004E U+0055 U+0031 U+0035 <>  U+13246
 U+004E U+0055 U+0031 U+0036 <>  U+13247
 U+004E U+0055 U+0031 U+0037 <>  U+13248
 U+004E U+0055 U+0031 U+0038 <>  U+13249
 U+004E U+0055 U+0031 U+0038 U+0041 <>  U+1324A
 U+004E U+0055 U+0031 U+0039 <>  U+1324B
 U+004E U+0055 U+0032 U+0030 <>  U+1324C
 U+004E U+0055 U+0032 U+0031 <>  U+1324D
 U+004E U+0055 U+0032 U+0032 <>  U+1324E
 U+004E U+0055 U+0032 U+0032 U+0041 <>  U+1324F
 U+004F U+0031 <>  U+13250
 U+004F U+0031 U+0041 <>  U+13251
 U+004F U+0032 <>  U+13252
 U+004F U+0033 <>  U+13253
 U+004F U+0034 <>  U+13254
 U+004F U+0035 <>  U+13255
 U+004F U+0035 U+0041 <>  U+13256
 U+004F U+0036 <>  U+13257
 U+004F U+0036 U+0041 <>  U+13258
 U+004F U+0036 U+0042 <>  U+13259
 U+004F U+0036 U+0043 <>  U+1325A
 U+004F U+0036 U+0044 <>  U+1325B
 U+004F U+0036 U+0045 <>  U+1325C
 U+004F U+0036 U+0046 <>  U+1325D
 U+004F U+0037 <>  U+1325E
 U+004F U+0038 <>  U+1325F
 U+004F U+0039 <>  U+13260
 U+004F U+0031 U+0030 <>  U+13261
 U+004F U+0031 U+0030 U+0041 <>  U+13262
 U+004F U+0031 U+0030 U+0042 <>  U+13263
 U+004F U+0031 U+0030 U+0043 <>  U+13264
 U+004F U+0031 U+0031 <>  U+13265
 U+004F U+0031 U+0032 <>  U+13266
 U+004F U+0031 U+0033 <>  U+13267
 U+004F U+0031 U+0034 <>  U+13268
 U+004F U+0031 U+0035 <>  U+13269
 U+004F U+0031 U+0036 <>  U+1326A
 U+004F U+0031 U+0037 <>  U+1326B
 U+004F U+0031 U+0038 <>  U+1326C
 U+004F U+0031 U+0039 <>  U+1326D
 U+004F U+0031 U+0039 U+0041 <>  U+1326E
 U+004F U+0032 U+0030 <>  U+1326F
 U+004F U+0032 U+0030 U+0041 <>  U+13270
 U+004F U+0032 U+0031 <>  U+13271
 U+004F U+0032 U+0032 <>  U+13272
 U+004F U+0032 U+0033 <>  U+13273
 U+004F U+0032 U+0034 <>  U+13274
 U+004F U+0032 U+0034 U+0041 <>  U+13275
 U+004F U+0032 U+0035 <>  U+13276
 U+004F U+0032 U+0035 U+0041 <>  U+13277
 U+004F U+0032 U+0036 <>  U+13278
 U+004F U+0032 U+0037 <>  U+13279
 U+004F U+0032 U+0038 <>  U+1327A
 U+004F U+0032 U+0039 <>  U+1327B
 U+004F U+0032 U+0039 U+0041 <>  U+1327C
 U+004F U+0033 U+0030 <>  U+1327D
 U+004F U+0033 U+0030 U+0041 <>  U+1327E
 U+004F U+0033 U+0031 <>  U+1327F
 U+004F U+0033 U+0032 <>  U+13280
 U+004F U+0033 U+0033 <>  U+13281
 U+004F U+0033 U+0033 U+0041 <>  U+13282
 U+004F U+0033 U+0034 <>  U+13283
 U+004F U+0033 U+0035 <>  U+13284
 U+004F U+0033 U+0036 <>  U+13285
 U+004F U+0033 U+0036 U+0041 <>  U+13286
 U+004F U+0033 U+0036 U+0042 <>  U+13287
 U+004F U+0033 U+0036 U+0043 <>  U+13288
 U+004F U+0033 U+0036 U+0044 <>  U+13289
 U+004F U+0033 U+0037 <>  U+1328A
 U+004F U+0033 U+0038 <>  U+1328B
 U+004F U+0033 U+0039 <>  U+1328C
 U+004F U+0034 U+0030 <>  U+1328D
 U+004F U+0034 U+0031 <>  U+1328E
 U+004F U+0034 U+0032 <>  U+1328F
 U+004F U+0034 U+0033 <>  U+13290
 U+004F U+0034 U+0034 <>  U+13291
 U+004F U+0034 U+0035 <>  U+13292
 U+004F U+0034 U+0036 <>  U+13293
 U+004F U+0034 U+0037 <>  U+13294
 U+004F U+0034 U+0038 <>  U+13295
 U+004F U+0034 U+0039 <>  U+13296
 U+004F U+0035 U+0030 <>  U+13297
 U+004F U+0035 U+0030 U+0041 <>  U+13298
 U+004F U+0035 U+0030 U+0042 <>  U+13299
 U+004F U+0035 U+0031 <>  U+1329A
 U+0050 U+0031 <>  U+1329B
 U+0050 U+0031 U+0041 <>  U+1329C
 U+0050 U+0032 <>  U+1329D
 U+0050 U+0033 <>  U+1329E
 U+0050 U+0033 U+0041 <>  U+1329F
 U+0050 U+0034 <>  U+132A0
 U+0050 U+0035 <>  U+132A1
 U+0050 U+0036 <>  U+132A2
 U+0050 U+0037 <>  U+132A3
 U+0050 U+0038 <>  U+132A4
 U+0050 U+0039 <>  U+132A5
 U+0050 U+0031 U+0030 <>  U+132A6
 U+0050 U+0031 U+0031 <>  U+132A7
 U+0051 U+0031 <>  U+132A8
 U+0051 U+0032 <>  U+132A9
 U+0051 U+0033 <>  U+132AA
 U+0051 U+0034 <>  U+132AB
 U+0051 U+0035 <>  U+132AC
 U+0051 U+0036 <>  U+132AD
 U+0051 U+0037 <>  U+132AE
 U+0052 U+0031 <>  U+132AF
 U+0052 U+0032 <>  U+132B0
 U+0052 U+0032 U+0041 <>  U+132B1
 U+0052 U+0033 <>  U+132B2
 U+0052 U+0033 U+0041 <>  U+132B3
 U+0052 U+0033 U+0042 <>  U+132B4
 U+0052 U+0034 <>  U+132B5
 U+0052 U+0035 <>  U+132B6
 U+0052 U+0036 <>  U+132B7
 U+0052 U+0037 <>  U+132B8
 U+0052 U+0038 <>  U+132B9
 U+0052 U+0039 <>  U+132BA
 U+0052 U+0031 U+0030 <>  U+132BB
 U+0052 U+0031 U+0030 U+0041 <>  U+132BC
 U+0052 U+0031 U+0031 <>  U+132BD
 U+0052 U+0031 U+0032 <>  U+132BE
 U+0052 U+0031 U+0033 <>  U+132BF
 U+0052 U+0031 U+0034 <>  U+132C0
 U+0052 U+0031 U+0035 <>  U+132C1
 U+0052 U+0031 U+0036 <>  U+132C2
 U+0052 U+0031 U+0036 U+0041 <>  U+132C3
 U+0052 U+0031 U+0037 <>  U+132C4
 U+0052 U+0031 U+0038 <>  U+132C5
 U+0052 U+0031 U+0039 <>  U+132C6
 U+0052 U+0032 U+0030 <>  U+132C7
 U+0052 U+0032 U+0031 <>  U+132C8
 U+0052 U+0032 U+0032 <>  U+132C9
 U+0052 U+0032 U+0033 <>  U+132CA
 U+0052 U+0032 U+0034 <>  U+132CB
 U+0052 U+0032 U+0035 <>  U+132CC
 U+0052 U+0032 U+0036 <>  U+132CD
 U+0052 U+0032 U+0037 <>  U+132CE
 U+0052 U+0032 U+0038 <>  U+132CF
 U+0052 U+0032 U+0039 <>  U+132D0
 U+0053 U+0031 <>  U+132D1
 U+0053 U+0032 <>  U+132D2
 U+0053 U+0032 U+0041 <>  U+132D3
 U+0053 U+0033 <>  U+132D4
 U+0053 U+0034 <>  U+132D5
 U+0053 U+0035 <>  U+132D6
 U+0053 U+0036 <>  U+132D7
 U+0053 U+0036 U+0041 <>  U+132D8
 U+0053 U+0037 <>  U+132D9
 U+0053 U+0038 <>  U+132DA
 U+0053 U+0039 <>  U+132DB
 U+0053 U+0031 U+0030 <>  U+132DC
 U+0053 U+0031 U+0031 <>  U+132DD
 U+0053 U+0031 U+0032 <>  U+132DE
 U+0053 U+0031 U+0033 <>  U+132DF
 U+0053 U+0031 U+0034 <>  U+132E0
 U+0053 U+0031 U+0034 U+0041 <>  U+132E1
 U+0053 U+0031 U+0034 U+0042 <>  U+132E2
 U+0053 U+0031 U+0035 <>  U+132E3
 U+0053 U+0031 U+0036 <>  U+132E4
 U+0053 U+0031 U+0037 <>  U+132E5
 U+0053 U+0031 U+0037 U+0041 <>  U+132E6
 U+0053 U+0031 U+0038 <>  U+132E7
 U+0053 U+0031 U+0039 <>  U+132E8
 U+0053 U+0032 U+0030 <>  U+132E9
 U+0053 U+0032 U+0031 <>  U+132EA
 U+0053 U+0032 U+0032 <>  U+132EB
 U+0053 U+0032 U+0033 <>  U+132EC
 U+0053 U+0032 U+0034 <>  U+132ED
 U+0053 U+0032 U+0035 <>  U+132EE
 U+0053 U+0032 U+0036 <>  U+132EF
 U+0053 U+0032 U+0036 U+0041 <>  U+132F0
 U+0053 U+0032 U+0036 U+0042 <>  U+132F1
 U+0053 U+0032 U+0037 <>  U+132F2
 U+0053 U+0032 U+0038 <>  U+132F3
 U+0053 U+0032 U+0039 <>  U+132F4
 U+0053 U+0033 U+0030 <>  U+132F5
 U+0053 U+0033 U+0031 <>  U+132F6
 U+0053 U+0033 U+0032 <>  U+132F7
 U+0053 U+0033 U+0033 <>  U+132F8
 U+0053 U+0033 U+0034 <>  U+132F9
 U+0053 U+0033 U+0035 <>  U+132FA
 U+0053 U+0033 U+0035 U+0041 <>  U+132FB
 U+0053 U+0033 U+0036 <>  U+132FC
 U+0053 U+0033 U+0037 <>  U+132FD
 U+0053 U+0033 U+0038 <>  U+132FE
 U+0053 U+0033 U+0039 <>  U+132FF
 U+0053 U+0034 U+0030 <>  U+13300
 U+0053 U+0034 U+0031 <>  U+13301
 U+0053 U+0034 U+0032 <>  U+13302
 U+0053 U+0034 U+0033 <>  U+13303
 U+0053 U+0034 U+0034 <>  U+13304
 U+0053 U+0034 U+0035 <>  U+13305
 U+0053 U+0034 U+0036 <>  U+13306
 U+0054 U+0031 <>  U+13307
 U+0054 U+0032 <>  U+13308
 U+0054 U+0033 <>  U+13309
 U+0054 U+0033 U+0041 <>  U+1330A
 U+0054 U+0034 <>  U+1330B
 U+0054 U+0035 <>  U+1330C
 U+0054 U+0036 <>  U+1330D
 U+0054 U+0037 <>  U+1330E
 U+0054 U+0037 U+0041 <>  U+1330F
 U+0054 U+0038 <>  U+13310
 U+0054 U+0038 U+0041 <>  U+13311
 U+0054 U+0039 <>  U+13312
 U+0054 U+0039 U+0041 <>  U+13313
 U+0054 U+0031 U+0030 <>  U+13314
 U+0054 U+0031 U+0031 <>  U+13315
 U+0054 U+0031 U+0031 U+0041 <>  U+13316
 U+0054 U+0031 U+0032 <>  U+13317
 U+0054 U+0031 U+0033 <>  U+13318
 U+0054 U+0031 U+0034 <>  U+13319
 U+0054 U+0031 U+0035 <>  U+1331A
 U+0054 U+0031 U+0036 <>  U+1331B
 U+0054 U+0031 U+0036 U+0041 <>  U+1331C
 U+0054 U+0031 U+0037 <>  U+1331D
 U+0054 U+0031 U+0038 <>  U+1331E
 U+0054 U+0031 U+0039 <>  U+1331F
 U+0054 U+0032 U+0030 <>  U+13320
 U+0054 U+0032 U+0031 <>  U+13321
 U+0054 U+0032 U+0032 <>  U+13322
 U+0054 U+0032 U+0033 <>  U+13323
 U+0054 U+0032 U+0034 <>  U+13324
 U+0054 U+0032 U+0035 <>  U+13325
 U+0054 U+0032 U+0036 <>  U+13326
 U+0054 U+0032 U+0037 <>  U+13327
 U+0054 U+0032 U+0038 <>  U+13328
 U+0054 U+0032 U+0039 <>  U+13329
 U+0054 U+0033 U+0030 <>  U+1332A
 U+0054 U+0033 U+0031 <>  U+1332B
 U+0054 U+0033 U+0032 <>  U+1332C
 U+0054 U+0033 U+0032 U+0041 <>  U+1332D
 U+0054 U+0033 U+0033 <>  U+1332E
 U+0054 U+0033 U+0033 U+0041 <>  U+1332F
 U+0054 U+0033 U+0034 <>  U+13330
 U+0054 U+0033 U+0035 <>  U+13331
 U+0054 U+0033 U+0036 <>  U+13332
 U+0055 U+0031 <>  U+13333
 U+0055 U+0032 <>  U+13334
 U+0055 U+0033 <>  U+13335
 U+0055 U+0034 <>  U+13336
 U+0055 U+0035 <>  U+13337
 U+0055 U+0036 <>  U+13338
 U+0055 U+0036 U+0041 <>  U+13339
 U+0055 U+0036 U+0042 <>  U+1333A
 U+0055 U+0037 <>  U+1333B
 U+0055 U+0038 <>  U+1333C
 U+0055 U+0039 <>  U+1333D
 U+0055 U+0031 U+0030 <>  U+1333E
 U+0055 U+0031 U+0031 <>  U+1333F
 U+0055 U+0031 U+0032 <>  U+13340
 U+0055 U+0031 U+0033 <>  U+13341
 U+0055 U+0031 U+0034 <>  U+13342
 U+0055 U+0031 U+0035 <>  U+13343
 U+0055 U+0031 U+0036 <>  U+13344
 U+0055 U+0031 U+0037 <>  U+13345
 U+0055 U+0031 U+0038 <>  U+13346
 U+0055 U+0031 U+0039 <>  U+13347
 U+0055 U+0032 U+0030 <>  U+13348
 U+0055 U+0032 U+0031 <>  U+13349
 U+0055 U+0032 U+0032 <>  U+1334A
 U+0055 U+0032 U+0033 <>  U+1334B
 U+0055 U+0032 U+0033 U+0041 <>  U+1334C
 U+0055 U+0032 U+0034 <>  U+1334D
 U+0055 U+0032 U+0035 <>  U+1334E
 U+0055 U+0032 U+0036 <>  U+1334F
 U+0055 U+0032 U+0037 <>  U+13350
 U+0055 U+0032 U+0038 <>  U+13351
 U+0055 U+0032 U+0039 <>  U+13352
 U+0055 U+0032 U+0039 U+0041 <>  U+13353
 U+0055 U+0033 U+0030 <>  U+13354
 U+0055 U+0033 U+0031 <>  U+13355
 U+0055 U+0033 U+0032 <>  U+13356
 U+0055 U+0033 U+0032 U+0041 <>  U+13357
 U+0055 U+0033 U+0033 <>  U+13358
 U+0055 U+0033 U+0034 <>  U+13359
 U+0055 U+0033 U+0035 <>  U+1335A
 U+0055 U+0033 U+0036 <>  U+1335B
 U+0055 U+0033 U+0037 <>  U+1335C
 U+0055 U+0033 U+0038 <>  U+1335D
 U+0055 U+0033 U+0039 <>  U+1335E
 U+0055 U+0034 U+0030 <>  U+1335F
 U+0055 U+0034 U+0031 <>  U+13360
 U+0055 U+0034 U+0032 <>  U+13361
 U+0056 U+0031 <>  U+13362
 U+0056 U+0031 U+0041 <>  U+13363
 U+0056 U+0031 U+0042 <>  U+13364
 U+0056 U+0031 U+0043 <>  U+13365
 U+0056 U+0031 U+0044 <>  U+13366
 U+0056 U+0031 U+0045 <>  U+13367
 U+0056 U+0031 U+0046 <>  U+13368
 U+0056 U+0031 U+0047 <>  U+13369
 U+0056 U+0031 U+0048 <>  U+1336A
 U+0056 U+0031 U+0049 <>  U+1336B
 U+0056 U+0032 <>  U+1336C
 U+0056 U+0032 U+0041 <>  U+1336D
 U+0056 U+0033 <>  U+1336E
 U+0056 U+0034 <>  U+1336F
 U+0056 U+0035 <>  U+13370
 U+0056 U+0036 <>  U+13371
 U+0056 U+0037 <>  U+13372
 U+0056 U+0037 U+0041 <>  U+13373
 U+0056 U+0037 U+0042 <>  U+13374
 U+0056 U+0038 <>  U+13375
 U+0056 U+0039 <>  U+13376
 U+0056 U+0031 U+0030 <>  U+13377
 U+0056 U+0031 U+0031 <>  U+13378
 U+0056 U+0031 U+0031 U+0041 <>  U+13379
 U+0056 U+0031 U+0031 U+0042 <>  U+1337A
 U+0056 U+0031 U+0031 U+0043 <>  U+1337B
 U+0056 U+0031 U+0032 <>  U+1337C
 U+0056 U+0031 U+0032 U+0041 <>  U+1337D
 U+0056 U+0031 U+0032 U+0042 <>  U+1337E
 U+0056 U+0031 U+0033 <>  U+1337F
 U+0056 U+0031 U+0034 <>  U+13380
 U+0056 U+0031 U+0035 <>  U+13381
 U+0056 U+0031 U+0036 <>  U+13382
 U+0056 U+0031 U+0037 <>  U+13383
 U+0056 U+0031 U+0038 <>  U+13384
 U+0056 U+0031 U+0039 <>  U+13385
 U+0056 U+0032 U+0030 <>  U+13386
 U+0056 U+0032 U+0030 U+0041 <>  U+13387
 U+0056 U+0032 U+0030 U+0042 <>  U+13388
 U+0056 U+0032 U+0030 U+0043 <>  U+13389
 U+0056 U+0032 U+0030 U+0044 <>  U+1338A
 U+0056 U+0032 U+0030 U+0045 <>  U+1338B
 U+0056 U+0032 U+0030 U+0046 <>  U+1338C
 U+0056 U+0032 U+0030 U+0047 <>  U+1338D
 U+0056 U+0032 U+0030 U+0048 <>  U+1338E
 U+0056 U+0032 U+0030 U+0049 <>  U+1338F
 U+0056 U+0032 U+0030 U+004A <>  U+13390
 U+0056 U+0032 U+0030 U+004B <>  U+13391
 U+0056 U+0032 U+0030 U+004C <>  U+13392
 U+0056 U+0032 U+0031 <>  U+13393
 U+0056 U+0032 U+0032 <>  U+13394
 U+0056 U+0032 U+0033 <>  U+13395
 U+0056 U+0032 U+0033 U+0041 <>  U+13396
 U+0056 U+0032 U+0034 <>  U+13397
 U+0056 U+0032 U+0035 <>  U+13398
 U+0056 U+0032 U+0036 <>  U+13399
 U+0056 U+0032 U+0037 <>  U+1339A
 U+0056 U+0032 U+0038 <>  U+1339B
 U+0056 U+0032 U+0038 U+0041 <>  U+1339C
 U+0056 U+0032 U+0039 <>  U+1339D
 U+0056 U+0032 U+0039 U+0041 <>  U+1339E
 U+0056 U+0033 U+0030 <>  U+1339F
 U+0056 U+0033 U+0030 U+0041 <>  U+133A0
 U+0056 U+0033 U+0031 <>  U+133A1
 U+0056 U+0033 U+0031 U+0041 <>  U+133A2
 U+0056 U+0033 U+0032 <>  U+133A3
 U+0056 U+0033 U+0033 <>  U+133A4
 U+0056 U+0033 U+0033 U+0041 <>  U+133A5
 U+0056 U+0033 U+0034 <>  U+133A6
 U+0056 U+0033 U+0035 <>  U+133A7
 U+0056 U+0033 U+0036 <>  U+133A8
 U+0056 U+0033 U+0037 <>  U+133A9
 U+0056 U+0033 U+0037 U+0041 <>  U+133AA
 U+0056 U+0033 U+0038 <>  U+133AB
 U+0056 U+0033 U+0039 <>  U+133AC
 U+0056 U+0034 U+0030 <>  U+133AD
 U+0056 U+0034 U+0030 U+0041 <>  U+133AE
 U+0057 U+0031 <>  U+133AF
 U+0057 U+0032 <>  U+133B0
 U+0057 U+0033 <>  U+133B1
 U+0057 U+0033 U+0041 <>  U+133B2
 U+0057 U+0034 <>  U+133B3
 U+0057 U+0035 <>  U+133B4
 U+0057 U+0036 <>  U+133B5
 U+0057 U+0037 <>  U+133B6
 U+0057 U+0038 <>  U+133B7
 U+0057 U+0039 <>  U+133B8
 U+0057 U+0039 U+0041 <>  U+133B9
 U+0057 U+0031 U+0030 <>  U+133BA
 U+0057 U+0031 U+0030 U+0041 <>  U+133BB
 U+0057 U+0031 U+0031 <>  U+133BC
 U+0057 U+0031 U+0032 <>  U+133BD
 U+0057 U+0031 U+0033 <>  U+133BE
 U+0057 U+0031 U+0034 <>  U+133BF
 U+0057 U+0031 U+0034 U+0041 <>  U+133C0
 U+0057 U+0031 U+0035 <>  U+133C1
 U+0057 U+0031 U+0036 <>  U+133C2
 U+0057 U+0031 U+0037 <>  U+133C3
 U+0057 U+0031 U+0037 U+0041 <>  U+133C4
 U+0057 U+0031 U+0038 <>  U+133C5
 U+0057 U+0031 U+0038 U+0041 <>  U+133C6
 U+0057 U+0031 U+0039 <>  U+133C7
 U+0057 U+0032 U+0030 <>  U+133C8
 U+0057 U+0032 U+0031 <>  U+133C9
 U+0057 U+0032 U+0032 <>  U+133CA
 U+0057 U+0032 U+0033 <>  U+133CB
 U+0057 U+0032 U+0034 <>  U+133CC
 U+0057 U+0032 U+0034 U+0041 <>  U+133CD
 U+0057 U+0032 U+0035 <>  U+133CE
 U+0058 U+0031 <>  U+133CF
 U+0058 U+0032 <>  U+133D0
 U+0058 U+0033 <>  U+133D1
 U+0058 U+0034 <>  U+133D2
 U+0058 U+0034 U+0041 <>  U+133D3
 U+0058 U+0034 U+0042 <>  U+133D4
 U+0058 U+0035 <>  U+133D5
 U+0058 U+0036 <>  U+133D6
 U+0058 U+0036 U+0041 <>  U+133D7
 U+0058 U+0037 <>  U+133D8
 U+0058 U+0038 <>  U+133D9
 U+0058 U+0038 U+0041 <>  U+133DA
 U+0059 U+0031 <>  U+133DB
 U+0059 U+0031 U+0041 <>  U+133DC
 U+0059 U+0032 <>  U+133DD
 U+0059 U+0033 <>  U+133DE
 U+0059 U+0034 <>  U+133DF
 U+0059 U+0035 <>  U+133E0
 U+0059 U+0036 <>  U+133E1
 U+0059 U+0037 <>  U+133E2
 U+0059 U+0038 <>  U+133E3
 U+005A U+0031 <>  U+133E4
 U+005A U+0032 <>  U+133E5
 U+005A U+0032 U+0041 <>  U+133E6
 U+005A U+0032 U+0042 <>  U+133E7
 U+005A U+0032 U+0043 <>  U+133E8
 U+005A U+0032 U+0044 <>  U+133E9
 U+005A U+0033 <>  U+133EA
 U+005A U+0033 U+0041 <>  U+133EB
 U+005A U+0033 U+0042 <>  U+133EC
 U+005A U+0034 <>  U+133ED
 U+005A U+0034 U+0041 <>  U+133EE
 U+005A U+0035 <>  U+133EF
 U+005A U+0035 U+0041 <>  U+133F0
 U+005A U+0036 <>  U+133F1
 U+005A U+0037 <>  U+133F2
 U+005A U+0038 <>  U+133F3
 U+005A U+0039 <>  U+133F4
 U+005A U+0031 U+0030 <>  U+133F5
 U+005A U+0031 U+0031 <>  U+133F6
 U+005A U+0031 U+0032 <>  U+133F7
 U+005A U+0031 U+0033 <>  U+133F8
 U+005A U+0031 U+0034 <>  U+133F9
 U+005A U+0031 U+0035 <>  U+133FA
 U+005A U+0031 U+0035 U+0041 <>  U+133FB
 U+005A U+0031 U+0035 U+0042 <>  U+133FC
 U+005A U+0031 U+0035 U+0043 <>  U+133FD
 U+005A U+0031 U+0035 U+0044 <>  U+133FE
 U+005A U+0031 U+0035 U+0045 <>  U+133FF
 U+005A U+0031 U+0035 U+0046 <>  U+13400
 U+005A U+0031 U+0035 U+0047 <>  U+13401
 U+005A U+0031 U+0035 U+0048 <>  U+13402
 U+005A U+0031 U+0035 U+0049 <>  U+13403
 U+005A U+0031 U+0036 <>  U+13404
 U+005A U+0031 U+0036 U+0041 <>  U+13405
 U+005A U+0031 U+0036 U+0042 <>  U+13406
 U+005A U+0031 U+0036 U+0043 <>  U+13407
 U+005A U+0031 U+0036 U+0044 <>  U+13408
 U+005A U+0031 U+0036 U+0045 <>  U+13409
 U+005A U+0031 U+0036 U+0046 <>  U+1340A
 U+005A U+0031 U+0036 U+0047 <>  U+1340B
 U+005A U+0031 U+0036 U+0048 <>  U+1340C
 U+0041 U+0041 U+0031 <>  U+1340D
 U+0041 U+0041 U+0032 <>  U+1340E
 U+0041 U+0041 U+0033 <>  U+1340F
 U+0041 U+0041 U+0034 <>  U+13410
 U+0041 U+0041 U+0035 <>  U+13411
 U+0041 U+0041 U+0036 <>  U+13412
 U+0041 U+0041 U+0037 <>  U+13413
 U+0041 U+0041 U+0037 U+0041 <>  U+13414
 U+0041 U+0041 U+0037 U+0042 <>  U+13415
 U+0041 U+0041 U+0038 <>  U+13416
 U+0041 U+0041 U+0039 <>  U+13417
 U+0041 U+0041 U+0031 U+0030 <>  U+13418
 U+0041 U+0041 U+0031 U+0031 <>  U+13419
 U+0041 U+0041 U+0031 U+0032 <>  U+1341A
 U+0041 U+0041 U+0031 U+0033 <>  U+1341B
 U+0041 U+0041 U+0031 U+0034 <>  U+1341C
 U+0041 U+0041 U+0031 U+0035 <>  U+1341D
 U+0041 U+0041 U+0031 U+0036 <>  U+1341E
 U+0041 U+0041 U+0031 U+0037 <>  U+1341F
 U+0041 U+0041 U+0031 U+0038 <>  U+13420
 U+0041 U+0041 U+0031 U+0039 <>  U+13421
 U+0041 U+0041 U+0032 U+0030 <>  U+13422
 U+0041 U+0041 U+0032 U+0031 <>  U+13423
 U+0041 U+0041 U+0032 U+0032 <>  U+13424
 U+0041 U+0041 U+0032 U+0033 <>  U+13425
 U+0041 U+0041 U+0032 U+0034 <>  U+13426
 U+0041 U+0041 U+0032 U+0035 <>  U+13427
 U+0041 U+0041 U+0032 U+0036 <>  U+13428
 U+0041 U+0041 U+0032 U+0037 <>  U+13429
 U+0041 U+0041 U+0032 U+0038 <>  U+1342A
 U+0041 U+0041 U+0032 U+0039 <>  U+1342B
 U+0041 U+0041 U+0033 U+0030 <>  U+1342C
 U+0041 U+0041 U+0033 U+0031 <>  U+1342D
 U+0041 U+0041 U+0033 U+0032 <>  U+1342E
```

Answer (score 0):

Full set:

[image: EH only]

MWE

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\let\NDC\NewDocumentCommand
        \cs_generate_variant:Nn 
            \seq_set_split:Nnn 
            { cno }

        \cs_generate_variant:Nn 
            \seq_gset_split:Nnn 
            { cno }

    \cs_generate_variant:Nn 
            \tl_count_tokens:n 
            { V }

    \cs_generate_variant:Nn 
            \tl_greplace_all:Nnn
            { Nxx }

    \cs_generate_variant:Nn 
            \tl_replace_all:Nnn
            { Nxx }

    \cs_generate_variant:Nn 
            \tl_replace_all:Nnn
            { Nvv }

    \cs_generate_variant:Nn 
            \regex_replace_all:nnN
            { xxN }
    \seq_new:N 
            \l_f_rq_seq
    \seq_new:N 
            \l_f_rqz_seq
    \seq_new:N 
            \l_f_rqy_seq
    \tl_new:N 
            \l_f_rqz_tl
    \seq_new:N 
            \l_f_rqyy_seq
    \int_new:N 
            \l_f_rqz_int
    \int_new:N 
            \l_f_rqy_int

    \tl_new:N 
            \g_f_rns_tl

    \tl_gset:Nn 
            \g_f_rns_tl
            {mfs}

    \tl_new:N 
            \l_f_rnsa_tl
    \tl_new:N 
            \l_f_rnsb_tl
    \tl_new:N 
            \l_f_rnsc_tl


\tl_new:N \l_tmpc_tl
%---
    \cs_set:Npn \ic_funcsortseq:cn #1#2 { 
    \seq_sort:cn  { #1 } 
        {
            \seq_clear:N 
                    \l_f_rqz_seq 
            \seq_clear:N 
                    \l_f_rqy_seq 
            \seq_set_split:Nnn 
                    \l_f_rqz_seq 
                    { ; } 
                    { ##1 }
            \seq_set_split:Nnn 
                    \l_f_rqy_seq 
                    { ; } 
                    { ##2 }
            \tl_set:Nx 
                    \l_f_rqz_tl 
                    { 
                        \seq_item:Nn 
                                \l_f_rqz_seq 
                                {1} 
                    }
            \tl_set:Nx 
                    \l_f_rqy_tl 
                    { 
                        \seq_item:Nn 
                                \l_f_rqy_seq 
                                {1} 
                    }

            \int_set:Nn 
                    \l_f_rqz_int 
                    { 
                        \tl_count_tokens:V 
                                \l_f_rqz_tl 
                    }
            \int_set:Nn 
                    \l_f_rqy_int 
                    { 
                        \tl_count_tokens:V 
                        \l_f_rqy_tl 
                    }
            \int_compare:nNnTF 
                    { \l_f_rqz_int } { #2 } { \l_f_rqy_int }
                    { \sort_return_swapped: }
                    { \sort_return_same: }
        }
}


%---
    \cs_set:Npn \ic_funcsortseqnumgen:cnn #1#2#3 { 

    \seq_sort:cn  { #1 } %  
        {
            \seq_clear:N 
                    \l_f_rqz_seq 
            \seq_clear:N 
                    \l_f_rqy_seq 
            \seq_set_split:Nnn 
                    \l_f_rqz_seq 
                    { ; } 
                    { ##1 }
            \seq_set_split:Nnn 
                    \l_f_rqy_seq 
                    { ; } 
                    { ##2 }
            \tl_set:Nx 
                    \l_f_rqz_tl 
                    { 
                        \seq_item:Nn 
                                \l_f_rqz_seq 
                                { #3 } 
                    }
            \tl_set:Nx 
                    \l_f_rqy_tl 
                    { 
                        \seq_item:Nn 
                                \l_f_rqy_seq 
                                { #3 } 
                    }

            \int_set:Nn 
                    \l_f_rqz_int 
                    { 
                        \l_f_rqz_tl 
                    }
            \int_set:Nn 
                    \l_f_rqy_int 
                    { 
                        \l_f_rqy_tl 
                    }
            \int_compare:nNnTF 
                    { \l_f_rqz_int } { #2 } { \l_f_rqy_int }
                    { \sort_return_swapped: }
                    { \sort_return_same: }
        }
}



%---
    \cs_set:Npn \ic_funcsortseqnum:cn #1#2 { 
    \seq_sort:cn  { #1 }  
        {
            \seq_clear:N 
                    \l_f_rqz_seq 
            \seq_clear:N 
                    \l_f_rqy_seq 
            \seq_set_split:Nnn 
                    \l_f_rqz_seq 
                    { ; } 
                    { ##1 }
            \seq_set_split:Nnn 
                    \l_f_rqy_seq 
                    { ; } 
                    { ##2 }
            \tl_set:Nx 
                    \l_f_rqz_tl 
                    { 
                        \seq_item:Nn 
                                \l_f_rqz_seq 
                                {1} 
                    }
            \tl_set:Nx 
                    \l_f_rqy_tl 
                    { 
                        \seq_item:Nn 
                                \l_f_rqy_seq 
                                {1} 
                    }

            \int_set:Nn 
                    \l_f_rqz_int 
                    { 
                        \l_f_rqz_tl 
                    }
            \int_set:Nn 
                    \l_f_rqy_int 
                    { 
                        \l_f_rqy_tl 
                    }
            \int_compare:nNnTF 
                    { \l_f_rqz_int } { #2 } { \l_f_rqy_int }
                    { \sort_return_swapped: }
                    { \sort_return_same: }
        }
}

%----
\NDC { \mfsloadaseq } { o m +m } { 

                \IfNoValueTF { #1 } 
                        { \tl_clear:N \g_f_ns_tl } 
                        { \tl_gset:Nn \g_f_ns_tl { #1 } }


    \cs_if_free:cT
            { g_f_r \g_f_ns_tl #2 _seq }
            { \seq_new:c
                    { g_f_r \g_f_ns_tl #2 _seq } 
            }
    \seq_gclear:c 
            { g_f_r \g_f_ns_tl #2 _seq } 
    \seq_gset_split:cno 
            { g_f_r \g_f_ns_tl #2 _seq } 
            { , } 
            { #3 }
}
%----
\NDC { \mfsloadaprop } { o m +m } { 
                \IfNoValueTF { #1 } 
                        { \tl_clear:N \g_f_ns_tl } 
                        { \tl_gset:Nn \g_f_ns_tl { #1 } }

    \cs_if_free:cT
            { g_f_r \g_f_ns_tl #2 _prop }
            { \prop_new:c
                    { g_f_r \g_f_ns_tl #2 _prop } 
            }
    \prop_gclear:c 
            { g_f_r \g_f_ns_tl #2 _prop } 
    \prop_gset_from_keyval:cn 
            { g_f_r \g_f_ns_tl #2 _prop } 
            { #3 }

}

%----
\NDC { \mfssortaseq } { o m m } { 
                \IfNoValueTF { #1 } 
                        { \tl_clear:N \g_f_ns_tl } 
                        { \tl_gset:Nn \g_f_ns_tl { #1 } }

\ic_funcsortseq:cn { g_f_r \g_f_ns_tl #2 _seq } { #3 }

}
%---
\NDC { \mfssortaseqnum } { o m m } { 
                \IfNoValueTF { #1 } 
                        { \tl_clear:N \g_f_ns_tl } 
                        { \tl_gset:Nn \g_f_ns_tl { #1 } }
\ic_funcsortseqnum:cn { g_f_r \g_f_ns_tl #2 _seq } { #3 }
}

\seq_new:N \g_f_curr_seq
\seq_new:N \g_f_currb_seq
\tl_new:N \g_f_curr_tl
\tl_new:N \l_f_currb_tl
\seq_new:N \g_f_fontsn_seq
\seq_new:N \g_f_fontln_seq

%---- Vars
\tl_new:N \g_f_ftext_tl
\int_new:N \g_f_gcode_int
\tl_new:N \g_f_gcode_tl
\int_new:N \g_f_numdigits_int
\tl_new:N \g_f_numdigits_tl
\tl_new:N \g_f_myblockname_tl    
\tl_new:N \g_f_myblocksetname_tl 
\tl_new:N \g_f_myfontname_tl
\tl_new:N \g_f_prevblocksetname_tl
%---
\tl_new:N \g_f_trtext_tl
%---- Functions
    \cs_set:Npn \fc_funcprinttrscheme:n #1 {
   \tl_gset:Nx
    \g_f_curr_tl
    {
                #1
        }
    \seq_gset_split:NnV 
            \g_f_currb_seq 
            { ; } 
            \g_f_curr_tl


        \tl_set:Nx \l_tmpa_tl 
        { 
        \seq_item:Nn
                \g_f_currb_seq 
                { 1 }
         } 
         
        \tl_set:Nx \l_tmpb_tl 
        {
        \seq_item:Nn
                \g_f_currb_seq 
                { 2 }
         } 

        % print
        \par\noindent
        \tl_use:N \l_tmpa_tl
        \space
        =
        \space
        { 
                \use:c { ffc\g_f_ns_tl\g_f_myblocksetname_tl }

            \large \color{blue} \Uchar \tl_use:N \l_tmpb_tl }
}

%---
    \cs_set:Npn \fc_functransliterate:n #1 { 
   \tl_gset:Nx
    \g_f_curr_tl
    {
                #1
        }
    \seq_gset_split:NnV 
            \g_f_currb_seq 
            { ; } 
            \g_f_curr_tl

        \tl_set:Nx \l_tmpa_tl
        { 
        \seq_item:Nn
                \g_f_currb_seq 
                { 1 }
         } 
         
        \tl_set:Nx \l_tmpb_tl
        {
        \seq_item:Nn
                \g_f_currb_seq 
                { 2 }
         } 

    \tl_greplace_all:Nxx
            \g_f_trtext_tl
            {
                \tl_use:N \l_tmpa_tl
            }
            {
                \Uchar
                 \tl_use:N \l_tmpb_tl
            }
}
%---
    \cs_set:Npn \fc_funcappplyfont:n #1 { 
            \int_gset:Nn 
                    \g_f_gcode_int
                    { `#1 }
            
            \tl_gset:NV 
                    \g_f_gcode_tl
                    \g_f_gcode_int

            \tl_gset:Nn 
                    \g_f_numdigits_tl
                    { 
                        \tl_count_tokens:V 
                                \g_f_gcode_tl 
                    }

            \seq_map_function:cN 
                    { g_f_r 
                      \tl_use:N
                            \g_f_ns_tl 
                      list
                      \tl_use:N 
                            \g_f_numdigits_tl
                      digits
                       _seq } 
                    \fc_funcgetblock:n 

\int_case:nnF { \g_f_gcode_int }
{
    { `\僜 } { \par }
    { 127026 } { \itshape }
    { 127027 } { \upshape }
    { 127028 } { \c_space_token }
    { 127029 } { \c_space_token }
    { 127030 } { \bfseries }
    { 127031 } { \mdseries }
    { 127032 } { \hashtag }
    { 127033 } { \\ }
}
{ 

    \bool_if:NTF
        \g_f_mirror_bool
        { 
            \reflectbox{
            \symbol{
                    \int_use:N 
                         \g_f_gcode_int 
                    }
            }
        }%T
        { 
            \symbol{
                    \int_use:N 
                         \g_f_gcode_int 
                    }
        }%F


    }  
                    
}

%---
    \cs_set:Npn \fc_funcgetblock:n #1 { 
   \tl_gset:Nx
    \g_f_curr_tl
    {
                #1
        }
    \seq_gset_split:NnV 
            \g_f_currb_seq 
            { ; } 
            \g_f_curr_tl

        \fc_funcgetfontnameb:nn
        { 
        \seq_item:Nn
                \g_f_currb_seq 
                { 1 }
         } 
        {
        \seq_item:Nn
                \g_f_currb_seq 
                { 2 }
         } 
}
\tl_new:N \g_f_fontoptionsa_tl
%---
    \cs_set:Npn \fc_funcgetfontnameb:nn #1#2 { 
    \bool_if:nT
    {
\int_compare_p:n { #1  <=  \g_f_gcode_int }
 &&
\int_compare_p:n { #2 >= \g_f_gcode_int }   
    }
    {
    
                    \tl_set:Nn 
                            \g_f_myblockname_tl
                            {
                            \seq_item:Nn
                                    \g_f_currb_seq 
                                    { 3 }
                            }
            \exp_args:Nxx
                    \prop_get:cnN%TF
                            { g_f_r \g_f_ns_tl block2blockset _prop }
                            { \g_f_myblockname_tl }
                            \g_f_myblocksetname_tl

            \exp_args:Nxx
                    \prop_get:cnN
                            { g_f_r \g_f_ns_tl blockset2font _prop }
                            { \g_f_myblocksetname_tl }
                            \g_f_myfontname_tl


            \exp_args:Nxx
                    \prop_get:cnNTF
                            { g_f_r \g_f_ns_tl blockset2fontoptions _prop }
                            { \tl_use:N \g_f_myblocksetname_tl }
                            \g_f_fontoptionsa_tl

                            {
%                           T:
                \regex_replace_all:nnN
                        { \; }
                        { \= }
                        \g_f_fontoptionsa_tl
                \regex_replace_all:nnN
                        { \- }
                        { \, }
                        \g_f_fontoptionsa_tl
                            }{

                            \tl_clear:N \g_f_fontoptionsa_tl
                            }
            \tl_if_eq:NNF
            \g_f_prevblocksetname_tl
            \g_f_myblocksetname_tl
            {
                \cs_if_free:cT
                    { ffc\g_f_ns_tl\g_f_myblocksetname_tl }
                    { 
                        \exp_args:Nxx
                            \newfontfamily
                            {   \use:c { ffc\g_f_ns_tl\g_f_myblocksetname_tl } }
                            { \tl_use:N \g_f_myfontname_tl }
                            [
                                \tl_use:N \g_f_fontoptionsa_tl      
                            ]
                    }
                \use:c { ffc\g_f_ns_tl\g_f_myblocksetname_tl }
                \tl_set_eq:NN
                    \g_f_prevblocksetname_tl
                    \g_f_myblocksetname_tl
            }
                     } 

}




\bool_new:N \g_f_mirror_bool
\bool_new:N \g_f_reversed_bool
%---- FTextM (mirrored)
\NDC \ftextm { s o +m } { 
            \bool_set_true:N
                    \g_f_mirror_bool
            \tl_set:Nn 
                    \g_f_trtext_tl 
                    { #3 }
            \IfBooleanTF { #1 }
                { 
                    \tl_reverse:N 
                        \g_f_trtext_tl 
                    \bool_set_true:N
                        \g_f_reversed_bool
                    \ftext*
                    }
                { \ftext }
            [#2]{ \tl_use:N \g_f_trtext_tl }

            \bool_set_false:N
                    \g_f_mirror_bool

}

%---- TRFTextM (mirrored)
\NDC \trftextm { s o m +m } { 
            \bool_set_true:N
                    \g_f_mirror_bool
                    
            \trtextnop[#2]{#3}{#4}
            \IfBooleanTF { #1 }
                { 
                    \tl_reverse:N 
                        \g_f_trtext_tl 
                    \bool_set_true:N
                        \g_f_reversed_bool
                    \ftext*
                    }
                { \ftext }
            [#2]{ \tl_use:N \g_f_trtext_tl }

            \bool_set_false:N
                    \g_f_mirror_bool

}

%---- TRFText
\NDC \trftext { s o m +m } { 
            \trtextnop[#2]{#3}{#4}
            \IfBooleanTF { #1 }
                { 
                    \tl_reverse:N 
                        \g_f_trtext_tl 
                    \bool_set_true:N
                        \g_f_reversed_bool
                    \ftext*
                    }
                { \ftext }
            [#2]{ \tl_use:N \g_f_trtext_tl }
}

\tl_new:N \l_f_uregex_tl
\tl_new:N \g_f_ns_tl
\tl_new:N \g_f_trbns_tl

%---- TRTextNOP
\NDC \trtextnop { o m +m } { 
            \tl_gset:Nx 
                    \g_f_trtext_tl
                    { #3 }
                    
                \IfNoValueTF { #1 } 
                        { \tl_clear:N \g_f_trbns_tl } 
                        { \tl_gset:Nn \g_f_trbns_tl { #1 } }
        \group_begin:               
            \exp_args:Nx
            \seq_map_function:cN 
                    { g_f_r \g_f_trbns_tl #2 _seq } 
                    \fc_functransliterate:n
        \group_end:

}


%---- TRText
\NDC \trtext { s o m +m } { 
            \tl_gset:Nx 
                    \g_f_trtext_tl
                    { #4 }
                \IfNoValueTF { #2 } 
                        { \tl_clear:N \g_f_trbns_tl } 
                        { \tl_gset:Nn \g_f_trbns_tl { #2 } }
            \IfBooleanT { #1 }
                { 
                    \tl_reverse:N 
                        \g_f_trtext_tl 
                    \bool_set_true:N
                        \g_f_reversed_bool
                    }

                        
        \group_begin:               
            \exp_args:Nx
            \seq_map_function:cN 
                    { g_f_r \g_f_trbns_tl #3 _seq } 
                    \fc_functransliterate:n
        \group_end:

            \tl_use:N
                    \g_f_trtext_tl

            \IfBooleanT { #1 }
                { 
                         $^\leftarrow$
                  }

}

%---- FText
\NDC \ftext { s o +m } { 
            \tl_gset:Nx 
                    \g_f_ftext_tl
                    { #3 }
    
                \IfNoValueTF { #2 } 
                        { \tl_clear:N \g_f_ns_tl } 
                        { \tl_gset:Nn \g_f_ns_tl { #2 } }

                \regex_replace_all:nnN
                        { \c{par} }
                        { 僜 }
                        \g_f_ftext_tl

                \regex_replace_all:nnN
                        { \c{itshape} }
                        {  }
                        \g_f_ftext_tl

                \regex_replace_all:nnN
                        { \c{upshape} }
                        {  }
                        \g_f_ftext_tl

                \regex_replace_all:nnN
                        { \c[S](.) }
                        {  }
                        \g_f_ftext_tl

                \regex_replace_all:nnN
                        { \c{space} }
                        {  }
                        \g_f_ftext_tl

                \regex_replace_all:nnN
                        { \c{bfseries} }
                        {  }
                        \g_f_ftext_tl
                        
                \regex_replace_all:nnN
                        { \c{mdseries} }
                        {  }
                        \g_f_ftext_tl
                        
                \regex_replace_all:nnN
                        { \c{hashtag} }
                        {  }
                        \g_f_ftext_tl
                        
                \tl_set:Nn \l_f_uregex_tl { \\ }        
                \regex_replace_all:nnN
                        { \u { l_f_uregex_tl } }
                        {  }
                        \g_f_ftext_tl

            \IfBooleanT { #1 }
                { 
                    \bool_if:NF
                            \g_f_reversed_bool
                            { \tl_reverse:N \g_f_ftext_tl }
                }                       
                        
        \group_begin:               
            \tl_map_function:cN 
                    { g_f_ftext_tl } 
                    \fc_funcappplyfont:n
        \group_end:
        
            \IfBooleanT { #1 }
                { 
                         $^\leftarrow$
            \bool_set_false:N
                    \g_f_reversed_bool
                    }

}
\tl_new:N \g_f_trns_tl
%---- FTrText
\NDC \ftrtext { s o o m +m } { 
            \tl_gset:Nn 
                    \g_f_trtext_tl
                    { #5 }
                \IfNoValueTF { #2 } 
                        { \tl_clear:N \g_f_ns_tl } 
                        { \tl_gset:Nn \g_f_ns_tl { #2 } }

                \IfNoValueTF { #3 } 
                        { \tl_clear:N \g_f_trns_tl } 
                        { \tl_gset:Nn \g_f_trns_tl { #3 } }


                \regex_replace_all:nnN
                        { \c{par} }
                        { 僜 }
                        \g_f_trtext_tl

                \regex_replace_all:nnN
                        { \c{itshape} }
                        {  }
                        \g_f_trtext_tl

                \regex_replace_all:nnN
                        { \c{upshape} }
                        {  }
                        \g_f_trtext_tl

                \regex_replace_all:nnN
                        { \c[S](.) }
                        {  }
                        \g_f_trtext_tl

                \regex_replace_all:nnN
                        { \c{space} }
                        {  }
                        \g_f_trtext_tl

                \regex_replace_all:nnN
                        { \c{bfseries} }
                        {  }
                        \g_f_trtext_tl
                        
                \regex_replace_all:nnN
                        { \c{mdseries} }
                        {  }
                        \g_f_trtext_tl
                        
                \regex_replace_all:nnN
                        { \c{hashtag} }
                        {  }
                        \g_f_trtext_tl
                        
                \tl_set:Nn \l_f_uregex_tl { \\ }        
                \regex_replace_all:nnN
                        { \u { l_f_uregex_tl } }
                        {  }
                        \g_f_trtext_tl
%--- translit (tr)
            \exp_args:Nx
            \seq_map_function:cN 
                    { g_f_r \g_f_trns_tl #4 _seq } 
                    \fc_functransliterate:n
                        
            \IfBooleanT { #1 }
                { 
                    \tl_reverse:N 
                        \g_f_trtext_tl 
                    \bool_set_true:N
                        \g_f_reversed_bool
                    }

        \group_begin:               
            \exp_args:Nx
            \str_map_function:nN 
                    { \g_f_trtext_tl }
                    \fc_funcappplyfont:n
        \group_end:

            \IfBooleanT { #1 }
                { 
                         $^\leftarrow$
                  }

}

%---- Print a transliteration scheme
\NDC \printtrscheme { s o o m m O{6}} { 
            \tl_gset:Nn 
                    \g_f_myblocksetname_tl
                    { #5 }

                \IfNoValueTF { #2 } 
                        { \tl_clear:N \g_f_ns_tl } 
                        { \tl_gset:Nn \g_f_ns_tl { #2 } }

                \IfNoValueTF { #3 } 
                        { \tl_clear:N \g_f_trns_tl } 
                        { \tl_gset:Nn \g_f_trns_tl { #3 } }


            \exp_args:Nxx
                    \prop_get:cnN
                            { g_f_r \g_f_ns_tl blockset2font _prop }
                            { \g_f_myblocksetname_tl }
                            \g_f_myfontname_tl

            \seq_gset_eq:Nc
                    \g_tmpa_seq
                    { g_f_r \g_f_trns_tl #4 _seq } 
        
        \IfBooleanTF {#1}
            { }
            {           
            \ic_funcsortseqnumgen:cnn
                    { g_tmpa_seq } 
                    { > } % ascending
                    { 2 } % sort field
            }
            
                \cs_if_free:cT
                    { ffc\g_f_ns_tl\g_f_myblocksetname_tl }
                    { %X
                        \exp_args:Nxx
                            \newfontfamily
                            {   \use:c { ffc\g_f_ns_tl\g_f_myblocksetname_tl } }
                            { \tl_use:N \g_f_myfontname_tl }
                    }           
            
            \begin{multicols}{#6}
            \exp_args:Nx
            \seq_map_function:cN 
                    { g_tmpa_seq } 
                    \fc_funcprinttrscheme:n
            \end{multicols}
                    
        { \tiny
    ~   FS ~ ns ~[ \tl_use:N \g_f_ns_tl ]~ 
        TS ~ ns ~[ \tl_use:N \g_f_trns_tl ]~ 
        TS ~ ( #4 ) ~ 
        bsn ~[ \tl_use:N \g_f_myblocksetname_tl ]~
        fn ~[ \tl_use:N \g_f_myfontname_tl ]~
        }
}

\tl_new:N \l_tmpu_tl
\tl_new:N \l_tmpv_tl
\tl_new:N \l_tmpw_tl

%--- Meta
\NDC \mm { s m } { 
\str_set:Nn \l_tmpa_str { #2 }
 { \ttfamily\small\str_use:N \l_tmpa_str }
    \IfBooleanTF { #1 } { \space $\mapsto$ \space #2 } { }

}

\ExplSyntaxOff

%Data - ancient
\mfsloadaseq[ancient]{list2digits}{
32;99;Basic Latin
}

\mfsloadaseq[ancient]{list3digits}{
100;127;Basic Latin
}
%
\mfsloadaseq[ancient]{list5digits}{
77824;78894;Egyptian Hieroglyphs
}

\mfsloadaprop[ancient]{block2blockset}{
Egyptian Hieroglyphs=egyptianhieroglyphs
}

\mfsloadaprop[ancient]{blockset2font}{
egyptianhieroglyphs=Noto Sans Egyptian Hieroglyphs
}

\mfsloadaprop[ancient]{blockset2fontoptions}{
egyptianhieroglyphs=Scale;1.2
}

\mfsloadaseq[ancient]{egytran}{
a001;77824,a002;77825,a003;77826,a004;77827,a005;77828,a005a;77829,a006;77830,a006a;77831,a006b;77832,a007;77833,a008;77834,a009;77835,a010;77836,a011;77837,a012;77838,a013;77839,a014;77840,a014a;77841,a015;77842,a016;77843,a017;77844,a017a;77845,a018;77846,a019;77847,a020;77848,a021;77849,a022;77850,a023;77851,a024;77852,a025;77853,a026;77854,a027;77855,a028;77856,a029;77857,a030;77858,a031;77859,a032;77860,a032a;77861,a033;77862,a034;77863,a035;77864,a036;77865,a037;77866,a038;77867,a039;77868,a040;77869,a040a;77870,a041;77871,a042;77872,a042a;77873,a043;77874,a043a;77875,a044;77876,a045;77877,a045a;77878,a046;77879,a047;77880,a048;77881,a049;77882,a050;77883,a051;77884,a052;77885,a053;77886,a054;77887,a055;77888,a056;77889,a057;77890,a058;77891,a059;77892,a060;77893,a061;77894,a062;77895,a063;77896,a064;77897,a065;77898,a066;77899,a067;77900,a068;77901,a069;77902,a070;77903,b001;77904,b002;77905,b003;77906,b004;77907,b005;77908,b005a;77909,b006;77910,b007;77911,b008;77912,b009;77913,c001;77914,c002;77915,c002a;77916,c002b;77917,c002c;77918,c003;77919,c004;77920,c005;77921,c006;77922,c007;77923,c008;77924,c009;77925,c010;77926,c010a;77927,c011;77928,c012;77929,c013;77930,c014;77931,c015;77932,c016;77933,c017;77934,c018;77935,c019;77936,c020;77937,c021;77938,c022;77939,c023;77940,c024;77941,d001;77942,d002;77943,d003;77944,d004;77945,d005;77946,d006;77947,d007;77948,d008;77949,d008a;77950,d009;77951,d010;77952,d011;77953,d012;77954,d013;77955,d014;77956,d015;77957,d016;77958,d017;77959,d018;77960,d019;77961,d020;77962,d021;77963,d022;77964,d023;77965,d024;77966,d025;77967,d026;77968,d027;77969,d027a;77970,d028;77971,d029;77972,d030;77973,d031;77974,d031a;77975,d032;77976,d033;77977,d034;77978,d034a;77979,d035;77980,d036;77981,d037;77982,d038;77983,d039;77984,d040;77985,d041;77986,d042;77987,d043;77988,d044;77989,d045;77990,d046;77991,d046a;77992,d047;77993,d048;77994,d048a;77995,d049;77996,d050;77997,d050a;77998,d050b;77999,d050c;78000,d050d;78001,d050e;78002,d050f;78003,d050g;78004,d050h;78005,d050i;78006,d051;78007,d052;78008,d052a;78009,d053;78010,d054;78011,d054a;78012,d055;78013,d056;78014,d057;78015,d058;78016,d059;78017,d060;78018,d061;78019,d062;78020,d063;78021,d064;78022,d065;78023,d066;78024,d067;78025,d067a;78026,d067b;78027,d067c;78028,d067d;78029,d067e;78030,d067f;78031,d067g;78032,d067h;78033,e001;78034,e002;78035,e003;78036,e004;78037,e005;78038,e006;78039,e007;78040,e008;78041,e008a;78042,e009;78043,e009a;78044,e010;78045,e011;78046,e012;78047,e013;78048,e014;78049,e015;78050,e016;78051,e016a;78052,e017;78053,e017a;78054,e018;78055,e019;78056,e020;78057,e020a;78058,e021;78059,e022;78060,e023;78061,e024;78062,e025;78063,e026;78064,e027;78065,e028;78066,e028a;78067,e029;78068,e030;78069,e031;78070,e032;78071,e033;78072,e034;78073,e034a;78074,e036;78075,e037;78076,e038;78077,f001;78078,f001a;78079,f002;78080,f003;78081,f004;78082,f005;78083,f006;78084,f007;78085,f008;78086,f009;78087,f010;78088,f011;78089,f012;78090,f013;78091,f013a;78092,f014;78093,f015;78094,f016;78095,f017;78096,f018;78097,f019;78098,f020;78099,f021;78100,f021a;78101,f022;78102,f023;78103,f024;78104,f025;78105,f026;78106,f027;78107,f028;78108,f029;78109,f030;78110,f031;78111,f031a;78112,f032;78113,f033;78114,f034;78115,f035;78116,f036;78117,f037;78118,f037a;78119,f038;78120,f038a;78121,f039;78122,f040;78123,f041;78124,f042;78125,f043;78126,f044;78127,f045;78128,f045a;78129,f046;78130,f046a;78131,f047;78132,f047a;78133,f048;78134,f049;78135,f050;78136,f051;78137,f051a;78138,f051b;78139,f051c;78140,f052;78141,f053;78142,g001;78143,g002;78144,g003;78145,g004;78146,g005;78147,g006;78148,g006a;78149,g007;78150,g007a;78151,g007b;78152,g008;78153,g009;78154,g010;78155,g011;78156,g011a;78157,g012;78158,g013;78159,g014;78160,g015;78161,g016;78162,g017;78163,g018;78164,g019;78165,g020;78166,g020a;78167,g021;78168,g022;78169,g023;78170,g024;78171,g025;78172,g026;78173,g026a;78174,g027;78175,g028;78176,g029;78177,g030;78178,g031;78179,g032;78180,g033;78181,g034;78182,g035;78183,g036;78184,g036a;78185,g037;78186,g037a;78187,g038;78188,g039;78189,g040;78190,g041;78191,g042;78192,g043;78193,g043a;78194,g044;78195,g045;78196,g045a;78197,g046;78198,g047;78199,g048;78200,g049;78201,g050;78202,g051;78203,g052;78204,g053;78205,g054;78206,h001;78207,h002;78208,h003;78209,h004;78210,h005;78211,h006;78212,h006a;78213,h007;78214,h008;78215,i001;78216,i002;78217,i003;78218,i004;78219,i005;78220,i005a;78221,i006;78222,i007;78223,i008;78224,i009;78225,i009a;78226,i010;78227,i010a;78228,i011;78229,i011a;78230,i012;78231,i013;78232,i014;78233,i015;78234,k001;78235,k002;78236,k003;78237,k004;78238,k005;78239,k006;78240,k007;78241,k008;78242,l001;78243,l002;78244,l002a;78245,l003;78246,l004;78247,l005;78248,l006;78249,l006a;78250,l007;78251,l008;78252,m001;78253,m001a;78254,m001b;78255,m002;78256,m003;78257,m003a;78258,m004;78259,m005;78260,m006;78261,m007;78262,m008;78263,m009;78264,m010;78265,m010a;78266,m011;78267,m012;78268,m012a;78269,m012b;78270,m012c;78271,m012d;78272,m012e;78273,m012f;78274,m012g;78275,m012h;78276,m013;78277,m014;78278,m015;78279,m015a;78280,m016;78281,m016a;78282,m017;78283,m017a;78284,m018;78285,m019;78286,m020;78287,m021;78288,m022;78289,m022a;78290,m023;78291,m024;78292,m024a;78293,m025;78294,m026;78295,m027;78296,m028;78297,m028a;78298,m029;78299,m030;78300,m031;78301,m031a;78302,m032;78303,m033;78304,m033a;78305,m033b;78306,m034;78307,m035;78308,m036;78309,m037;78310,m038;78311,m039;78312,m040;78313,m040a;78314,m041;78315,m042;78316,m043;78317,m044;78318,n001;78319,n002;78320,n003;78321,n004;78322,n005;78323,n006;78324,n007;78325,n008;78326,n009;78327,n010;78328,n011;78329,n012;78330,n013;78331,n014;78332,n015;78333,n016;78334,n017;78335,n018;78336,n018a;78337,n018b;78338,n019;78339,n020;78340,n021;78341,n022;78342,n023;78343,n024;78344,n025;78345,n025a;78346,n026;78347,n027;78348,n028;78349,n029;78350,n030;78351,n031;78352,n032;78353,n033;78354,n033a;78355,n034;78356,n034a;78357,n035;78358,n035a;78359,n036;78360,n037;78361,n037a;78362,n038;78363,n039;78364,n040;78365,n041;78366,n042;78367,nl001;78368,nl002;78369,nl003;78370,nl004;78371,nl005;78372,nl005a;78373,nl006;78374,nl007;78375,nl008;78376,nl009;78377,nl010;78378,nl011;78379,nl012;78380,nl013;78381,nl014;78382,nl015;78383,nl016;78384,nl017;78385,nl017a;78386,nl018;78387,nl019;78388,nl020;78389,nu001;78390,nu002;78391,nu003;78392,nu004;78393,nu005;78394,nu006;78395,nu007;78396,nu008;78397,nu009;78398,nu010;78399,nu010a;78400,nu011;78401,nu011a;78402,nu012;78403,nu013;78404,nu014;78405,nu015;78406,nu016;78407,nu017;78408,nu018;78409,nu018a;78410,nu019;78411,nu020;78412,nu021;78413,nu022;78414,nu022a;78415,o001;78416,o001a;78417,o002;78418,o003;78419,o004;78420,o005;78421,o005a;78422,o006;78423,o006a;78424,o006b;78425,o006c;78426,o006d;78427,o006e;78428,o006f;78429,o007;78430,o008;78431,o009;78432,o010;78433,o010a;78434,o010b;78435,o010c;78436,o011;78437,o012;78438,o013;78439,o014;78440,o015;78441,o016;78442,o017;78443,o018;78444,o019;78445,o019a;78446,o020;78447,o020a;78448,o021;78449,o022;78450,o023;78451,o024;78452,o024a;78453,o025;78454,o025a;78455,o026;78456,o027;78457,o028;78458,o029;78459,o029a;78460,o030;78461,o030a;78462,o031;78463,o032;78464,o033;78465,o033a;78466,o034;78467,o035;78468,o036;78469,o036a;78470,o036b;78471,o036c;78472,o036d;78473,o037;78474,o038;78475,o039;78476,o040;78477,o041;78478,o042;78479,o043;78480,o044;78481,o045;78482,o046;78483,o047;78484,o048;78485,o049;78486,o050;78487,o050a;78488,o050b;78489,o051;78490,p001;78491,p001a;78492,p002;78493,p003;78494,p003a;78495,p004;78496,p005;78497,p006;78498,p007;78499,p008;78500,p009;78501,p010;78502,p011;78503,q001;78504,q002;78505,q003;78506,q004;78507,q005;78508,q006;78509,q007;78510,r001;78511,r002;78512,r002a;78513,r003;78514,r003a;78515,r003b;78516,r004;78517,r005;78518,r006;78519,r007;78520,r008;78521,r009;78522,r010;78523,r010a;78524,r011;78525,r012;78526,r013;78527,r014;78528,r015;78529,r016;78530,r016a;78531,r017;78532,r018;78533,r019;78534,r020;78535,r021;78536,r022;78537,r023;78538,r024;78539,r025;78540,r026;78541,r027;78542,r028;78543,r029;78544,s001;78545,s002;78546,s002a;78547,s003;78548,s004;78549,s005;78550,s006;78551,s006a;78552,s007;78553,s008;78554,s009;78555,s010;78556,s011;78557,s012;78558,s013;78559,s014;78560,s014a;78561,s014b;78562,s015;78563,s016;78564,s017;78565,s017a;78566,s018;78567,s019;78568,s020;78569,s021;78570,s022;78571,s023;78572,s024;78573,s025;78574,s026;78575,s026a;78576,s026b;78577,s027;78578,s028;78579,s029;78580,s030;78581,s031;78582,s032;78583,s033;78584,s034;78585,s035;78586,s035a;78587,s036;78588,s037;78589,s038;78590,s039;78591,s040;78592,s041;78593,s042;78594,s043;78595,s044;78596,s045;78597,s046;78598,t001;78599,t002;78600,t003;78601,t003a;78602,t004;78603,t005;78604,t006;78605,t007;78606,t007a;78607,t008;78608,t008a;78609,t009;78610,t009a;78611,t010;78612,t011;78613,t011a;78614,t012;78615,t013;78616,t014;78617,t015;78618,t016;78619,t016a;78620,t017;78621,t018;78622,t019;78623,t020;78624,t021;78625,t022;78626,t023;78627,t024;78628,t025;78629,t026;78630,t027;78631,t028;78632,t029;78633,t030;78634,t031;78635,t032;78636,t032a;78637,t033;78638,t033a;78639,t034;78640,t035;78641,t036;78642,u001;78643,u002;78644,u003;78645,u004;78646,u005;78647,u006;78648,u006a;78649,u006b;78650,u007;78651,u008;78652,u009;78653,u010;78654,u011;78655,u012;78656,u013;78657,u014;78658,u015;78659,u016;78660,u017;78661,u018;78662,u019;78663,u020;78664,u021;78665,u022;78666,u023;78667,u023a;78668,u024;78669,u025;78670,u026;78671,u027;78672,u028;78673,u029;78674,u029a;78675,u030;78676,u031;78677,u032;78678,u032a;78679,u033;78680,u034;78681,u035;78682,u036;78683,u037;78684,u038;78685,u039;78686,u040;78687,u041;78688,u042;78689,v001;78690,v001a;78691,v001b;78692,v001c;78693,v001d;78694,v001e;78695,v001f;78696,v001g;78697,v001h;78698,v001i;78699,v002;78700,v002a;78701,v003;78702,v004;78703,v005;78704,v006;78705,v007;78706,v007a;78707,v007b;78708,v008;78709,v009;78710,v010;78711,v011;78712,v011a;78713,v011b;78714,v011c;78715,v012;78716,v012a;78717,v012b;78718,v013;78719,v014;78720,v015;78721,v016;78722,v017;78723,v018;78724,v019;78725,v020;78726,v020a;78727,v020b;78728,v020c;78729,v020d;78730,v020e;78731,v020f;78732,v020g;78733,v020h;78734,v020i;78735,v020j;78736,v020k;78737,v020l;78738,v021;78739,v022;78740,v023;78741,v023a;78742,v024;78743,v025;78744,v026;78745,v027;78746,v028;78747,v028a;78748,v029;78749,v029a;78750,v030;78751,v030a;78752,v031;78753,v031a;78754,v032;78755,v033;78756,v033a;78757,v034;78758,v035;78759,v036;78760,v037;78761,v037a;78762,v038;78763,v039;78764,v040;78765,v040a;78766,w001;78767,w002;78768,w003;78769,w003a;78770,w004;78771,w005;78772,w006;78773,w007;78774,w008;78775,w009;78776,w009a;78777,w010;78778,w010a;78779,w011;78780,w012;78781,w013;78782,w014;78783,w014a;78784,w015;78785,w016;78786,w017;78787,w017a;78788,w018;78789,w018a;78790,w019;78791,w020;78792,w021;78793,w022;78794,w023;78795,w024;78796,w024a;78797,w025;78798,x001;78799,x002;78800,x003;78801,x004;78802,x004a;78803,x004b;78804,x005;78805,x006;78806,x006a;78807,x007;78808,x008;78809,x008a;78810,y001;78811,y001a;78812,y002;78813,y003;78814,y004;78815,y005;78816,y006;78817,y007;78818,y008;78819,z001;78820,z002;78821,z002a;78822,z002b;78823,z002c;78824,z002d;78825,z003;78826,z003a;78827,z003b;78828,z004;78829,z004a;78830,z005;78831,z005a;78832,z006;78833,z007;78834,z008;78835,z009;78836,z010;78837,z011;78838,z012;78839,z013;78840,z014;78841,z015;78842,z015a;78843,z015b;78844,z015c;78845,z015d;78846,z015e;78847,z015f;78848,z015g;78849,z015h;78850,z015i;78851,z016;78852,z016a;78853,z016b;78854,z016c;78855,z016d;78856,z016e;78857,z016f;78858,z016g;78859,z016h;78860
,aa001;78861,aa002;78862,aa003;78863,aa004;78864,aa005;78865,aa006;78866,aa007;78867,aa007a;78868,aa007b;78869,aa008;78870,aa009;78871,aa010;78872,aa011;78873,aa012;78874,aa013;78875,aa014;78876,aa015;78877,aa016;78878,aa017;78879,aa018;78880,aa019;78881,aa020;78882,aa021;78883,aa022;78884,aa023;78885,aa024;78886,aa025;78887,aa026;78888,aa027;78889,aa028;78890,aa029;78891,aa030;78892,aa031;78893,aa032;78894}\mfssortaseq[ancient]{egytran}{<}
%=
\begin{document}
\section{Sample}\par\noindent Egyptian Hieroglyphs: \trftext[ancient]{egytran}{a001e026m012h} 

\bigskip
\mm*{\ftext{ABC abc}}

\mm*{\ftext*{ABC abc}}

\mm*{\ftextm{ABC abc}}

\mm*{\ftextm*{ABC abc}}

\section{Reference}
\subsection{Egyptian Hieroglyphs}|\printtrscheme[ancient][ancient]{egytran}{egyptianhieroglyphs}[5]|
\end{document}
```

[image: sample]

Comment: Trimmed to just Egyptian Hieroglyphs to fit into the 30k character limit for an answer. Expl3 code for transliteration input, and mirrored and reverse output (using expl3 namespaced sequences for storing and sorting user-definable transliteration scheme(s), property lists for lookups, and regex/replace). Fuller set of ancient scripts (as per image) at https://github.com/texcicada/expl3/blob/main/font-change-template4a_ancient.tex (PDF: https://github.com/texcicada/expl3/blob/main/font-change-template4a_ancient.pdf).