# hierotex by Serge Rosmorduc manual installation

Tags: packages

This is my first message to this forum, and you can consider me as a newbie.
I have installed MiKTeX 2.9 on windows 8.1 and I'm using LED as editor.
Since I need to write hieroglyphs in a way which is more professional than the standard package provided, I tried to install Hierotex package retrieved by CTAN.
Unfortunately when in check the visible packages by the console it does not appear and when I try to use it (quite tricky because it requires to use a support function called sesh) currently it's giving me this error:

[image]

Can someone give me an hint on how to overcome this problem and complete the correct installation?

here it is the log content

```
2018-09-19 15:22:56,181+0200 INFO  miktex-maketfm - starting with command 

line: miktex-maketfm -v Egyp
2018-09-19 15:22:56,213+0200 INFO  maketfm - Running miktex-makemf.exe...
2018-09-19 15:22:56,213+0200 INFO  maketfm - running: miktex-makemf.exe --miktex-enable-installer --verbose Egyp
2018-09-19 15:22:56,435+0200 INFO  maketfm - Running miktex-hbf2gf.exe...
2018-09-19 15:22:56,435+0200 INFO  maketfm - running: miktex-hbf2gf.exe --miktex-enable-installer -g Egyp 300
2018-09-19 15:22:56,662+0200 FATAL miktex-maketfm - No creation rule for font Egyp.
2018-09-19 15:22:56,662+0200 FATAL miktex-maketfm - No creation rule for font Egyp.
2018-09-19 15:22:56,662+0200 FATAL miktex-maketfm - Info: 
2018-09-19 15:22:56,662+0200 FATAL miktex-maketfm - Source: 
2018-09-19 15:2
```

2:56,662+0200 FATAL miktex-maketfm - Line: 0

I add an additional useful info: it does not appear among the installed packages
[image]

last finding from my side

```
% Thomas Esser, 1998, 1999, public domain.
output_format 1
compress_level 9
decimal_digits 3
page_width 210mm
page_height 297mm
horigin 1in
vorigin 1in
% pdftex.map is set up by texmf/dvips/config/updmap
map pdftex.map
% This shows how to add your own map file. 
% Remove the comment and adjust the name:
map +hierofonts.map
map +diacrFonts
```

.map

I don't know to which comment it's referred this message which was in the pdftex.cfg

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) It's always better to copy&paste code or error messages instead of making a screenshot of it. Did you look in the log file as suggested in the error message?

Comment: Thanks for welcoming me ( and correcting my typos... ;) ) I had to screenshot the message because for some weird motivation it cannot be copied...
Regarding the log message I can copy and past the last lines, because i did a lot of trials and I don't want to create confusion.

Comment: You can click "edit" to add the log content to your question and remove your comments.

Comment: **problem solved**  I kindly ask the admins to close the thread

Comment: If you think that someone else could have this problem, it would be useful to post your solution. Otherwise the question can be closed.

Comment: I will add to the post my solution. Maybe someone could take advantage from it

Comment: @dexteritas i added the solution, please check if it is clear and it's ok. thanks for helping a newbie to contribute!

Comment: You may post your solution as an answer and accept it, so that the question won't be shown as "unanswered".

Comment: @dexteritas, thanks again for tutoring me...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Solution**
 
Finally I found the solution digging in StackExchange itself (So to remind me that it's better to dig into the already existing posts than creating new ones...).
 
Anyway
the solution can be found [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/377937/installing-hieroglyph-package) in the best voted answer.
I have an additional note. after the installation the package was still not working well, since most of the features ( for instance and \environment) were not recognized as defined. The point is that the manual suggest to add only the following command line to include the package in the document 
`\usepackage{hiero}`
 Unfortunately there was a missing include in the *hiero.sty* file which was making the whole content of *egypto.sty* was hidden to the system.
The solution to have the package fully working is the following:
 Open *hiero.sty* and add almost at the beginning the 
`\include{egypto.sty}` 
 My final result is the following
[image: final result]

Answer (score 0):

1. Download a distribution of Latex. We will use MiKTeX.
2. Install MiKTeX. Go under download folder in your PC: Double click on icon MiKTeX `basic-miktex-22.10-x64`
3. Download HieroTex package. LaTeX packages can be retrieved through Comprehensive TEX Archive Network (CTAN). There is two packages `hieroglyph` and `hieroglf`. Download `hieroglyph` package only.
4. Download package documentation on dedicated github repository: `Egypto.pdf`
5. Unzip folders `hieroglyphs` in download folder in your PC. Select folder, right click, and then extract here.
6. Decompress files `HieroTeX-3.5.tgz`. In the search bar (Search for bar with a magnifying glass bottom left on your screen), type `cmd` and then choose command prompt.

   A command prompt will open.

   Update file location (select folder hieroglyph and then right click. Select properties. It will show you the path to your folder.

   Type below commands with the updated file path in the prompt. It will decompress the file.

   ```sh
   tar -xvzf "C:\Users\jetaime\Downloads\hieroglyph\hieroglyph\HieroTeX-3.5.tgz" -C "C:\Users\hp800\Downloads\hieroglyph\hieroglyph\"
   ```

   You will see two new files `.\hieroglpyh\hieroglyph\HieroTeX` and `.\hieroglpyth\hieroglyph\texmf`

   If this fails, you may download 7zip application to decompress those files as an alternative.
7. Copy folders to my documents

   ```sh
   copy /y "C:\Users\jetaime\Downloads\hieroglyph\hieroglyph\HieroTeX" "C:\Users\hp800\Documents\HieroTeX"
   ```

   Alternatively, you may use right click copy option and then navigate to my documents. Right click paste
8. Update your environment variable. HieroTex folder is made up of two subFolders: Seshnesu and texmf. Seshnesu (scribe Nesout). Seshnesu contains an executable file called `sesh.exe`. An exectuable file is a program in Windows system 1. Windows needs to know where to find it and it is why we need to update environment variable. Sesh will be used to convert a proprietary file format (`.htx`) to a latex file.

   ```sh
   SETX /M PATH "%PATH%;C:\Users\jetaime\Documents\HieroTeX\Seshnesu;C:\Users\jetaime\Documents\HieroTeX\texmf\tex\latex\hierotex;"
   ```

Alternatively, you may

- Type control in the search bar and select control panel. In the control panel, search for environment variables (There is another search box in the upper right part of the control panel window)
- Select Edit the system environment variable.
- Choose user variable PATH and edit
- Add the two folder paths

  C:\Users\jetaime\Documents\HieroTeX\Seshnesu
  C:\Users\jetaime\Documents\HieroTeX\texmf\tex\latex\hierotex

9. Update your latex system settings. In our case, MiKTeX settings. LaTeX application needs to know where to look for fonts to be used with package. Fonts are held in folder texmf

- Type `mik` in the search bar. It will show you the MiKTeX console icon. Select that option.
- Once console is open, navigate to settings. In the settings, search for directories
- Add folder using plus sign icon

  ```sh
  C:\Users\jetaime\Documents\HieroTeX\texmf
  ```

10. Test your installation.

- On MiKTeX console, click on TeXwork incon. (It has a capital T with a pencil on it). It will open a pop up window with an editor on it.
- Copy-past below skeleton on the editor 8

  ```
   \documentclass{article}
   \usepackage}{hiero}
   \begin{document}
   \begin{hieroglyph}
   i-mm:n:M36-ra:1-ms-s-sw
   \end{hieroglyph}
   \end{document}
  ```
- Save it as `test.htx` in my documents. It will create a hierotext file (`.htx`) to be processed by sesh Nasout.
- Run `sesh Nasout` to read your file

  ```sh
  sesh.exe <C:\Users\jetaime\Documents\test.htx> C:\Users\jetaime\Documents\test.tex
  ```

There is no alternative for this one. You will need to use the command prompt.

- Open `test.tex` file with TeXworks. After having been processed by `sesh Nasout`, your `test.tex` file will be like below skeleton. The application will translate signs typed with Manuel de codage rules (i-mm:n:M36-ra:1-ms-s-sw) to Alan Gardiner's sign list.

  ```
   \documentclass{article}
   \usepackage}{hiero}
   \begin{document}
   \begin{hieroglyph}{\leavevmode \loneSign{\Aca GM/48/}\HinterSignsSpace
   \Cadrat{\CadratLineI{\Aca GG/51/}\CadratLine{\Aca GN/66/}\CadratLine{\Aca GM/67/}}\HinterSignsSpace
   \Cadrat{\CadratLineI{\Aca GN/36/}\CadratLine{\Aca GZ/32/}}\HinterSignsSpace
   \loneSign{\Aca GF/62/}\HinterSignsSpace
   \loneSign{\Aca GS/63/}\HinterSignsSpace
   \loneSign{\Aca GM/54/}}\end{hieroglyph}
   \end{document}
  ```
- Convert your tex file to a pdf file. Hit typeset button (It has a play icon on it). Latex engine will run and return a pdf file. Pdf file will be located in my documents

  ```sh
  C:\Users\jetaime\Documents\test.pdf
  ```

Pdf file should return the name of Ramess II in hieroglyphs without its cartouche.

11. Create bat file. We target common user here. Having to use the command prompt each time might rebuff a lot of users. So, we are going to create a process that will remove this complexity for the user.

- Open a notepad (search for notepad application in the button search bar)
- Paste below code. Adjust it with your own path

  ```sh
  sesh.exe <C:\Users\jetaime\Documents\file_to_process.htx> C:\Users\jetaime\Documents\file_processed.tex

  C:\Users\jetaime\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\miktex\bin\x64\pdflatex.exe C:\Users\jetaime\Documents\file_processed.tex
  ```
- Save notepad file as a bat file in my documents `C:\Users\jetaime\Documents\generate-pdf-from-htx-file.bat`
- Test your automation. Make a copy of `test.htx` file and rename it as `file_to_process.htx`. Double click on the bat file. It should convert your htx file to a tex file and generate a pdf file.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) You can set a code language for highlighting, e.g. shell with `\`\`\`sh` ... `\`\`\``.