# TexStudio - polyglossia - xelatex : how to create symbols

Tags: xetex, symbols, texstudio, characters, polyglossia

I'm using TexStudio to write my thesis and I just changed to polyglossia and xelatex because I'm need to write down words in a lot of different languages.
Since I do this however, a lot of commands from TexStudio don't work anymore, e.g. `\textless`, all the cyrillic caracters like `\CYRR`, etc..
Can you tell me what's the problem and how I can change it ?

My introduction lines :

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper,final]{book}

\usepackage{amsmath}    
\usepackage{amsfonts}    
\usepackage{amssymb}    
\usepackage{makeidx}    
\usepackage{graphicx}    
\usepackage{fontspec}    
\setmainfont{Times New Roman}    
\usepackage{polyglossia}    
\setmainlanguage{french}   
\setotherlanguages{english,german,latin,italian,spanish,russian,greek}    
\newcommand{\og}{\guillemotleft~}    
\newcommand{\fg}{~\guillemotright}    
\usepackage{multicol}    
\setlength{\columnsep}{1.5cm}    
\setlength{\columnseprule}{0.2pt}     
\usepackage[left=2.00cm, right=2.00cm, top=2.20cm, bottom=2.20cm]{geometry}    
\newcommand{\myparagraph}[1]{\paragraph{#1}\mbox{}\\}  

\begin{document}    
\CYRR    
\end{document}
```

> File log : ! Undefined control sequence.      \CYRR

Comment: Just input Р (U+0420 CYRILLIC CAPITAL LETTER ER)

Comment: Related: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/30829/how-to-insert-greek-with-ascii-keyboard-and-xetex-polyglossia?rq=1.

Comment: @barbarabeeton No, the character will survive copy-pasting.

Comment: @barbarabeeton The code point is preserved. Marking Russian text with `\foreignlanguage` or other means is for getting correct hyphenation.

Comment: @egreg -- okay, got it.  i was reading the suggestion in two separate parts; the fact that the unicode value is the necessary bit slipped right over my head.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need `\CYRR` or `\textless`, nor defining `\og` and `\fg`:

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper,final]{book}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{polyglossia}

\setmainfont{Times New Roman}
\setmainlanguage{french}
\setotherlanguages{english,german,latin,italian,spanish,russian,greek}

\newrobustcmd{\RU}[1]{\foreignlanguage{russian}{#1}}

\begin{document}

Texte en « français ».

Texte en «français».

Une «Р» en l'alphabet cyrillique! L'espace entre
le mot e le point d'exclamation est correct.

Un mot en russe \RU{Русский}: et voilà.

\begin{english}
There is no need to use \verb|\textless|, because
typing \texttt{<} gives <.
\end{english}

\end{document}
```

Single Cyrillic characters are not a problem, but for words or phrases that you may want the hyphenation to be correct, there are the usual methods: `\foreignlanguage` or the environments `otherlanguage` and `otherlanguage*`. Polyglossia adds also environments based on the language name. However, you might want the `\RU` markup also for single letters, in order to *see* what they are.

[image]

You see that I took the picture with the Cyrillic ER selected; indeed, I copied it an pasted in the main window of UnicodeChecker (great free software for Mac OS X), resulting in

[image]